# How to compile effectively?

Tags: compile, guidelines

What are the best practices of compiling functions? I understand that this is a vague question, but let me list some aspects that might trigger useful answers. Some of these have already been answered (these don't need answers) but I included them for sake of clarity and completeness:

1. Which functions are allowed in `Compile` (see these lists: [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), [distributions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate))?
2. There are structures which are not allowed by the *Mathematica* virtual machine, e.g. boolean tensors are not supported (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/function-does-not-compile-with-greater-in-it), particularly Oleksandr's comment). Are there other disallowed objects?
3. Which operations should be left for the main evaluation to do? (e.g. `x = x + c1[y]` or `x = c2[x, y]`, where the compiled function `c2` contains the addition inside).
4. Which practice is better: partition a large computation into smaller compiled functions, or wrap the whole into one big function? What factors should be considered when making a decision? One such factor is for example that a large compiled function cannot easily return intermediate values (at least it is not trivial how to do this, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1782/how-to-force-compile-to-return-multiple-results), and perhaps it also decreases performance).
5. Type-conversions: `Compile` silently converts `Integer`/`Real` input to the appropriate type, and it also [packs non packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/how-to-use-a-matrix-variable-for-a-compiled-function), but I'm not sure what the cost of it is. Is it efficient/safe to leave the compiler to deal with type-conversions?
6. How to call for custom functions in the compiled code? This involves calls for [external user functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/89), [recursive calls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13504/89) (perhaps [recursive calls passing arguments by reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31171/89)), or [directly injecting code into a held `Compile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31201/89).
7. Anything else...?

As I'm in the process of understanding `Compile`, I have a very basic understanding at the moment. Please feel free to add any knowledge to this post.

Comment: One thing which I feel compelled to mention, but doesn't seem worth a whole answer, is that `Goto` won't work right in `Compile`, at least as of version 8. It's kind of annoying since otherwise `Compile`'s limited subset of Mathematica would be a great fit for crufty old Fortran code.

Comment: Here is a talk from wolfram research conference I think very useful:
Effective Use of the Mathematica Compiler and Code Generation http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=101&video=751

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I'll just throw in a few random thoughts in no particular order, but this will be a rather high-level view on things. This is necessarily a subjective exposition, so treat it as such.

#### Typical use cases

In my opinion, `Compile` as an efficiency-boosting device is effective in two kinds of situations (and their mixes):

- The problem is solved most efficiently with a procedural style, because for example an efficient algorithm for it is formulated procedurally and does not  have a simple / efficient functional counterpart (note also that functional programming in Mathematica is peculiar in many respects, reflecting the fact that functional layer is a thin one on top of the rule-based engine. So, some algorithms which are efficient in other functional languages may be inefficient in Mathematica). A very clear sign of it is when you have to do array indexing in a loop.
- The problem can be solved by joining several `Compile`-able built-in functions together, but there are (perhaps several) "joints" where you face the performance-hit if using the top-level code, because it stays general and can not use specialized versions of these functions, and for a few other reasons. In such cases, `Compile` merely makes the code more efficient by effectively type-specializing to numerical arguments and not using the main evaluator. One example that comes to mind is when we compile `Select` with a custom (compilable) predicate and can get a substantial performance boost ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-best-practices-or-performance-considerations-are-there-for-choosing-between/42#42) is one example).

I use this rule of thumb when determining whether or not I will benefit from `Compile`: the more my code inside `Compile` looks like C code I'd write otherwise, the more I benefit from it (strictly speaking, this is only true for the compilation to C, not MVM).

It may happen that some portions of top-level code will be the major bottleneck and can not be recast into a more efficient form, for a given approach to the problem. In such a case, `Compile` may not really help, and it is best to rethink the whole approach and try to find another formulation for the problem.  In other words, it often saves time and effort to do some profiling and get a good idea about the *real* places where the bottlenecks are, *before* turning to `Compile`.

#### Limitations of `Compile`

Here is an (incomplete) list of limitations, most of which you mentioned yourself

- Can only accept regular arrays (tensors) of numerical or boolean types. This excludes ragged arrays and more general Mathematica expressions.
- In most cases, can only return a single tensor of some type
- Only machine-precision arithmetic
- From the user-defined functions, only pure functions are compilable, plus one can inline other compiled functions. Rules and "functions" defined with rules are inherently not compilable.
- No way to create functions with memory (a-la static variables in C)
- Only a small subset of built-in functions can be compiled to byte-code (or C)
- Possibilities for writing recursive compiled functions seem to be very limited, and most interesting cases seem to be ruled out
- No decent pass-by-reference semantics, which is a big deal (to me anyways)
- You can not really use indexed variables in `Compile`, although it may *appear* that you can.
- ...

#### Whether or not to compile to C?

I think this depends on the circumstances. Compilation to C is expensive, so this makes sense only for performance-critical code to be used many times. There are also many cases when compilation to MVM will  give similar performance, while being much faster. One such example can be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-make-an-inkblot/3346#3346), where the just-in-time compilation to MVM target led to a major speed-up, while compilation to C would have likely destroyed the purpose of it - in that particular case.

Another class of situations when compiling to C is may not be the best option is when you want to "serialize" the `CompiledFunction` object, and distribute it to others, for example in a package, and you don't want to count on a C compiler being installed on the user's machine. As far as I know, there is no automatic mechanism yet to grab the generated shared library and package it together with the `CompiledFunction`, and also one would have to cross-compile for all platforms and automatically dispatch to the right library to load. All this is possible but complicated, so, unless the speed gain can justify such complications for a given problem, it may be not worth it, while compilation to MVM target creates the top-level `CompiledFunction` object, which is automatically cross-platform, and does not require anything (except Mathematica) to be installed.

So, it really depends, although more often than not compilation to C will lead to faster execution and, if you at all decide to use `Compile`, will be justified.

#### What to include in `Compile`

I share an opinion that, unless you have some specific requirements, it is best to only use `Compile` on minimal code fragments which would benefit from it the most, rather than have one big `Compile`. This is good because:

- It allows you to better understand where the real bottlenecks are
- It makes your compiled code more testable and composable
- If you really need it, you can then combine these pieces and use `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` option setting, to get all the benefits that one large `Compile` would give you
- Since `Compile` is limited in what it can take, you will have less headaches on how to include some uncompilable pieces, plus less chances to overlook a callback to the main evaluator

That said, you may benefit from one large `Compile` in some situations, including:

- Cases when you want to grab the resulting C code and use it stand-alone (linked against Wolfram RTL)
- Cases when you want to run your compiled code in parallel on several kernels and don't want to think about possible definitions distribution issues etc (this was noted by @halirutan)

#### Listable functions

When you can, it may be a good idea to use the `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable` option, so that your code can be executed on (all or some) available cores in parallel. I will give one example which I think is rather interesting, because it represents a problem which may not initially look like one directly amenable to this (although it is surely not at all hard to realize that parallelization may work here) - computation of `Pi` as a partial sum, of a well-known infinite sum representation. Here is a single-core function:

```
Clear[numpi1];
numpi1 = 
   Compile[{{nterms, _Integer}}, 
      4*Sum[(-1)^k/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, nterms}], 
        CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Here is a parallel version:

```
numpiParallelC = 
  Compile[{{start, _Integer}, {end, _Integer}}, 
    4*Sum[(-1)^k/(2 k + 1), {k, start, end}], CompilationTarget -> "C",
       RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

Clear[numpiParallel];
numpiParallel[nterms_, nkernels_] := 
  Total@Apply[numpiParallelC, 
     MapAt[# + 1 &, {Most[#], Rest[#] - 1}, {2, -1}] &@
        IntegerPart[Range[0, nterms, nterms/nkernels]]];
```

Now, some benchmarks (on a 6-core machine):

```
(res0=numpiParallel[10000000,1])//AbsoluteTiming
(res1=numpiParallel[10000000,6])//AbsoluteTiming
(res2=numpi1[10000000])//AbsoluteTiming
Chop[{res0-res2,res0-res1,res2-res1}]

(*
 ==>
 {0.0722656,3.14159}
 {0.0175781,3.14159}
 {0.0566406,3.14159}
 {0,0,0}
*)
```

A few points to note here:

- It may happen that the time it takes to prepare the data to be fed into a `Listable` compiled function, will be much more than the time the function runs (e.g. when we use `Transpose` or `Partition` etc on huge lists), which then sort of destroys the purpose. So, it is good to make an estimate whether or not that will be the case.
- A more "coarse-grained" alternative to this is to run a single-threaded compiled function in parallel on several Mathematica kernels, using the built-in parallel functionality (`ParallelEvaluate`, `ParallelMap`, etc). These two possibilities are useful in different situations.

#### Auto-compilation

While this is not directly related to the explicit use of `Compile`, this topic logically belongs here. There are a number of built-in (higher-order) functions, such as `Map`, which can *auto-compile*. What this means is that when we execute

```
Map[f, list]
```

the function `f` is analyzed by `Map`, which attempts to automatically call `Compile` on it (this is not done at the top-level, so using `Trace` won't show an explicit call to `Compile`). To benefit from this, the function `f` must be compilable. As a rule of thumb, it has to be a pure function for that (which is not by itself a sufficient condition) - and generally the question of whether or not a function is compilable is answered here in the same way as for explicit `Compile`. In particular, functions defined by patterns will *not* benefit from auto-compilation, which is something to keep in mind.

Here is a little contrived but simple example to illustrate the point:

```
sumThousandNumbers[n_] := 
   Module[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += i, {i, n, n + 1000}]; sum]

sumThousandNumbersPF = 
   Module[{sum = 0}, Do[sum += i, {i, #, # + 1000}]; sum] &
```

Now, we try:

```
Map[sumThousandNumbers, Range[3000]]//Short//Timing
Map[sumThousandNumbersPF, Range[3000]]//Short//Timing

(*
  ==> {3.797,{501501,502502,503503,504504,505505,<<2990>>,3499496,
               3500497,3501498,3502499,3503500}}

      {0.094,{501501,502502,503503,504504,505505,<<2990>>,3499496,
               3500497,3501498,3502499,3503500}}
*)
```

which shows a 40-times speedup in this particular case, due to auto-compilation.

There are in fact *many* cases when this is important, and not all of them are as obvious as the above example. One such case was considered in a [recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/finding-elements-in-a-sorted-list/2374#2374) to the question of extracting numbers from a sorted list belonging to some window. The solution is short and I will reproduce it here:

```
window[list_, {xmin_, xmax_}] := 
    Pick[list, Boole[xmin <= # <= xmax] & /@ list, 1]
```

What may look like a not particularly efficient solution, is actually *quite* fast due to the auto-compilation of the predicate `Boole[...]` inside `Map`, plus `Pick` being optimized on packed arrays. See the aforementioned question for more context and discussion.

This shows us another benefit of auto-compilation: not only does it often make the code run *much* faster, but it also does not unpack, allowing surrounding functions to also benefit from packed arrays when they can.

Which functions can auto-compile? One way to find out is to inspect `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`:

```
Cases["CompileOptions"/.SystemOptions["CompileOptions"],
      opt:(s_String->_)/;StringMatchQ[s,__~~"Length"]]

{"ApplyCompileLength" -> \[Infinity], "ArrayCompileLength" -> 250, 
 "FoldCompileLength" -> 100, "ListableFunctionCompileLength" -> 250, 
 "MapCompileLength" -> 100, "NestCompileLength" -> 100, 
 "ProductCompileLength" -> 250, "SumCompileLength" -> 250, 
 "TableCompileLength" -> 250}
```

This also tells you the threshold lengths of the list beyond which the auto-compilation is turned on. You can also change these values. Setting the value of `...CompileLength` to `Infinity` is effectively disabling the auto-compilation. You can see that "ApplyCompileLength" has this value. This is because it can only compile 3 heads: `Times`, `Plus`, and `List`. If you have one of those in your code, however, you can reset this value, to benefit from auto-compilation. Generally, the default values are pretty meaningful, so it is rarely necessary to change these defaults.

#### A few more techniques

There are a number of techniques involving `Compile`, which are perhaps somewhat more advanced, but which sometimes allow one to solve problems for which plain `Compile` is not flexible enough. Some which I am aware of:

- Sometimes you can trade memory for speed, and, having a nested ragged list, pad it with zeros to form a tensor, and pass that to `Compile`.
- Sometimes your list is general and you can not directly process it in `Compile` to do what you want, however, you can reformulate a problem such that you can instead process a list of element *positions*, which are integers. I call it "element-position duality". One example of this technique in action is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/efficient-conditional-mean-on-a-large-data-set/1671#1671), for a larger application of this idea see my last post in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a8d5b98706eaaef7) (I hesitated to include this reference because my first several posts there are incorrect solutions. Note that for that particular problem, a far more elegant and short, but somewhat less efficient solution was given in the end of that thread).
- Sometimes you may need some structural operations to prepare the input data for `Compile`, and the data contains lists (or, generally, tensors), of different types (say, integer positions and real values). To keep the list packed, it may make sense to convert integers to reals (in this example), converting them back to integers with `IntegerPart` inside `Compile`. One such example is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/efficient-conditional-mean-on-a-large-data-set/1671#1671)
- Run-time generation of compiled functions, where certain run-time parameters get embedded. This may be combined with memoization. One example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973424/in-mathematica-how-do-i-compile-the-function-outer-for-an-arbitrary-number-of/4973603#4973603), another very good example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204784/how-to-compile-a-function-that-computes-the-hessian/8210224#8210224)
- One can emulate pass-by-reference and have a way of composing larger compiled functions out of smaller ones *with parameters* (well, sort of), without a loss of efficiency. This technique is showcased for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246330/delete-repeating-list-elements-preserving-order-of-appearance/5251034#5251034)
- A common wisdom is that since neither linked-lists, nor `Sow`-`Reap` are compilable, one has to pre-allocate large arrays most of the time, to store the intermediate results. There are at least two other options:

  - Use `` Internal`Bag ``, which is compilable (the problem however is that it can not be returned as a result of `Compile` as of now, AFAIK).
  - It is quite easy to implement an analog of a dynamic array inside your compiled code, by setting up a variable which gives the current size limit, and copy your array to a new larger array once more space is needed. In this way, you only allocate (at the end) as much space as is really needed, for a price of *some* overhead, which is often negligible.
- One may often be able to use vectorized operations like `UnitStep`, `Clip`, `Unitize` etc, to replace the if-else control flow in inner loops, also inside `Compile`. This *may* give a huge speed-up, particularly when compiling to MVM target. Some examples are in my comments in [this](http://smalltalkthoughts.blogspot.com/2009/08/small-mathematica-vs-c-benchmark.html) and  [this](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/07/f-vs-mathematica-fast-pricer-for.html) blog posts, and one other pretty illustrative example of a vectorized binary search in my answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/f8685f194db18175)
- Using additional list of integers as "pointers" to some lists you may have. Here, I will make an exception for this post, and give an explicit example, illustrating the point. The following is a fairly efficient function to find a longest increasing subsequence of a list of numbers. It was developed jointly by DrMajorBob, Fred Simons and myself, in an on and off-line MathGroup discussion (so this final form is not available publicly AFAIK, thus including it here)

Here is the code

```
Clear[btComp];
btComp = 
Compile[{{lst, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{refs, result, endrefs = {1}, ends = {First@lst}, 
      len = Length@lst, n0 = 1, n1 = 1, i = 1, n, e}, 
     refs = result = 0 lst;
     For[i = 2, i <= len, i++, 
        Which[
          lst[[i]] < First@ends, 
             (ends[[1]] = lst[[i]]; endrefs[[1]] = i; refs[[i]] = 0),
          lst[[i]] > Last@ends, 
             (refs[[i]] = Last@endrefs;AppendTo[ends, lst[[i]]]; AppendTo[endrefs, i]), 
          First@ends < lst[[i]] < Last@ends, 
             (n0 = 1; n1 = Length@ends;  
              While[n1 - n0 > 1, 
                n = Floor[(n0 + n1)/2];
                If[ends[[n]] < lst[[i]], n0 = n, n1 = n]];
                ends[[n1]] = lst[[i]];
                endrefs[[n1]] = i;
                refs[[i]] = endrefs[[n1 - 1]])
        ]];
        For[i = 1; e = Last@endrefs, e != 0, (i++; e = refs[[e]]), 
            result[[i]] = lst[[e]]];
        Reverse@Take[result, i - 1]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Here is an example of use (list should not contain duplicates):

```
test = RandomSample[#, Length[#]] &@ Union@RandomInteger[{1, 1000000}, 1000000];

btComp[test] // Length // Timing
```

The fastest solution based on built-ins, which is indeed *very* fast, is still about  6 times slower for this size of the list:

```
LongestCommonSequence[test, Sort@test] // Short // Timing
```

Anyways, the point here is that this was possible because of extra variables `refs` and `endrefs`, the use of which allowed to only manipulate single integers (representing positions of sub-lists in a larger list) instead of large integer lists.

#### A few assorted remarks

- *Things to watch out for*: see [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/821/how-well-does-mathematica-code-exported-to-c-compare-to-code-directly-written-fo/) for some tips on that. Basically, you should avoid

  - Callbacks to the main evaluator
  - Excessive copying of tensors (`CopyTensor` instruction)
  - Accidental unpacking happening in top-level functions preparing input for `Compile` or processing its output. This is not related to `Compile` proper, but it happens that `Compile` does not help at all, because the bottleneck is in the top-level code.
- *Type conversion* I would not worry about performance hit, but sometimes wrong types may lead to run-time errors, or unanticipated callbacks to `MainEvaluate` in the compiled code.
- Certain functions (e.g. `Sort` with the default comparison function, but not only), don't benefit from compilation much or *at all*.
- It is not clear how `Compile` handles `Hold`- attributes in compiled code, but [there are indications](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/f7b6836791fe1d47) that it does not fully preserve the standard semantics we are used to in the top-level.
- *How to see whether or not you can effectively use `Compile` for a given problem*. My experience is that with `Compile` in Mathematica you have to be "proactive" (with all my dislike for the word, I know of nothing better here). What I mean is that to use it effectively, you have to search the structure of your problem / program for places where you could transform the (parts of) data into a form which can be used in `Compile`. In most cases (at least in my experience), except obvious ones where you already have a procedural algorithm in pseudo-code, you have to reformulate the problem, so you have to actively ask: *what should I do to use `Compile` here*.

Comment: I did not at first realize how essential the use of `Boole` was [in this solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2374/12).  The same thing could be more easily written using a `Select`, but that is much slower.  It seems `Boole` allowed the auto-compilation to happen, or perhaps the speedup is only because `Boole` enabled packed arrays as you mentioned in your comment.  Maybe it's worth investigating this further and including it in this answer of your, or perhaps here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Added a section to reflect this. See if you like it.

Comment: My point (just didn't have time to test it fully when I wrote the first comment) was that if we take `cf = Compile[{{r, _Real, 1}}, Boole[1. < # < 10.] & /@ r]`, it compiles fine.  But if we remove `Boole`, it does not (it calls back to MainEvaluate).  It seems a compiled function can't return a vector of booleans, but `Boole` is an effective way to work around this.  I have never thought of it this way before.  (Of course this specific function is better vectorized, as in ruebenko's recent answer on my question, but it was just for illustration)

Comment: @Szabolcs I knew about this, and generally that `True` and `False` are not so well integrated into `Compile` as numeric types. But this is a good point. This may be worth including into my answer above - please feel free to do it, if you are inclined, or I will try to find some time later to do this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I thought I'd ask you this, given your choice of example here and your academic past — do you have fast implementations of the TW distribution? I know it's not a simple problem to integrate the Painlevé equation and my current implementation takes about 0.4 seconds per point on a 2.6Ghz core i7 processor. This was mostly based on an older notebook, I believe written by Tracy. Since I don't require high precision, but frequent evaluations at arbitrary points memoization isn't mostly helpful. I use interpolation now for speed, but thought I'd check if you had smarter ways...

Comment: @R.M I wasn't alas working with Tracy-Widom, since my work was focused on the distributions of smallest eigenvalues for certain random matrices (Wishart matrices, approximating Dirac operator in QCD), and in a certain scaling limit which is different from Tracy-Widom. And right now, I don't even have Mehta book, so my memories of that stuff are fading :-) (I left academia 4 years ago and I only worked on RMT during my post-doc, my PhD was in Quantum Field Theory, only slightly related to RMT). But, why don't you post this as a question and list your specific difficulties?

Comment: @R.M I can also look at it and see if I can do something, if this doesn't take too long. But right now I am on vacation and having a very limited internet access and computing resources (old and slow laptop I took with me on the road). I can look at it when I am back, in a couple of weeks, why don't you send me an email then?

Comment: Thanks Leonid, there's no hurry. As I said, I do have a working solution and since I don't desire crazy accuracy, an interpolation solution is good and fast enough for my needs. I'm a bit hesitant to post it as a question because not only do I have something working and also because it is specialized and localized. While on the surface the equations look simple, techniques to solve it often require deeper understanding of the Painlevé equations. There was a recent paper by Folkmar Bornemann that computes it using the Fredholm determinant instead, and I was thinking of giving that a shot.

Comment: If I go down that latter path, that might lead to some implementation questions that might be useful more generally. I just wanted to check quickly if you had something ready that you could look up in an old notebook :) Enjoy your vacation! I'll ping you back on this sometime later. I'm no mathematician/physicist, so my use of TW is very tangential and a side issue to the main work :)

Comment: @R.M Ok, sounds cool. Thanks for the warm wishes. I did work with Fredholm determinants quite a bit, b.t.w.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Hi,  Leonid, what about `CoerceTensor`, What does it do? Should `CoerceTensor` also be avoided?

Comment: @matheorem IIRC, it has to do with coersing a tensor to a given type, e.g. reals or complex numbers. It is better if it is also avoided, but I don't think it occurs as often as `CopyTensor`. Besides, these instructions are typically more harmful when they occur in some loop, than when they happen just a few times in the program.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you, I understand

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: You write in your post that '`Listable` attribute for `Compile` works only one-level, unlike usual `Listable` attribute, which threads down to all levels.' Has something changed about that? Just tried it myself and `Compile` threads down to all levels if `Listable` attribute is activated. Also in the documentation it is stated: '`RuntimeAttributes->Listable` is effectively equivalent to the `Listable` attribute of the built-in function.'

Comment: @DisplayName Indeed, you seem to be right. Not sure why I made that statement. I will remove it now, and if I ever recall the rationale and find cases when that statement is true, I will put it back with more details.

Comment: Er… what do you mean by "You can not really use indexed variables in `Compile`, although it may appear that you can"? AFAIK indexed variable can be used in `Compile` to some degree, for example: `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools\`"]` and `Compile[x[1], Sin[x[1]]] // CompilePrint`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148189/1871

Comment: Ah, we used to discuss it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183912/1871 I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 36):

Setting `SetSystemOptions[ "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal"->True]` will emit a message when parts of your function do not get compiled. After compilation, `` Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"] `` followed by `CompilePrint[cF]` (with `cF` the function you have compiled will display some bytecode; looking for `CopyTensor` or `MainEvaluate` in that helps locate inefficiencies (`MainEvaluate` calls the main mma kernel, so it effectively means not compiling).

Other useful options may be found by evaluating `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`

EDIT: As suggested by Oleksandr in a comment, `On[Compile::noinfo]` is also useful.

Answer (score 36):

[Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) has already given an excellent answer for the question but it's so… long and may be frustrating for someone just beginning to learn the usage of `Compile` so I decided to post this as an answer.

Recently (OK… actually it's more than a year ago) I found that [Ted Ersek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/460/ted-ersek)'s [*Mathematica* tricks](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html)(.nb version can be found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4557/)) contains a brief but masterly summarization for the limitation of `Compile`. Though it's written based on *Version 4*, the 6 rules listed by him are still valid and if you fully understand them, you can handle most compilation issues. For convenience, I'll paste the relevant part below (with modifications for part of the commentaries and examples).

*BTW, based on the 6 rules, I wrote a Chinese tutorial for compilation [here](http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=bf2a031f7d0d69064941032c7857dfd1&type=note).*

---

> (1)  Only a subset of kernel functions can be used in compiled evaluation.

*We already have [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871) for the issue.*

---

> (2)  Compiled evaluation can't use global variables.

In the next piece of code a compiled function uses a global variable `width`.  Later we see that the function works, but timing tests will show that it's slower than if the function was defined without using `Compile`.

```
width=2.5;
g1 = Function[{x}, x + width];
g2 = Compile[{x}, x + width];

Do[g1[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[g2[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.786027, Null}
> {1.303057, Null}
> ```

The next piece of code defines the same function as the previous example and takes the global variable as an argument. This is the way global variables should be used in a compiled function.

```
g3 = Compile[{x, y}, x + y];

Do[g3[0.3, width], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.415907, Null}
> ```

The next piece of code shows what happens if we try to set the value of a global variable inside a compiled function.  Here again the function works, but timing tests show that the function is slower than the same function defined without using `Compile`.

```
h1 = Function[{x}, (temp = 2.5; x + temp)];
h2 = Compile[{x}, (temp = 2.5; x + temp)];

Do[h1[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[h2[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.471703, Null}
> {2.391085, Null}
> ```

In the last example the value of `temp` was set inside `Compile`.  When something like this is needed, `Block`, `Module`, or `With` should be used to make `temp` a local variable.  Compiled functions are defined below that do the same thing as the last example using `Block`, `Module`, `With` and they all use compiled evaluation which runs much faster.  Besides the advantage in speed the approach below ensures that evaluating say `ha[0.3]`, `hb[0.3]`, `hc[0.3]` will not change the value `temp` might have outside the compiled function.

```
ha = Compile[{x}, Block[{temp = 2.5}, x + temp]];
hb = Compile[{x}, Module[{temp = 2.5}, x + temp]];
hc = Compile[{x}, With[{temp = 2.5}, x + temp]];

Do[ha[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[hb[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[hc[0.3], {10^6}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.364617, Null}
> {0.352145, Null}
> {0.347725, Null}
> ```

---

> (3)  Compiled evaluation can't work with patterns.

*This rule can be viewed as a deduction of rule (1).*

The function in next piece of code takes a list of real numbers, and determines if `0.5` is in the list. This function is fully compiled.

```
f4=Compile[{{lst,_Real,1}},FreeQ[lst,0.5]];
<<CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@f4
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 B0 = FreeQ[ T(R1)0, T(R0)0, R1]]
> 2 Return
> ```

The function below also takes a list of real numbers, and determines if the list is free of negative numbers. This function works, but timing tests will show that it's no faster than the same function defined without using `Compile`. The problem in this case is that the compiled function uses the pattern `_?Negative`.  Compiled evaluation isn't used if the second argument in `Compile` includes patterns of any kind.  When faced with a problem like this we should use an algorithm that doesn't require patterns, or define a function without using `Compile`.

```
f5=Compile[{{lst,_Real,1}},FreeQ[lst,_?Negative]];
CompilePrint@f5
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 R0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{lst}, _?Negative][ T(R1)0]]
> 2 B0 = FreeQ[ T(R1)0, T(R0)0, R1]]
> 3 Return
> ```

The next piece of code shows one way the function from the last example can be written to avoid the use of patterns.  This version will use compiled evaluation.

```
f5fixed=Compile[{{lst,_Real,1}}, FreeQ[Sign[lst],-1]  ];
CompilePrint@f5fixed
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 T(I1)1 = Sign[ T(R1)0]
> 2 B0 = FreeQ[ T(I1)1, T(I0)0]]
> 3 Return
> ```

**Notice that function definition like `f[x_] = …` or `f[x_] := …` also uses pattern so they can't be compiled!**

---

> (4) Local variables in compiled evaluation must always have the same type.

The next piece of code defines a function which uses a local variable `temp` where temp starts with an integer value.  Later in the function `temp` is changed to a real number.  In this case the function works, but timing tests will show it's no faster than the same function defined without using `Compile`.  Local variables used in a compiled function should always have the same type (`Real`, `Integer`, `Complex`, `True|False`) to ensure compiled evaluation is used.

```
f6 = Compile[{x}, Module[{temp = 5}, (temp = temp + x; Round[temp])]];
CompilePrint@f6
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 I1 = I0
> 2 R1 = I1
> 3 R1 = R1 + R0
> 4 V17I1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x, tempCompile$2}, 
>     Block[{temp = tempCompile$2}, {temp 
> = temp + x, temp}]][ R0, I1]]
> 5 Return
> ```

So one can fix `f6` in the following ways:

```
f6fixed1 = Compile[{x}, Module[{temp = 5}, temp = Round[temp + x]]];
CompilePrint@f6fixed1
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 I1 = I0
> 2 R1 = I1
> 3 R1 = R1 + R0
> 4 I2 = Round[ R1]
> 5 I1 = I2
> 6 Return
> ```

```
f6fixed2 = Compile[{x}, Module[{temp = 5.}, temp = temp + x; Round[temp]]];
CompilePrint@f6fixed2
```

> ```
> …………
> 1 R2 = R1
> 2 R3 = R2 + R0
> 3 R2 = R3
> 4 I1 = Round[ R2]
> 5 Return
> ```

---

> (5)  A compiled function can't change the value of it's argument.

The next piece of code shows an attempt to define a function.  If you try to use this function you will see it doesn't work.  The problem here is that the function tries to change the value of it's argument, but a compiled function can't change the value of it's argument for the same reason we can't evaluate `3=5`.

```
f7=Compile[{x},
Do[x=Cos[x],{4}];
x];
```

Some times we want to use an algorithm that starts with some value and replaces it with another value.  If we want to do this in a compiled function we should initialize a local variable to the value of the functions argument, and then change the value of the local variable.  The function in the next cell does this and uses compiled evaluation.

```
f7fixed=Compile[{x},
Module[{temp=x},
Do[temp=Cos[temp],{4}];
temp
]];
```

---

> (6)  Compiled evaluation can't work with all possible list structures.

The only list structures compiled evaluation can work with are vectors, matrices, and other tensors.  The function defined in the next piece of code returns a list structure that doesn't meet these restrictions so compiled evaluation can't be used.  In a case like this there is no advantage to using Compile to define the function.

```
f8=Compile[{x},{x,{2x,3x}}];
CompilePrint@f8
```

> ```
> …………
> 11    T(R1)2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[List][ R0, T(R1)1]]
> 12    Return
> ```

Comment: sha fa!!! : ) +1

Answer (score 13):

I do a simple test on how `Compile` translate the list generating function to pseudo-code `C`. For example, in *Mathematica*, `Range` is more efficient than `Table`, and `Table` from a known list is better than Table when i runs from 1 to imax. But in `Compile`, thing changes. `Table` with i runs from 1 to imax has the same code with `Range`, so has the same efficiency.

```
<< "CompiledFunctionTools`"
f1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Table[i, {i, 1, n}]]
CompilePrint[f1]


        1 argument
        6 Integer registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I1 = 1
        I4 = 0
        Result = T(I1)0

1   I2 = I0
2   I3 = I4
3   T(I1)0 = Table[ I2]
4   I5 = I4
5   goto 7
6   Element[ T(I1)0, I3] = I5
7   if[ ++ I5 < I2] goto 6
8   Return


f2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Range[n]]
CompilePrint[f2]

        1 argument
        6 Integer registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I2 = 1
        I4 = 0
        Result = T(I1)0

1   I1 = I0
2   I3 = I4
3   T(I1)0 = Table[ I1]
4   I5 = I4
5   goto 7
6   Element[ T(I1)0, I3] = I5
7   if[ ++ I5 < I1] goto 6
8   Return
```

Compile 'translates' the ideas of Range and Table to the same pseudo-C code. So not always the faster function in Mathematica could run faster in the C-translated code.

```
f3 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Table[i, {i, Range[n]}]]
CompilePrint[f3]

        1 argument
        7 Integer registers
        4 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I2 = 1
        I4 = 0
        Result = T(I1)3

1   I1 = I0
2   I3 = I4
3   T(I1)2 = Table[ I1]
4   I5 = I4
5   goto 7
6   Element[ T(I1)2, I3] = I5
7   if[ ++ I5 < I1] goto 6
8   I3 = Length[ T(I1)2]
9   I1 = I4
10  T(I1)3 = Table[ I3]
11  I5 = I4
12  goto 15
13  I6 = GetElement[ T(I1)2, I5]
14  Element[ T(I1)3, I1] = I6
15  if[ ++ I5 < I3] goto 13
16  Return
```

In this case, Table from a known list runs faster in Mathematica, but run slower in Compiled code. f3 takes 16 steps while f1, f2 takes only 8 steps.

The more native way to generate a list is shown in f4. It uses only 11 steps, but f4 uses CopyTensor in a loop so should be the slowest.

```
f4 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
  Block[{x = {}}, Do[AppendTo[x, i], {i, n}]; x]]
CompilePrint[f4]

    1 argument
    5 Integer registers
    1 Real register
    5 Tensor registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    I0 = A1
    I4 = -1
    I2 = 0
    Result = T(R1)3

1   T(R1)3 ={ }
2   I1 = I0
3   I3 = I2
4   goto 10
5   T(I1)1 ={ I4 }
6   T(I2)2 ={ T(I1)1 }
7   R0 = I3
8   T(R1)4 = Insert[ T(R1)3, T(R0)0, T(I2)2]]
9   T(R1)3 = CopyTensor[ T(R1)4]]
10  if[ ++ I3 < I1] goto 5
11  Return
```

One can use a higher function in Mathematica to get the same result. f5 uses CopyTensor and takes 30 steps.

```
f5 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Array[# &, n]]
CompilePrint[f5]

        1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        9 Integer registers
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I3 = 1
        I1 = 0
        Result = T(I1)2

1   B0 = I0 <= I1
2   if[ !B0] goto 5
3   Return Error
4   goto 5
5   I2 = I0
6   I4 = I1
7   T(I1)0 = Table[ I2]
8   I5 = I1
9   goto 11
10  Element[ T(I1)0, I4] = I5
11  if[ ++ I5 < I2] goto 10
12  I4 = I0
13  I2 = I1
14  T(I1)1 = Table[ I4]
15  I5 = I1
16  goto 18
17  Element[ T(I1)1, I2] = I5
18  if[ ++ I5 < I4] goto 17
19  T(I1)0 = CopyTensor[ T(I1)1]]
20  T(I1)1 = CopyTensor[ T(I1)0]]
21  I2 = Length[ T(I1)1]
22  I4 = I1
23  T(I1)2 = Table[ I2]
24  I6 = I1
25  goto 29
26  I7 = GetElement[ T(I1)1, I6]
27  I8 = I7
28  Element[ T(I1)2, I4] = I8
29  if[ ++ I6 < I2] goto 26
30  Return
```

A simple function to counts the number of line in C-code:

```
FindCCompileLine[f_CompiledFunction] :=
 Length@StringPosition[CompilePrint[f], "\n"];
```

Check, generate a list from {1,...,10}

```
f1[10] == f2[10] == f3[10] == f4[10] == f5[10]
True

FindCCompileLine[#] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}

{22, 22, 30, 26, 45}

MyTiming[#] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}

0.780005  0.780005  1.076407   5.054432  1.435209
```

**Conclusions**

- Simple function like `Table`, `Range` is more efficient, translated to shorter c-code. f1 f2 uses 8 steps to finish the job. f1, f2 are the fastest.
- Don't use high order function for a simple task: f5 vs f1 vs f2 vs f3. f5 relies on Array to generate the list {1,2,3,...10} , and needs 30 steps. f3 uses Table with a known list, and needs 16 steps.
- `CopyTensor` can be used, but avoid to put CopyTensor in a loop. f4 is slowest, f5 uses `CopyTensor` too, but not as slow as f4. f4 put the AppendTo (which use CopyTensor to copy to a new list each time) in a Do loop.
- In general, with a good pseudo code (without `CopyTensor` in a loop, without `MainEvaluate`) the longer C code will run slower. f3 vs f1 vs f2.
- Avoid `Append`, `AppendTo` to insert a value in a list, try to use `Table` to generate a new list with the inserted value.
- The function translated by `Compile`, and the function evaluated in `Mathematica` in the different way. Compile is not fully optimized and could be improved better. Maybe, one can try the add on package Mathcode: http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcode/ 
  to get a better compiled C code?
- For list building, use `` Internal`Bag `` as mentioned by István Zachar in the comments.

Comment: This is a very long post considering how little novel insight it offers. Leonid (and the documentation) has already warned us about using `CopyTensor` excessively. The number of lines in C does not really correlate with evaluation speed: sometimes it is more fast if steps of a loop are explicitly written (more lines) then put in a loop. For successive list building, [``Internal`Bag``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/89) is one really fast solution. A better, more concise summary would be more useful than all the `CompilePrint` output.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to do it shorter and more concise, but as you are an expert so maybe your point of view is different with the beginner's view.

Comment: Sure DaoTRINH, you're right about the viewpoints (though I don't consider myself an expert), and it is most important that you did a systematic investigation of the problem! Sorry for the blunt comment, keep it up, such approaches will do good use for the community :)

Answer (score 10):

Not a complete answer by any means but if you are new to `Compile` I highly recommend that you read the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html) on the Mathematica compiler.  It is very useful.

Answer (score 10):

This answer I gave illustrates how to define the type of local variables used in a `Module` inside `Compile` which helps solve some types of issues as compiled functions sometimes are more strongly typed than non compiled ones.

[Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile/847#847)

Inlining external functions inside `Compile` can sometimes be problematic (because of the need of definining the type of some local variables like above for example).
The post [Compiling more functions that don't call MainEvaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/66) answers this problem for many situations (for all that I have seen) by expanding Mathematica code recursively until it is only composed of compilable functions. The code will then be automatically optimized by `Compile`.
This is quite interesting because it allows to divide your numerical code more easily into simpler functions in order to do complex things.