# How to change ColorFunction after plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Say I have a plot like

```
plot = DensityPlot[ Exp[-((x-5)^2+(y-5)^2)/5^2],
                    {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0,1} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to change the `ColorFunction` *after the fact*, as an operation on `plot` (say change it to `ColorFunction -> "Temperature"`) without changing the initial plot instructions?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to change the colors used in an existing plot, not replot it with a different set of colors, correct?

Comment: @rcollyer Yeah. Basically, I generate lots of ListDensityPlots from a large dataset, then want to use a different `ColorFunction` for a select one or two of them.

Comment: `plot` is a graphics object, it does not retain information of the underlying mathematical function used to construct it (i.e. you cannot access the "z" values). You can replace the VertexColors in the graphics object, but you'd need to map rgb values between colormaps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One solution that works quite well and is fast (interpolation would've been slow), is to use `Nearest` on a fine grid. The advantage is that you don't have to re-evaluate your plot, or modify it prior to generating it like Yu-Sung's answer does. Here's an example:

```
(* Create a rule list of original RGB colors to value and a nearest function *)
list = List @@ ColorData["LakeColors"][#] -> # & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.001];
nf = Nearest[list];

(* function to convert original RGB triplets to those of chosen color data *)
convert[s_String][x_List] := List @@ ColorData[s][First@nf[x]]

(* Apply to plot *)
plot /. Rule[VertexColors, x_List] :> Rule[VertexColors, (convert["Temperature"] /@ x)]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That works (+1), but `FindMinimum` works too and requires no grid.

Comment: @Jens Yeah, I thought about `FindMinimum`, but wasn't sure about how robust it would be for arbitrary and complicated colormaps (I'm not questioning it, just am too sleepy/lazy to think through... )

Comment: Agreed, there are bound to be cases where `FindMinimum` will give a wrong local minimum.

Comment: One can make this ~30 times faster by setting `nr = Nearest[list]` before hand, and then doing `convert[s_String][x_List] := List @@ ColorData[s][First@nr[x]]`.

Comment: @RiemannZeta Thank you for catching that! :) I've updated the post.

Answer (score 18):

## Inspection

Let's take a look at what is being returned from the plot:

```
plot = DensityPlot[Exp[-((x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2)/5^2], {x,0,10}, {y,0,10}, PlotRange -> {0,1}]
```

The output mainly consists of a big [GraphicsComplex](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsComplex.html):

```
In[2]:= Head[Plot[[1]]]
Out[2]= GraphicsComplex
```

with color specified by [VertexColors](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html):

```
In[3]:= Short[Options[plot[[1]]]]
Out[3]= {VertexColors->{<<1>>}}
```

So in theory, by replacing VertexColors with other color values, you can change the colors without reevaluation.

#### Good News

By default, [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DensityPlot.html) uses color functions on z values and it is scaled ([`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html)`->True`), which makes our task a bit easier since scaled z-values between 0 and 1 will be applied to color functions.

#### Bad News

We need z-values because we need to apply color functions on them. But, the color function is already evaluated, and only RGB values are stored in `VertexColors`. Thankfully, the default color function is 1-1 function, but there is no such guarantee in general. Also, the inverse function of the color functions are not trivial (not that hard, just will take some time to compute--beating the purpose of not re-evaluating).

## Solution

A bit of cheating. But let's set up the graphics a bit so that it actually contains useful information. Instead of the default color function, let's use `GrayLevel`.

```
plot = DensityPlot[Exp[-((x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2)/5^2], {x,0,10}, {y,0,10},
  PlotRange -> {0,1}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

If you take a look at the vertex colors again, now it is in fact the same value as the scaled z-values of the function (and nicely packed too).

```
In[5]:= Short[Options[plot[[1]]], 4]
Out[5]= {VertexColors->{0.,0.0475548,0.0989165,0.150418,0.197553,0.23559,<<238>>,0.0113745,0.0113745,0.0113745,0.0113745,0.0113745}}
```

From here, now it is just a matter of applying a color function to the list of vertex colors--which is indeed scaled z-values--and replace it with the new values.

The position of `VertexColors` within output can be inspected by the following:

```
In[6]:= Position[Plot, HoldPattern[VertexColors -> _]]
Out[6] = {{1, 3}}
```

Usually, the positions in plot outputs are pretty stable unless you change options that modifies geometry (such as `Exclusions`), and there is a slight worry that `Position` may cause unpacking of nicely packed plot outputs (read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/820)), so let's stick to this value for a while (of course, actual replace should be `{1, 3, 2}`, the second argument of the rule). A simple test:

```
ReplacePart[plot, {1,3,2} -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ plot[[1, 3, 2]])]
```

[image]

It works nicely. Now with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 ReplacePart[plot, {1,3,2} -> (ColorData[gradient] /@ plot[[1, 3, 2]])],
 {gradient, ColorData["Gradients"]}]
```

[image]

## Problems

If the goal is to completely avoid Kernel evaluation, there is no easy solution--if not impossible, since [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html) will rely on the Kernel evaluation anyway.

Calling `ColorData` (and any other color functions, such as [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html) or `Hue` for that matter) manually like this is not efficient in two ways;

First, internal plot functions do a lot of optimization for calling color data. Essentially it is getting a treatment like `CompliedFunction`, but more specialized. By manually calling them, you are not getting much speed up.

Secondly, the output form is a list of `RGBColor[...]` which makes the whole result unpacked. Not efficient memory-wise.

There is a way to achieve maximum efficiency by turning `ColorData` into a linear interpolation function of triples and using `CompiledFunction` or `InterpolatingFunction`, but I frankly don't think that it is worth...

Comment: The most complete answer!

Answer (score 13):

The basic idea is to find the inverse function of the `ColorFunction` that your original plot uses, to reconstruct the scaled function values. Then apply the new `ColorFunction` to those values.

Here is how this would look for the special case when the *original* plot uses `Hue`:

```
colorfunction1 = Hue;
colorfunction2 = ColorData["Temperature"]; 
plot = 
 DensityPlot[
  Exp[-((x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2)/5^2], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ColorFunction -> colorfunction1]
```

[image: hue plot]

Now I replace the `Hue` function:

```
p = plot /. 
  r_colorfunction1 :> 
   colorfunction2[Quiet[InverseFunction[colorfunction1][r]]]
```

[image: Temperature]

So in principle, this works. However, `Hue` is special because it is invertible easily. For the default color scheme (`"LakeColors"`) that's not so easy. `InverseFunction` seems to be unavailable for the blends appearing there.

So one would have to do the inversion by hand, probably using `FindMinimum`, applied to the difference between `RGBColors` in the `VertexColors` list and the `RGBColors` returned by the original color function. It's a `FindMinimum` problem because numerically the inversion may not work.

**Edit**

What I did with the `Hue` example was cheating in the same way that Yu-Sung Chang's solution based on `GrayLevel` was cheating, because the default color functions are more complicated. So here is something that works for the blends in the `ColorData` list, including the default `LakeColors`:

```
invertColor[rgb_, blend_, x_?NumericQ] := (#.#) &[
   Apply[List, rgb] - Apply[List, blend[x]]];
changeColorFunction[pl_, colfn1_, colfn2_] := 
 pl /. HoldPattern[
    VertexColors -> l_] :> (VertexColors -> Map[colfn2[
        Clip[
         x /. Last@
           Quiet@FindMinimum[invertColor[#, colfn1, x], {x, 0}], {0, 
          1}]] &, l])
```

The arguments in `changeColorFunction[pl_, colfn1_, colfn2_]` are the plot that you want to change, the original `ColorFunction` and the new one (both are assumed to have `RGBColor` values).

Here I'm applying it to a plot **with default colors**:

```
colorfunction2 = ColorData["Temperature"];
colorfunction1 = ColorData["LakeColors"];
plot = DensityPlot[
  Exp[-((x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2)/5^2], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
changeColorFunction[plot, colorfunction1, colorfunction2]
```

[image: Temperature]

Another example with the same default plot:

```
changeColorFunction[plot, colorfunction1, ColorData["FallColors"]]
```

[image: FallColors]

Probably it's worth reiterating that the inversion of the color function is a little tricky - but it seems to work well for the default colors.