# Recover data points from RGBColor of known ColorScheme

Tags: graphics, image-processing

In general I want to recover the z-values from an image of a DensityPlot. A simple example might just be

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y, x Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50},
    {y, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}], 1]
ListDensityPlot[%, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction ->"RedBlueTones",
    Frame -> False,ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangePadding -> None]
Export["img.jpg", %]
```

I can get all the color data just by

```
pixelData = ImageData[Import["img.jpg"], "Real32"]
```

but when I want to get a z-value according to the RGBColor of any individual pixel within "pixelData" I'm lost. I guess it's rather straight forward using something like the inverse of

```
ColorData["RedBlueTones",z]
```

I also don't care about any range specifications since I can rescale to the desired range provided with the bar legend of the image of interest.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the the Export[] function makes this irreversible. However, if you can figure the inverse function of your colorfunction, you could extract the z values from a new densityplot of the function z[x_,y_]=InverseColorFunction[imagedata[[x,y]]]

Comment: Related: [How to change ColorFunction after plotting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5312/245) - also Jens, but a different person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that this has an answer up to scaling, one can write a function that creates a `NearestFunction` object that converts from `RGBColor` triplets to z-values at the unit interval:

```
ClearAll[colorSchemeToUnitZ];
colorSchemeToUnitZ[ColorScheme_String, 
   resolution_: 100] /; (MemberQ[
     ColorData["Physical"]~Join~ColorData["Gradients"], ColorScheme] &&
     resolution < 150) :=
 colorSchemeToUnitZ[ColorScheme] = Module[
   {rules},
   rules = Table[(ColorData[ColorScheme][i] /. RGBColor -> List) -> {i}, {i,0, 1, 1/N@resolution}];
   Nearest[rules]
   ]
```

Essentially, every color scheme defines a 1D path in a 3D color space i.e.

```
With[{
  pts1 = Table[(ColorData["RedBlueTones"][i] /. RGBColor -> List), {i,
      0, 1, .01}],
  pts2 = Table[(ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][i] /. 
      RGBColor -> List), {i, 0, 1, .01}]},
 ListPointPlot3D[{pts1, pts2},
  ColorFunction -> (RGBColor@## &),
  AxesLabel -> {"R", "G", "B"},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1} ]
 ]
```

[image]

and the `NearestFunction` maps to a parameter along the path every RGB value of the color scheme. It is exactly what you wan: an inverse for the color function corresponding to the color scheme:

```
invData = 
  First@Flatten[
    Map[colorSchemeToUnitZ["RedBlueTones"], 
     pixelData, {2}], {{3}, {2}}];
```

(note, I've only used `pixelData` here). Now

```
ArrayPlot[Transpose@invData]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After tracing through `ColorFunction`, I found the gradients live in the list

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain
```

and `"RedBlueTones"` corresponds to the 14th position.

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain[[14, 5]]
(* {RGBColor[0.450385,0.157961,0.217975],RGBColor[0.599449,0.262748,0.294618],
    RGBColor[0.721701,0.434448,0.400225],RGBColor[0.813151,0.617722,0.507726],
    RGBColor[0.865768,0.767491,0.623596],RGBColor[0.857126,0.848339,0.734867],
    RGBColor[0.771923,0.848195,0.811697],RGBColor[0.61971,0.781131,0.831119],
    RGBColor[0.433786,0.670834,0.793785],RGBColor[0.256859,0.523007,0.711644],
    RGBColor[0.139681,0.311666,0.550652]} *)
```

After some more investigating, it appears `ColorFunction` just interpolates linearly between these:

```
ColorData["RedBlueTones"][.02]
(* RGBColor[0.4801978`,0.17891839999999998`,0.2333036`] *)

Blend[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain[[14, 5, 1;;2]], .2]
(* RGBColor[0.4801978`,0.17891839999999998`,0.2333036`] *)
```

So we can use this to write a function that inverts a gradient `ColorFunction`:

```
InverseColorData[grad_String, color_RGBColor] := Module[{pos, knots, step, interpdata, interp, sol, x, y, z},
  pos = Position[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain, grad][[1, 1]];
  knots = DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain[[pos, 5]];
  step = 1/(Length[knots]-1);

  interpdata = Transpose[{Range[0., 1, step], #}]& /@ Transpose[List @@@ knots];
  interp = MapThread[LineBetween, {interpdata, {x, y, z}}];

  sol = MapThread[#3 /. Solve[#1 == #2 && 0 <= #3 <= 1, #3]&, {interp, List @@ color, {x, y, z}}];

  First[Intersection[##, SameTest -> (Chop[#1 - #2] == 0&)]& @@ sol]
]

LineBetween[lis_, x_] := Module[{par = Partition[lis, 2, 1], x1, y1, x2, y2},
  Piecewise[
    (
      {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = #;
      {(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x - x1) + y1, x1 <= x <= x2}
    )& /@ par
  ]
]
```

and now we test:

```
With[{rand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]},
  Transpose[{
    rand,
    InverseColorData["RedBlueTones", ColorData["RedBlueTones"][#]]& /@ rand
  }]
]
(* {{0.244535,0.244535}, {0.470216,0.470216}, {0.65504,0.65504}, {0.729637,0.729637},
    {0.205673,0.205673}, {0.664396,0.664396}, {0.363139,0.363139}, {0.671589,0.671589},
    {0.329273,0.329273}, {0.119555,0.119555}} *)
```

**Bonus:**

Since `ColorFunction` linearly interpolates, we can easily visualize the channels of `"RedBlueTones"`:

```
With[{knots = DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeMain[[14, 5]]},
  Labeled[
    ListLinePlot[
      Transpose[{Range[0, 1, .1], #}]& /@ Transpose[List @@@ knots],
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
    ],
    "RedBlueTones"
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice +1.  Just to make some extra work it doesn't work quite right with some other color schemes eg. `ColorData["AvocadoColors"]` (random choice.). I'm guessing it needs just a little tweak to make more robust.

Comment: The issue is that color scheme has a region of a constant channel (Red==0 for z<1/4), so `Solve` fails.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the issue. One could adapt via `Reduce` I suppose.

Comment: Works like a charm (at least for this color scheme) as long as the RGB channels are given in high precission. For (re)imported images, however, the RGB tripel is rounded at some point and exact solutions cannot be found. In this case, the solution proposed by gpap produces results more reliably.

Comment: Mind you, my solution also rounds it up to whatever resolution you pick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
pixelData = ImageData[Import["img.jpg"], "Real32"];
fit[u_, v_, w_] = Normal[LinearModelFit[Table[Append[List @@ Blend["RedBlueTones",
#] &[t], t], {t, 0, 1, 1/1000}], Flatten[Table[u^i v^j w^k, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2},
{k, 0, 2}]], {u, v, w}]];
Plot[fit @@ Function[Blend["RedBlueTones", #]][t] - t, {t, 0, 1}](*Error of fit*)
getZ[x_, y_] := fit @@ pixelData[[x, y]]
```