# Does Set vs. SetDelayed have any effect after the definition was done?

Tags: assignment

I was always assuming that the only difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`) is that `SetDelayed` holds the right argument, so that `a := b` is effectively the same as `a = Unevaluated[b]`. Especially I assumed that after the assignment is done, there's no further difference for variables or functions assigned with `Set` and variables assigned with `SetDelayed`. Looking at `OwnValues` resp. `DownValues` seems to support that assumption.

However I now noticed that when writing `?a`, Mathematica displays the type of assignment used for the definition, which means it has to store it somewhere. And I somehow doubt that it only stores it in order to show it with `?`.

Therefore my question is: Is there any difference in the behaviour of values assigned with `=` and with `:=` (apart from the different output of `?`), assuming the actual assigned expression is the same (i,e, `OwnValues`/`DownValues` have the same value after both assignments)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5919284/618728

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, at least in one place.

```
x = {1, 2, 3}    
x[[2]] = 8;
```

All right there, but

```
y := {1, 2, 3}    
y[[2]] = 8
```

gives `Set::noval: Symbol y in part assignment does not have an immediate value`

Credit to [this old comment by Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919284/question-on-definition-and-values-of-symbols#comment7104123_5919284). Also note the point on memory usage:

> [...] I'd guess that delayed definitions may use some intermediate internal variables, while immediate ones point straight to the memory where the data is stored.

Comment: Beat me to it - +1.

Comment: I knew you were coming @LeonidShifrin

Comment: That's really interesting. Are there any other cases where there's a difference, esp. one involving `DownValues`? The obvious idea `x[1]={1,2,3};y[1]:={1,2,3}` doesn't work because `x[1][[2]]` already cannot be assigned.

Comment: @celtschk, now that's an interesting question, because it seems to take 536 bytes to store a DownValue Set definition of an integer and 536 to store a SetDelayed one

Comment: @celtschk While this is not directly related, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267143/why-doesnt-ruledelayed-hold-unevaluated) discussion also interesting. In particular, `RuleDelayed` inside `DownValues` is not totally inert (contrary to a popular belief, it *does* evaluate the r.h.s. of the rule, albeit in a special way). Consider `ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := Unevaluated@Unevaluated[x];`, and contrast `DownValues[f]` with `Block[{RuleDelayed = HoldComplete},
 DownValues[f]]`, for instance.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Indeed. Interestingly, `f[1]` still evaluates to `Unevaluated[1]`, while `Hold[f[1]] /. DownValues[f]` gives `Hold[1]`. Obviously Mathematica does not *really* use `DownValues` for evaluation ...

Comment: @celtschk Not so simple: ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{RuleDelayed},
 SetAttributes[RuleDelayed, HoldAllComplete];
 Hold[f[1]] /. DownValues[f]]``. As I said, the whole point is not that `DownValues` are not used (which is in some sense true but not really the cause here), but that `RuleDelayed` in `DownValues` evaluates it's r.h.s. and strips any number of `Unevaluated` wrappers. In the above code, I prevented that, thus the result.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, you could make your version of RuleDelayed without HoldAllComplete, by using my favourite "bug"(?): `SetAttributes[rd, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}];
Module[{$guard = True},
 rd[l_, s_Unevaluated] := rd[l, s];
 rd[l_, s_] /; $guard := Block[{$guard = False},
   rd[l, s]];
 ]`

Comment: @Rojo Perhaps. It wasn't my intent this time to play more with this, I was just making a point that it was `RuleDelayed` which was responsible for stripping `Unevaluated` wrappers. You can look at Alexey's answer in the cited question where he managed to reproduce the exact behavior of `RuleDelayed` with this code. I don't have time to test now if it is possible to also use your trick for this purpose, but it may be an interesting experiment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I know it wasn't your point. I just had read in your answer that you had had to use HoldAllComplete, and hadn't read Alexey's answer. His code doens't work though

Comment: @Rojo Oh, I see. I actually did not get it that you refer to that past answer of mine in that discussion. Yes, this is interesting. I don't have time right now, but will revisit this later. And, I did not know that Alexey's code is broken - or at least did not remember it. A fascinating topic, isn't it? I am however less interested in these details nowadays, there are more important things to learn or make myself busy with, for me.

Comment: I was wondering how this information (`:=` vs `=`) is transferred to subkernels when doing parallel computations.  AFAIK definitions are transferred using the (assignable) ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinitions`` function.  It turns out that when using `=` we have `OwnValues -> HoldPattern[x] :> {4, 5, 6}` in the definition list while when using `:=` we have `OwnValues -> {HoldPattern[x] :> {4, 5, 6}}`.  Note that braces.  Just an interesting bit to add and to confirm that this info is indeed transferred properly to subkernels.

Comment: w.r.t. memory usage: `a = 1; b := 1; DumpSave["a.mx", a]; DumpSave["b.mx", b]; {FileByteCount["a.mx"], FileByteCount["b.mx"]}`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another difference

```
test[a_] = Unevaluated[1 /; a];
test2[a_] := 1 /; a
test[True]
test2[True]
```

> ```
> 1/;True  
> 1
> ```

I think this has to do with different handling of `RuleDelayed` and `Rule`. I actually found this difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` after finding the following difference between those.

```
True/.a_->  2/;a
True/.a_:>  2/;a
True/.a_:>  Evaluate[2/;a]
```

> ```
> 2/;True
> 2
> 2
> ```

**Silly note on syntax highlighting**

Note that the syntax coloring, which does not connect the `a`s in the case of `Rule`, can be misleading. Of course (in the case where `a` does not have a value) the symbols `a` do correspond and we do not simply replace by the symbol `a`, but rather by what `a_` matches.

```
True/.a_->  !a,
True/.a_:>  !a
```

> ```
> False (*of course this is the right output, and not !a*)
> False
> ```

So this has nothing to do with the difference.

**Root of the difference**

The code

```
True/.a_:> !a
```

is evaluated using the undocumented function `RuleCondition` (WReach explains that function nicely [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/4330)). This can be seen by looking at the trace

```
Trace[True/.a_:>2/;a]
```

But in

```
Trace[True/.a_->2/;a]
```

no `RuleCondition` appears. A simple replacement is made, where the pattern is simply replaced by the expression with head `Condition`. So no "special handling" occurs here and whether we replace or not does not depend on the condition.

**Another difference between Rule and RuleDelayed**

First I thought the difference was responsible for the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`. I felt it was worth mentioning anyway.

```
Hold[2]/.a_Integer-> RuleCondition[a*2]
Hold[2]/.a_Integer:>  RuleCondition[a*2]
```

> ```
> Hold[2 2]
> Hold[4]
> ```

**Another difference**

Even another difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`, also involving `Condition`, is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40182/4330)

Comment: This had to be said, nice catch +1

Comment: @Rojo thanks again, I fixed the mistake I mentioned now :).

Comment: I think that one problem may be that tag[[1]]=list with lots of parts is not the same as tag[[1]]=list with one element; one part. I have found that the complaint about tag[[1]]=one part can be eliminated by indexing tag[1]=one part.

Comment: Hey Carl, I'm sorry I don't quite understand your comment in the context of this question. Was it meant as a comment on [the other answer by Rojo in this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6348/4330)? Alternatively, I was thinking it seemed like you were maybe referring to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48792/4330).