# Reproducing a Plot done with WolframAlpha

Tags: plotting, summation, iterators

I have problem to draw in *Mathematica* a plot like this:

```
Plot[{Sum[a^10*(-1)^(x-a), {a, 1, x}]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

The problem is that on the plot there is no graph.
As it can be calculated, there should be some values plotted. 
When I try to draw this equation in *Mathematica* as

```
plot (sum(a^10*(-1)^(x-a),a=1 to x)), x = 1 to 10
```

everything works fine, so I think I did something wrong with the first command in Mathematica, but I can't find the mistake.

Comment: The same question on StackExchange: "[Plot with sum commend](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20389534/590388)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Plot` has attributes, HoldAll, so the `Sum` isn't evaluated,

try this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sum[a^10*(-1)^(x - a), {a, 1, x}]], {x, 1, 10}]
```

Where the sum evaluates to:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

before plotting:

[image]

related questions/answers:

[Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate)

[How and when to use Evaluate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34343/how-and-when-to-use-evaluate/34359#34359)

[Behavior of expression evaluation in Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19453/behavior-of-expression-evaluation-in-plot/19455#19455)

I prefer a different domain:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sum[a^10*(-1)^(x - a), {a, 1, x}]], {x, -3, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yeah, that's it

Comment: @s0rce I have one more problem when i Want to draw this: Plot[Evaluate[Sum[Binomial[x, l]*l^10*(-1)^(x - l), {l, 0, x}]], {x, 1,2}], no graph is plotted, and I can't notice way, because if I will calucate this, there should be some points

Comment: @Ziva the result of your sum seems to be only defined for integers.

Comment: @sOrce, Yes, you are right! I forgot to restrict x to integers.