# Why this function can't be plot

Tags: plotting

#### Situation

I have define a function in Mathematica like this:

```
phi[t_] := Subscript[ϕ, m] Cos[(2 π)/T t]
```

Then I specify some parameters in this function with a `Rule`:

```
flapDragon[t] = phi[t] /. {Subscript[ϕ, m] -> 1.204, T -> 0.0278}
```

Which output `1.204 Cos[226.014 t]`.

#### Problem

However when I plot the function `flapDragon[t]` using:

```
Plot[flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}]
```

It plot nothing, but with:

```
Plot[Evaluate@flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}]
```

it can plot something.

#### Question

I wonder why I have to use `Evaluate` before `flapDragon[t]` with `Plot` function.

Comment: When you define flapDragon[t] = phi[t] /. etc you need to include an underscore after the t.  i.e. You need flapDragon[t_]=phi[t] /. etc.  Without the underscore you have only defined flapDragon for the specific symbol t, not anything that might take the place of t.

Comment: You've not defined the `flapDragon` function correctly, use `fD[t_]:=`... Also, avoid using sub and superscript variables. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Comment: I still wonder why `Evaluate` works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you have not defined `flapDragon` as a function of a variable `t`, you've defined it as a symbol with a single `DownValue` for the symbol `t`.

Notice that this does not work,

```
Plot[Evaluate@flapDragon[tt], {tt, 0, 0.02}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That's because `flapDragon[tt]` is not defined.

> I still wonder why Evaluate works

The reason it works is that `Plot` uses `Block` to localize its variables.  This means that the variable `t` is not fully localized like it is with `Module`.  Compare these

```
Block[{t},
 flapDragon[t]
 ]
Module[{t},
 flapDragon[t]
 ]
(* 1.204 Cos[226.014 t] *)
(* flapDragon[t$502358] *)
```

So in this case, it works because you use the exact same variable when you defined `flapDragon` as when you plotted it.  You can avoid this confusion by using a pattern to define your function `flapDragon[t_] = ....` or `flapDragon[t_] := ....` (both work in this situation)

Comment: En, I still could figure out the reason why `Plot[flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}] ` don't works but `Plot[Evaluate@flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}]` works from your answer.

Comment: But, The reason why `Plot[Evaluate@flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}]` works may be not because "Plot uses Block to localize its variables" as you figure out. "Plot has Attributes HoldAll, so one possibility to get what you expect is to do just SetOptions[Plot, Evaluated -> True];" Ref. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19453/behavior-of-expression-evaluation-in-plot

Comment: That isn't the interesting question at hand, the question is why `Plot[Evaluate@flapDragon[t], {t, 0, 0.02}]` works **at all**, when `flapDragon` wasn't even defined as a function.  Of course you need `Evaluate` when doing `Plot`, [do a search](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=plot%20holdall%20evaluate) and you'll find many posts about it.  The reason it works in this case is most certainly a fluke related to what I wrote here.

Comment: thanks. it seems you understand my question better than I. I didn't make the essential of my problem clear. I wish to keep my original question as it used to be, for the purpose to remind me of detailed problem formulation