# How to plot a function?

Tags: plotting, functions

Let's assume a box-function and a convolution:

```
f = UnitBox[x];
c[t_] := Convolve[t, t, x, y] /. y -> x;
c[f]
```

My problem arises when plotting the functions. Why does the code p2 work and the code p1 not? Where is the difference?

```
p1 = Plot[{f, c[f]}, {x, -2, 2}]
p2 = Plot[{f, UnitTriangle[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: `p1 = Plot[{f, Evaluate@c[f]}, {x, -2, 2}]`

Answer (score 4):

```
f = UnitBox[x];
c[t_] := Convolve[t, t, x, y] /. y -> x;
p1 = Plot[{f, Evaluate@c[f]}, {x, -2, 2}]
p2 = Plot[{f, UnitTriangle[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun (as Sumit has answered question). Also search site for questions and posts such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19453/behavior-of-expression-evaluation-in-plot/19455#19455).

```
f = UnitBox[x];
c[t_] := Convolve[t, t, x, y] /. y -> x;
c[f];
cn[t_] := Integrate[f UnitBox[t - x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

Animate[Plot[{f, c[f], UnitBox[x - p]}, {x, -2, 2},
  Filling -> {3 -> {Axis, LightRed}, 1 -> {3}},
  Evaluated -> True,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{p, cn[p]}]},
  Exclusions -> None], {p, -2, 2}]
```

[image]