# plot[] with subsititution rule

Tags: plotting, replacement

I encounter this problem in *Mathematica* 9.0.1, I'm not sure if it ever happens in other version.

```
Plot[{x, x + 1}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

This will show a red curve and a green curve, which is as expected.

But

```
Plot[{a, b} /. {a -> x, b -> x + 1}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

will give me two green curves.

Since

```
{a, b} /. {a -> x, b -> x + 1}
```

will give you

```
{x, 1 + x}
```

, I don't understand why there is difference in the results given by the two plot statements.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot

Comment: From the documentation: `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates f only after assigning specific numerical values to x. You need to `Evaluate` first.