# Plot an implicit function containing the correlation of two vectors

Tags: plotting

I am trying to do something like this:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Expand[Correlation[{0, 1, 2}, {b1, b2, b3}] == .5], {b1, -5, 
  5}, {b2, -5, 5}, {b3, -10, 10}]
```

But apparently this make the computer freeze.

Comment: It works fine for me; it might be faster to plot `expr = Re[Correlation[{0, 1, 2}, {b1, b2, b3}]]` though.

Comment: Or get rid of `Expand` and add [`Evaluated->True`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot)

Comment: @b.gatessucks Could you please type out the whole command here? Thanks!

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[
 expr == .5], {b1, -5, 
  5}, {b2, -5, 5}, {b3, -10, 10}]`.

Comment: I found your solution faster than the one proposed in the answer. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

First simplify your function:

```
f[b1_, b2_, b3_] = FullSimplify[Correlation[{0, 1, 2}, {b1, b2, b3}], 
  Assumptions -> {b1, b2, b3} \[Element] Reals]
```

[image]

The plot. Teared edge is where singularity happens. Stripes help you to see where the slope is steeper.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 f[b1, b2, b3] == .5, {b1, -5, 5}, {b2, -5, 5}, {b3, -10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshShading -> {Red, Automatic}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Yellow]]
```

[image]