# Issues with creating functions

Tags: plotting, functions

Sometimes when I try to create a function inside a function, Mathematica gives me a hard time. I usually just have to play around with the syntax until it gets something it "likes" but I really have idea *why* certain things work and others don't. 
Here's an example I just ran into recently:

**Code version A:**

```
ans[tf_] :=
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == -x[t] - v[t], x[0] == 1, 
     v[0] == 1}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tf}] // Flatten;
ans[2]
Plot[{x[t], v[t]} /. %, {t, 0, 2}]
```

So this works beautifully. But for some reason if I try to nest my `ans[2]` inside my function by replacing it with the `%`, Mathematica can't evaluate it!

**Code version B:**

```
ans[tf_] :=
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == -x[t] - v[t], x[0] == 1, 
     v[0] == 1}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tf}] // Flatten;

Plot[{x[t], v[t]} /. ans[2], {t, 0, 2}]
```

So my question boils down to: Why does *Code Version A* work and *Code Version B* doesn't?

Comment: Add the option `Evaluated -> True` to your second Plot

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE Steven!  Please do not use the `bugs` tag for new question.  We use this tag to categorize *confirmed* bugs.  It'll be re-added if this is confirmed to be a bug by the community.

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot  and  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/12

Comment: @belisarius But `Evaluated` is not documented anywhere. Either, politically correct: `Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 2}]`, or, faster: `Plot @@ {{x[t], v[t]} /. %, {t, 0, 2}}`

Comment: Maybe the reason why this is so, is that there is infinite evaluation, and sometimes this is not as efficient as needed, and therefore there is this funny attribute `HoldAll`, which is hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

`NDSolve` doesn't localize the function variable so it doesn't work if your `t` has a value while it is being evaluated. For example, the following won't work.

```
Block[{x = 1}, NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

`Plot` often automatically decides not to evaluate the function until after giving the variable numerical values. If this is the case then for each point `Plot` wants to plot (say `t=1.23`), it does something equivalent to `Block[{t=1.23}, {x[t], v[t]} /. ans[2]]` to get the output value.

In your first case, `ans[2]` had been preevaluated into `InterpolatingFunction`s and stored in `%`, so it works. But in your second case, the `ans[2]` and hence the `NDSolve` are evaluated WHILE `t` has a numerical value so FAAIL

You could patch it by forcing `Plot` to preevaluate the argument as people suggested, but it seems more appropriate to fix the heart of the issue and localize your `t` on `ans`

```
ans[tf_] := 
 Block[{t}, 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == -x[t] - v[t], x[0] == 1, 
     v[0] == 1}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tf}] // Flatten]
```

Or even better, get pure functions out of `NDSolve` by using `{x, v}` as a third argument instead of `{x, v}`, and then you can use ANY variable name in your `Plot`.
This opens the door to using a formal symbol (symbols that are protected by default) in `ans` if you want to do away with the `Block`.

Comment: [Plot often automatically decides not to evaluate ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animism)

Comment: @belisarius if you drop your soap, `Plot[t, GARCH[3,2]`

Comment: Your comment was flagged for reasons the mod will be unable to understand