# Why does initialization slow down manipulate in this case?

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate

I'm trying to manipulate a plot of function with some parameters. The function is a long expression, so I tried to put it inside the Initialization options of `Manipulate`. However, once I did that, the performance is really bad, compared to one that have the function explicitly written out. Here is a simplified version:

Here is the original one:

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  Re[( C10 Exp[I 2 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10)) + ( 
    C10 Exp[I 4 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10)) + ( 
    C10 Exp[I 8 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10))], {τ, 
   0, π}, {ω, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 60],
 {{C10, 0.5}, 0.1, 1.}]
```

and here is the one with definition inside `Initialization` option:

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  f[ω, τ, C10], {τ, 0, π}, {ω, -0.5, 0.5},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 60],
 {{C10, 0.5}, 0.1, 1.}, 
 Initialization :> {f[ω_, τ_, C10_] := 
    Re[( C10 Exp[I 2 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10)) + ( 
      C10 Exp[I 4 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10)) + ( 
      C10 Exp[I 8 τ] )/(0.1 - I (ω - C10/10))]}]
```

Here is the screenshot for comparison:

[image]
[image]

They original one seems much faster than the later one.
Why does this happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems just due to not having Evaluate inside the DensityPlot applied to the function.

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  Evaluate@f[\[Omega], \[Tau], C10], {\[Tau], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Omega], -0.5, 0.5},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 60],
 {{C10, 0.5}, 0.1, 1.}, 
 Initialization :> {f[\[Omega]_, \[Tau]_, C10_] := 
    Re[( C10 Exp[I 2 \[Tau]] )/(0.1 - I (\[Omega] - C10/10)) + ( 
      C10 Exp[I 4 \[Tau]] )/(0.1 - I (\[Omega] - C10/10)) + ( 
      C10 Exp[I 8 \[Tau]] )/(0.1 - I (\[Omega] - C10/10))]}]
```

`?? DensityPlot`  has HoldAll, same as `Plot`. This is a common thing to watch for when having functions inside functions that has `Hold` in them. see this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html

and Here are related questions that explains it well. [Why do I have to put Evaluate[] here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here) and this [How and when to use Evaluate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34343/how-and-when-to-use-evaluate)  and many more

So, this has nothing to do with Initialization. It is just the common issue of not using `Evaluate` when it is needed inside the Plot functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I never thought about `Evaluate`, because it gives the results but slower :)