# Problems with Manipulate (indicated by blinking output cell)

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format

The following code produces the error message when exported to CDF in the title of this question. Although I have seen similar issues on SE, the problem is manifest by the "blinking" of the plot output's cell bracket. My goal is to export this code to CDF but am stymied now.

```
Manipulate[If[s = 20, s = 0];
 y1[t_] := y[t, 2];
 Plot[y1[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{s, y1[s]}]}],
 {{s, 0, "GO"}, 0, 20, .01, ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 4, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True},

 Initialization -> (y[t_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-0.2 t]))
 ]
```

Comment: Move the definition of `y1[t_]=...` inside `Initialization`, i.e., `Initialization :> {y[t_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-0.2 t]), y1[t_] = y[t, 2]}`   (after fixing the typo as eldo noted -- `If[s==20,...]` instead of  `If[s=20,...]`)

Comment: @kguler - good point to move the two functions to `Initialization`. But even then you have to replace their "t" by "x" (or any other unused symbol). Also, the bracket after `SaveDefinitions` is in the wrong place. It has to close the `Trigger`-definition.

Comment: @eldo, good points..

Comment: @kguler - thanks :) I would (for more time-consuming plots) also recomend to precede the first argument of `Plot` with `Evaluate`. Strangely, this can become necessary when you use `Initialization`: [(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41699/why-does-initialization-slow-down-manipulate-in-this-case)]

Comment: @eldo - Why SaveDefinitions -> False at all? The default for SaveDefinitions is False. I used SaveDefinitions->True in my code b/c I had additional functions to plot (for other values of x0) along with the corresponding Epilogs.

Comment: @Stephen - Sorry, this was my mistake. You can, of course, leave `SaveDefinition` as defined in your example.

Comment: @eldo - It seems that your use of LocalizeVariables and TrackedSymbols solved my issue. The removal of the Initialization command and placing the function y[t_,x0_] before the Plot command does not seem necessary. What do you gain by this? I restored the Initialization command and all worked well.

Comment: @Stephen - thanks for the accept. It's simply better style not to separate the two functions. Either put both at the beginning or - as kguler suggested - into the `Initialization`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine with me:

```
Manipulate[
 If[s == 20, s = 0];
 y1[x_] := y[x, 2];
 y[x_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-0.2 x]);

 Plot[y1[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{s, y1[s]}]}],

 {{s, 0, "GO"}, 0, 20, .01, ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 4},

 SaveDefinitions -> True,
 TrackedSymbols :> {s}
 ]
```

To try it, copy my code (you had some typos in yours).
`TrackedSymbols` (if used in the right way) kills the blinking.

Answer (score 5):

First, making an assignment to a symbol with `=` or `:=` usually triggers an update; this is because if the value or definition (down values) of a tracked symbol is changed, the system marks the code within a `Dynamic` that depends on the symbol for an update.  The whole body of the `Manipulate` is put inside a `Dynamic`, so that the definition `y1[t_] := y[t, 2]` causes an update if `y1` is a tracked symbol, which it will be by default.  This leads to an infinite loop because each time the body is executed, the tracked symbol `y1` is defined.

There are two (or three) basic ways to go: (1) Remove the dependency of the code on (or do not define `y1` in the bode), or (2) do not track `y1`.  Below shows (1), since [@eldo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14254/eldo) has already shown (2).  I've also done a few other things. I've isolated the code segment that depends on the symbol `s` by wrapping it in `Dynamic`.  This means that when `s` changes, only the point is redrawn and the `Plot` is not recomputed.  This can be a great trick for improving the responsiveness of a `Manipulate`.  Next, I used `Mod` instead of `If`.  I've localized the symbols `y` and `y1`, which would be my preference unless there is a need for them to be global.  The declaration

```
{{y, y}, ControlType -> None}
```

initializes `y` to be `y` and makes it a local variable of the `DynamicModule` created by `Manipulate`; in contrast, the declaration

```
{y, ControlType -> None}
```

initializes `y` to be `0`, the default.  This causes an error when `y[t_, x0_] :=...` is executed.  Finally, I put both function definitions, `y` and `y1`, in the `Initialization` option.  This takes the definitions out of the body of `Manipulate` and prevents the infinite loop.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y1[Pause[0.002]; t], {t, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, 
    Dynamic @ With[{s = Mod[s, 20]}, Point[{s, y1[s]}]]}],

 {{s, 0, "GO"}, 0, 20, .01, ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 4},
 {{y, y}, ControlType -> None}, {{y1, y1}, ControlType -> None},

 Initialization :> (
   y1[t_] := y[t, 2];
   y[t_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-0.2 t])
   )]
```

Comment: +1 - should be part of the help text. Isolating the "s" the way you did it seems to solve an old problem of mine. However, instead of writing this somehow obscure `ControlType -> None`, why don't you simply change the "t" in the two Initialization-functions to "somesymbol"? I just tried your code with this change and that works.

Comment: @eldo What difference does changing the `t` make?  It seems to work both ways, so why not leave it as the OP had it?  [Also, thanks! +1 to you, too.]

Comment: @Michael E2 - I tried your code w/o `{{y, y}, ControlType -> None}` and it exported to CDF just fine. So I don't understand why you used that code in the first place

Comment: @Stephen.  To make `y` into a local symbol.  If you wish `y` to be global, leave out the `{{y, y},...}`.  If this is the only code in the CDF, then you won't notice any difference either way.  Later if you add another `Manipulate` that uses the symbol `y` or `y1`, then it probably will make difference.  There are reasons for doing it one way or the other that depend on the application.  I pointed out how to localize a function definition in `Manipulate` because I have yet to find it in the documentation.

Comment: I added another function to plot `y2[t]` and in `Epilog` - `{s, y2[s]}` where I defined `y2` in the `Initialization` as `y2[t_] := y[t, 0.1];` Now the output cell blinks, although export to CDF works fine.

Comment: @Stephen You might want to move the `Dynamic`.  For example, `Epilog -> Dynamic[ With[{s = Mod[s, 20]}, {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{s, y1[s]}], Brown, Point[{s, y2[s]}]}] ]`.  You can also put the second point inside `Point`: `Dynamic[With[{s = Mod[s, 20]}, Point[{{s, y1[s]}, {s, y2[s]}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Brown}]]]`.