# Is there something wrong with this piece of code involving Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, memory, code-review

I am playing around with the `Manipulate` sentence. I think the following code is right, and actually Mathematica 9.0 doesn't return any error message, but I am observing something strange:

- when I execute the `Manipulate` sentence, the fan of my laptop starts *overworking* (I do not know if this expression is right) making lot of noise, which usually means that there is a heavy process running, and if I delete the result of the code, the fan returns to its normal state; and
- the vertical line at the right of the result of the code is highlighted in black and slightly *twinkling*.

This is the code:

```
Manipulate[f[x_] := Sin[x]; {Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a}], f[a]}, {a, 1, 50}]
```

And this is the image of what I get, where you can see the black vertical line:

[image: Manipulate causing computer strange behaviour]

So, my question is: do you get the same computer behaviour, or is it just me? And, is there something wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49257/problems-with-manipulate-indicated-by-blinking-output-cell/49264#49264

Answer (score 8):

Your code is redefining the function `f` every time the `Manipulate` updates its contents pane, which causing *Mathematica* to go hyper.

You should use the option `Initialization` so the function is defined just once.

```
Manipulate[
  Column @ {Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a}], f[a]},
  {a, 1, 50},
  Initialization :> (f[x_] = Sin[x])]
```

[image: manip]

Comment: Ok, let me try to get this straight: The front-end tells `Manipulate` to re-evaluate its first argument whenever one of the symbols in it (or at least one of those tracked) changes definition. In the OP's case, this re-evaluation of the first argument causes `f` to change definition, leading to a never ending loop of misery. (Oh, and +1 for `Initialization` btw).

Comment: @TeakeNutma. You got it. The reason edo's approach calms things down is because, when `f` is no longer tracked, there is no infinite recursion. But it's not the best fix because it still re-evaluates `f` on each update of the contents pane.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm working with complicated `Manipulate`s involving tables with 30.000 rows times 20 columns. All of my functions are outside `Manipulate`. 20 constants are globally defined, 30 variables are "tracked". If I would move all my 40 functions to `Initialization` I couldn`t read my code anymore. IMO `TrackedSymbols` works in an extremely fast and reliable manner.

Comment: @eldo. I do not argue against the controlling the tracking of symbols. Nor do I argue against defining functions outside a `Manipulate` expression. But it is always a bad idea to have a function definition as part of the ***first*** argument to `Manipulate`, even when you use the `TrackedSymbols` option to suppress recursive evaluation. The `SetDelayed` expression defining the function will still be evaluated once each time the contents pane is refreshed.

Comment: @m_goldberg Agree

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[f[x_] := Sin[x]; {Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a}], f[a]}, {a, 1, 50},
  TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

solved the problem for me (I got the same flickering). The `Documentation` doesn't say too much about `TrackedSymbols`. In your case not only `a` but also `x` is continiously updateted. But `Manipulate` should update `x` only in case `a` changes, i.e., the slider is moved. This you specify by limiting `TrackedSymbols` to `a`.

Comment: I think `TrackedSymbols` should generally be used with `RuleDelayed` according to the docs, not `Rule`.

Comment: @TeakeNutma Thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

It seems the definition of `f` inside the `Manipulate` is causing the problem (I'm not sure on the exact details, perhaps someone else can elaborate). Besides [eldo's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56751/5485) with [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html),
you might opt to define `f` outside:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
Manipulate[{Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a}], f[a]}, {a, 1, 50}]
```

But why define `f` at all? It can also be done without specifying `f`:

```
Manipulate[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, a}], Sin[a]}, {a, 1, 50}]
```

Note that if you want the `Sin` to keep being displayed as `Sin` on the RHS of the plot, you can do the following:

```
Manipulate[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, a}], With[{a = a}, HoldForm@Sin[a]]}, {a, 1, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On Mathematica 10, the following should also work (haven't checked though):

```
Manipulate[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, a}], Inactive[Sin][a]}, {a, 1, 50}]
```