# How can my Manipulate be aware of a local variable inside a nested Module

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, scoping

I have 3 sets of 5 x-y points:

```
RandomInteger[10, {3, 5, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to display only one set of points at a time, and use a slider to move on to show the next set. This of course could be simply done with a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Module[{l},
  l = RandomInteger[10, {3, 5, 2}];
  ListPlot[l[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}]], {i, 1, 3, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, notice that I have to hard code the Manipulate parameter to have a maximum of 3 (the number of sets there is). To avoid hard-coding, I have to make the `Manipulate` aware of the `Length[l]` i.e. the number of sets there is). I just can't seem to find a way how to do so given that `l` was a variable local to only the `Module`.

---

**My question is**: how can I make my `Manipulate` aware of a local variable in my nested `Module`?

---

**PS**: I could of course nest the `Manipulate` within a `DynamicModule`, but I'm wondering if there's any straightforward way to achieve the same thing with the opposite nesting (`Module` inside `Manipulate`).

```
DynamicModule[{l},
 l = RandomInteger[10, {3, 5}];
 Manipulate[ListPlot[l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[l], 1}]]
```

Comment: is l = RandomInteger[10, {3, 5}] necessary to be inside Manipulate?

Comment: It's not in this simplified example I made up, but in reality, my `l` would be the end result of the computations in had performed in `Module`.

Comment: have you tried: Manipulate[
 ListPlot[l[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}], {i, 1, Length@l,
   1}] if l is defined outside Manipulate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do what you want. I would not use `Module`. Here are three, all of which use methods other than `Module` to localize variables:

```
SeedRandom @ 42;
With[{rand = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5, 2}]},
  Manipulate[
    ListPlot[rand[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}],
    {i, 1, Length[rand], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]

SeedRandom @ 42;
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[rand[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}],
  {i, 1, Length[rand], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Initialization -> (rand = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5, 2}])]

SeedRandom @ 42;
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[rand[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}],
  {{rand, RandomInteger[10, {5, 5, 2}]}, None},
  {i, 1, Length[rand], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

All give the result

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

if you need to keep the definition of l inside manipulate, I think you can try this

```
Manipulate[l = RandomInteger[10, {3, 5, 2}];
 ListPlot[l[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}], {i, 1, 
  Dynamic@Length@l, 1}]
```

you need to know that for every i, l will be computed again and again.
if you want to do 3 plot per each l then you can do it like this

```
Manipulate[l = RandomInteger[10, {3, 5, 2}];
 Dynamic@ListPlot[l[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}], {i, 1, 
  Dynamic@Length@l, 1}]
```

Comment: It is always a bad idea to have variable definition as part of the first argument to Manipulate. See my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56770/3066). The comment thread is relevant.