# Plot graphs in different colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am generating a set of plots and exploring how changing a parameter affects the plot shape.  I want each plot to be a different color, but the color rule i'm applying seems to only work for the last color in the list.  what is wrong with my syntax?

```
Vmorse[x_] = 
d*(Exp[-2 \[Alpha] (x - x0)] - 2 Exp[-\[Alpha] (x - x0)]);
morseSubsTest = {d -> 4.43, \[Alpha] -> {1.9, 1, 3}, x0 -> 1.13};

 Plot[Vmorse[x] /. morseSubsTest, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {-5, 0.5}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Morse Potential change alpha", 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
Plot[Evaluate@(Vmorse[x] /. morseSubsTest), {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 0.5}, PlotLabel -> "Morse Potential change alpha", 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

Comment: I can't find a question showing the differences between using `Evaluate[f[x]]` and the Option `Evaluated -> True` ... but it's out there. Who can find it?

Comment: @belisarius: This? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot