# Why does Plot only sometimes use different colors for each curve

Tags: plotting

In this example Plot does not color each curve differently:

```
Plot[{vx0 Sin[t], vy0 Cos[t]} /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

but in this example it does:

```
Plot[{vx0 Sin[t] /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}, 
vy0 Cos[t] /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

How do I automatically enable Mathematica to give a different color to each curve?

Comment: `Evaluate`?${}$

Comment: Mathematica guesses how many curves there are before the plot expression is evaluated.  In most cases, you can get the result you want by wrapping the expression with `Evaluate`

Comment: Evaluate works, is that the simplest solution? Why does it guess incorrectly in one case? It feels like excess coding just to plot two curves.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43323/plot-graphs-in-different-colors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compare the `FullForm` of your two inputs:

```
FullForm[Hold[Plot[{vx0 Sin[t], vy0 Cos[t]} /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}, {t, 0, 12}]]]
(* 
   Hold[Plot[ReplaceAll[List[Times[vx0,Sin[t]],Times[vy0,Cos[t]]],
   List[Rule[vy0,1],Rule[vx0,1]]],List[t,0,12]]]
*)

FullForm[Hold[Plot[{vx0 Sin[t] /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}, vy0 Cos[t] /.
  {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}}, {t, 0, 12}]]]
(*
    Hold[Plot[List[ReplaceAll[Times[vx0,Sin[t]],List[Rule[vy0,1],Rule[vx0,1]]],
   ReplaceAll[Times[vy0,Cos[t]],List[Rule[vy0,1],Rule[vx0,1]]]],List[t,0,12]]]
*)
```

For the second, the head of the first argument to `Plot` is `List`. When `Plot` sees this, it uses the length of the list as the number of colors to choose. For the first, the head is `ReplaceAll`. In this case, it doesn't anticipate that there will be more than one plot, so it only chooses one color.

`Evaluate` lets `ReplaceAll` do its job before `Plot` sees the argument. This yields a list, which allows plot to determine the number of colors to choose.

Answer (score 3):

See

- for an explanation of the general problem: [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)
- for this specific problem: [Plot graphs in different colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43323/plot-graphs-in-different-colors)
- for the differences below: [Using Evaluate and Evaluated -> True in Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot)

Note the difference if `t` has a value:

```
t = 2.;

Plot[{vx0 Sin[t], vy0 Cos[t]} /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}, {t, 0, 12}, 
 Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{vx0 Sin[t], vy0 Cos[t]} /. {vy0 -> 1, vx0 -> 1}], {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image]