# Create polynomials from Series

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

This question actually doesn't have quite a lot to do with the `Series` function, but I don't know how to describe my problem. So here's the thing.

I'm trying to plot function `f[x]` and its Maclaurin expansion together

```
ff[n_,x_] := Normal@Series[f[x],{x,0,n}]
```

But when I feed `ff` with an `x`, Mathematica always substitute the `x` in the expression with its actual value, which is not how `Series` works. So how could I hold the numerical value of `x` until `Series` finishes its calculation?

This problem always happens to me, though in different contexts, and I used to find ways around it, but this time I want to solve it in the correct way.

Comment: `f@x_:=Sin@x; Plot[{f[x], ff[#, x] & /@ Range@5}, {x, 0, Pi}, Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: @belisarius it quite confuses me: I did not tell Mathematica to hold anything, why do I have to tell it to evaluate? BTW your expression works well, even without specifically declaring `Evaluated` to be `True`, but when I write `Plot[ff[1,x], ... ]`, it doesn't work and I have to add `Evaluated -> True`. Either some deeper connection is eluding me, or Mathematica works in a truly mysterious way!

Comment: This may be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11772/193

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ff[n_,x_] := Normal@Series[f[x0],{x0,0,n}]  /. x0->x
```

or this is probably preferred since we dont want to reevaluate the `Series` for each `x`:

```
 f[x_] = Sin[x];
 ff[n_] := (Normal@Series[f[x0], {x0, 0, n}] /. x0 -> #) &;
```

note the usage then becomes `f[n][x]` :

```
 Show[{
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
     Plot[ff[#][x] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]}, 
           PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image]

### edit

as pointed out by @MichaelE2, the above does not in fact save us from revaluation of `Series` for every x. This does however:

```
 ff[n_Integer] := 
     ff[n] = Evaluate[(Normal@
         Series[f[\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 0, n}] /. \[FormalX] -> #)] &
```

Just to avoid completely stealing the code I used a formal character ( esc-$-x-esc )
rather than block protecting `x0`

```
 ff[6]
```

> ```
> #1 - #1^3/6 + #1^5/120 &
> ```

Comment: I think if you look at `ff[1]`, you'll see that `Series` is unevaluated (since `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`).  It will still get evaluated for each `x`.  I think you want something more sophisticated, like `ff[n_Integer] := ff[n] = Evaluate[Block[{x0}, (Normal@Series[f[x0], {x0, 0, n}] /. x0 -> #)]] &`

Comment: good catch, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    f[x_] := Sin[x];
ff[n_, x_] := Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}]];
Plot[Evaluate[ff[5, x]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Is it what you are after?

Comment: Could you explain to me, or give me some material about why `Evaluate` could work in this case? I'm afraid the Mathematical manual is not quite clear

Comment: Alex Su Yes, I can. If it does not plot where there is no reason for that, try Evaluate.

Comment: Well it feels like painting the rubik's cube. Fair enough

Answer (score 2):

With some "bells and whistles"

```
f[x_] = Sin[x];

ff[n_, x_] := Normal[Series[f[x], {x, 0, n}]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[Tooltip /@ {f[x], ff[n, x]}],
  {x, 0, \[Pi]},
  PlotLegends -> {
    ToString[f[x], TraditionalForm],
    "Polynomial\napproximation"}],
 {{n, 5, "Order of\npolynomial"}, 1, 20, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]