# How to Color each curve differently?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, legending, labeling

```
Plot[{{A0 E^(-k1 t), -((
     A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) + E^(k2 t)) k1)/(k1 - k2)), (
    A0 E^(-k1 t - 
      k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) k1 + E^(k1 t + k2 t) k1 + E^(k2 t) k2 - 
       E^(k1 t + k2 t) k2))/(k1 - k2)} /. {A0 -> 1, k1 -> 4, 
    k2 -> 10}}, {t, 2, 0}]
```

How may I color each curve differently?

Comment: Plot[Evaluate[{A0 E^(-k1 t), -((A0 E^(-k1 t-k2 t) (-E^(k1 t)+E^(k2 t)) k1)/(k1-k2)), (A0 E^(-k1 t-k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) k1+E^(k1 t+k2 t) k1+E^(k2 t) k2-E^(k1 t+k2 t) k2))/(k1-k2)} /. {A0->1, k1->4, k2->10}], {t, 2, 0}]

Comment: Or `Plot[...,Evaluated->True]`.

Answer (score 0):

For a verry nice Q & A see [Using Evaluate and Evaluated -> True in Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot)

```
Plot[{{A0 E^(-k1 t)
, -((A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) + E^(k2 t)) k1)/(k1 - k2))
, (A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) k1 + E^(k1 t + k2 t) k1 + E^(k2 t) 
k2 - E^(k1 t + k2 t) k2))/(k1 -k2)} /. {A0 -> 1, k1 -> 4, k2 -> 10}}
, {t, 2, 0}
, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{{A0 E^(-k1 t)
, -((A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) + E^(k2 t)) k1)/(k1 - k2))
, (A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) k1 + E^(k1 t + k2 t) k1 + E^(k2 t) 
k2 - E^(k1 t + k2 t) k2))/(k1 -k2)} /. {A0 -> 1, k1 -> 4, k2 -> 10}}
, {t, 2, 0}
, Evaluated -> True
, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

And contemplate the following:

```
A0 = 1; k1 = 4; k2 = 10;

Plot[{{A0 E^(-k1 t)
, -((A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) + E^(k2 t)) k1)/(k1 - k2))
, (A0 E^(-k1 t - k2 t) (-E^(k1 t) k1 + E^(k1 t + k2 t) k1 + E^(k2 t) 
k2 - E^(k1 t + k2 t) k2))/(k1 -k2)}}
, {t, 2, 0}]
```