# How do I plot multiple plots with recurring functions more efficiently?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, manipulate

I want to manipulate multiple plots with recurring functions, take for example:

```
Manipulate[Grid[{
   {Plot[f1 = a*Sin[k*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f2 = a*Cos[2 k*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1 + f2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1 + 2 f2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1 + 3 f2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}],
 {a, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}]
```

The functions of the last three plots are composed of the two functions in the first two plots (which I have named `f1` and `f2`). But when I evaluate in the above way the last three do not turn out correctly. They only do when I enter `f1` and `f2` in their complete forms, which I believe causes redundant repetitions of `f1` and `f2`, and takes an increasingly heavy toll whence I plot complicated functions. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: See [11772](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot), [6894](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here) and related questions. Basically, don't assign `f1` and `f2` inside `Plot` (or use `Evaluate`/`Evaluated->True` if you really need to)

Comment: @Mathe172 OK I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of f1 and f2 is wrong, it calculates once at the first. Let's defines them as functions:

```
f1 = #1*Sin[#2*#3] &;
f2 = #1*Cos[2 #1*#3] &;

Manipulate[Grid[{
   {Plot[f1[k, a, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f2[k, a, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1[k, a, x] + f2[k, a, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1[k, a, x] + 2 f2[k, a, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   {Plot[f1[k, a, x] + 3 f2[k, a, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}], {a, 0, 1}, {k,
   0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, thank you!