# Changes to StreamPlot in v11.1 breaking my code

Tags: plotting, evaluation, compatibility

The code below used to work nicely in 11.0:

```
ϕc[x_, y_, α_] = r^(Pi/α) Cos[Pi/α θ] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ -> ArcTan[x, y]};
StreamPlot[
  {D[ϕc[x, y, α], x], D[ϕc[x, y, α], y]} /. α -> Pi/2, {x, 0.001, 3}, {y, 0.001, 3}]
```

but in 11.1 the functions in `StreamPlot` get the values of `x` and `y` substituted in before the derivative is evaluated, with consequent `General::ivar: 0.0012142143 is not a valid variable` errors. I can do something like

```
ϕc[x_, y_, α_] = r^(Pi/α) Cos[Pi/α θ] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ -> ArcTan[x, y]};
f = D[ϕc[x, y, α], x] /. α -> Pi/2;
g = D[ϕc[x, y, α], y] /. α -> Pi/2;
StreamPlot[{f, g}, {x, 0.001, 3}, {y, 0.001, 3}]
```

Of course, but that's kind of clunky. Long story short, I think my question is how do I create "inline definitions" of the kind of functions I have in the example above?

P.S.: And why in all the world does Wolfram introduce substantial changes like that in a minor version update, or at all?

Comment: Try `StreamPlot[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][ϕc][x, y, π/2], Derivative[0, 1, 0][ϕc][x, y, π/2]}, {x, 0.001, 3}, {y, 0.001, 3}]`.

Comment: Use the option `Evaluated->True` to obtain the M11.0 behavior, or wrap the first argument in `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) suggests in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158981/changes-to-streamplot-in-v11-1-breaking-my-code#comment423335_158981), you should use the option `Evaluated->True` to reproduce the version 11.0 behavior, or wrap the first argument in `Evaluate`:

```
StreamPlot[
  {D[ϕc[x, y, α], x], D[ϕc[x, y, α], y]} /. α -> Pi/2, {x, 0.001, 3}, {y, 0.001, 3}, 
  Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image: plot]

```
StreamPlot[Evaluate[{D[ϕc[x, y, α], x], D[ϕc[x, y, α], y]} /. α -> Pi/2],
  {x, 0.001, 3}, {y, 0.001, 3}]
```

(output is the same).

The first method is recommended because [`Evaluated->True` localizes the variables during symbolic evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11774/280), as opposed to wrapping the first argument by `Evaluate`.