# Append vs AppendTo

Tags: evaluation

According to the documentation `AppendTo[s,elem]` is equivalent to `s = Append[s,elem]`.
But then

`y = {}; Plot[y = Append[y, x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}]`

works as intended, while

`y = {}; Plot[AppendTo[y, x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}]`

produces the error message

> AppendTo::rvalue: {[Pi]/4} is not a variable with a value, so its
> value cannot be changed.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 8):

It is an evaluation issues. I can't pin the exact sequence now, but here is a workaround

```
y = {}; 
Plot[AppendTo[y, x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}, Evaluated -> False]
y
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which now gives the same exact output as

```
y = {}; 
Plot[y = Append[y, x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}]
```

You can see this answer [using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/using-evaluate-and-evaluated-true-in-plot) for more information about what `Evaluated` do.

Comment: You can also do `Plot[AppendTo[Unevaluated@y,x];...]`