# Copying one symbol into another

Tags: code-review, upvalues

I would like to know how can I completely copy one Symbol to another. When I say copy, a refer to `UpValues`, `DownValues`, `FormatValues`.. and so on.

I created this function to do that, but I don't know if it's a good practice.

```
SetAttributes[copy,HoldFirst];
copy[new_Symbol,org_Symbol]:=Module[{},
    ClearAll@new;
    UpValues@new=UpValues@org/.org:> new;
    DownValues@new=DownValues@org/.org:> new;
    FormatValues@new=FormatValues@org/.org:> new;
    SetAttributes[new,Attributes[org]];
]
```

So I can copy some symbol `b` into `a` using `a~copy~b`.

There is a simpler way to do that? Or this approach is ok?

---

**Update**

Thanks for all comments. This is the evolution of the function above:

```
SetAttributes[copy,HoldFirst];
new_~copy~org_:=With[{prop={Attributes,UpValues, OwnValues, DownValues, SubValues, NValues, FormatValues, Messages,Options}},
    ClearAll@new;
    Set[#@new,#@org/.HoldPattern@org:>new]&~Scan~prop;
]
```

Comment: Do you have a good use case for this?  Or is it just theoretical?

Comment: There's some `clone` function of Leonid around, that does basically this. Don't forget Options, NValues, OwnValues, SubValues, Defaults. And make it HoldAll

Comment: Also, you can't trust this for built-ins, some of which seem to have "hidden" values, or for ReadProtected and Locked symbols, or for symbols that are recognized as special by other functions

Comment: There's a subtlety: if `org` refers to `org` in its definition, will `new` keep referring to `org` or to `new`?

Comment: In other words, I wouldn't trust this too much unless you know the function you are cloning. And I don't know a better way to copy a symbol

Comment: Those replacements are risky too. For starters, wrap org in HoldPattern at least

Comment: @Rojo, you are right. If I have the symbol `org` in the RHS of `org` I'll have a problem in the way I did.

Comment: @Rojo [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580284) might be the post you're looking for

Comment: @rm-rf, exactly, but I stopped looking for it after seing the post you were too late to post

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I have a good use. I'm working on a function to retrieve database tables in the form of objects. The properties of this object are in down and upvalues of the symbol, and a need to copy it between functions in my code.

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update**  It turns out that the correct way is to use `ExtendedDefinition`, not `ExtendedFullDefinition`.  Please see [the answer by @jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/68872/12) for a detailed explanation.

---

This is a simplification of your solution:

```
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[new] = 
 Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[old] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new
```

I believe `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` is used in transferring definitions between the main kernel and subkernels.  Also note the `HoldPattern` on the LHS of the rule which ensures that `OwnValues` will work.

---

One thing to think about is: what should happen if `old` refers back to itself?  Should `new` keep referring to `old`, or to itself?  This solution, like yours, replaces the `old` in the definition as well.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could assign to that +1

Comment: @Rojo I learned about it from Oleksandr.  I'm not sure if anything can go wrong with this ... check the `Options`.  As I said, it's meant to be used for transferring definitions to subkernels, and for some contexts this should be prevented.

Comment: Wow, much more simpler!! Tks! I have to think about the  "old to itsef" question. I Don't know yet the best to my case. +1

Comment: Damn... I just came here to write this! Of course, I learned this from you, so it's right that you got to post it :)

Comment: Does this method properly preserve `Unevaluated`, which is lost in a regular `DownValues` call?  I am talking about issue described in [Leonid's comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/does-set-vs-setdelayed-have-any-effect-after-the-definition-was-done#comment18019_6348) and the linked Q&A.  (I cannot test it because this function is not in version 7.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it does seem to preserve it.

Comment: Something doesn't go well with symbols defined in packages. Even for a public symbol with full context specified, `Language\`ExtendedFullDefinition[symbolFromPackage]` and `Language\`ExtendedFullDefinition[application\`package\`symbolFromPackage]` both evaluate to `Language\`DefinitionList[]`.

Comment: @Akater ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` has an `ExcludedContexts` option.  Check if it's what's blocking the context of the package you want to use.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it was blocking all user contexts, and lots of built-in ones, as well. It works now, thank you.

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there a particular reason to use ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` instead of ``Language`ExtendedDefinition``? Presented version with `ExtendedFullDefinition` can be dangerous. If `old` symbol depends on `anotherSymbol`, then definition of `anotherSymbol` will be present in `DefinitionList` given by `ExtendedFullDefinition`. If `anotherSymbol` has `old` symbol anywhere in its `...Values`, then assignment from answer will permanently change definition of `anotherSymbol`. Using `ExtendedDefinition` instead of `ExtendedFullDefinition` will prevent it.

Comment: @jkuczm These are undocumented symbols, and much of what I wrote was based on guessing.  It sounds like you are likely correct, but I do not have time to test this and update my post today.  Perhaps you could write another answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok I'll add an answer explaining dangers associated with `ExtendedFullDefinition`.

Comment: Thanks @jkuczm, that will be useful to everyone.

Comment: It looks like somebody has added something this to the Function Repository as ```ResourceFunction["CopyDefinitions"]```.

Answer (score 18):

Adding to [Szabolcs's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/copying-one-symbol-into-another/19903#19903), it's better to use `ExtendedDefinition` instead of `ExtendedFullDefinition`.

In situation in which `old` symbol (the one that we want to copy), depends on `anotherSymbol` and `anotherSymbol` has `old` symbol somewhere in it's `...Values` e.g.:

```
ClearAll[new, old, anotherSymbol]
old = anotherSymbol
anotherSymbol[] := 2 old
```

Full definition of `old` includes definition of `anotherSymbol`:

```
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[old]
(* Language`DefinitionList[
    old -> {
        OwnValues -> HoldPattern[old] :> anotherSymbol, SubValues -> {},
        UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {},
        DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    },
    anotherSymbol -> {
        OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {},
        DownValues -> {HoldPattern[anotherSymbol[]] :> 2 old},
        NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {},
        Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    }
] *)
```

Assignment using `ExtendedFullDefinition`:

```
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[new] =
    Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[old] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new
(* Language`DefinitionList[
    new -> {
        OwnValues -> HoldPattern[new] :> anotherSymbol, SubValues -> {},
        UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {},
        DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    },
    anotherSymbol -> {
        OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {},
        DownValues -> {HoldPattern[anotherSymbol[]] :> 2 new},
        NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {},
        Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    }
] *)
```

has a side effect. As we can see above, rule `HoldPattern[old] :> new` changes not only possible self references of `old`, discussed in Szabolcs's answer, but also references to `old` in definition of `anotherSymbol`.

By evaluating above assignment we have changed definition of `anotherSymbol`:

```
?? anotherSymbol
(* Global`anotherSymbol
anotherSymbol[]:=2 new *)
```

`` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``, in contrast to "Full" variant, returns and assigns only definition of symbol passed to it as argument.

```
ClearAll[new, old, anotherSymbol]
old = anotherSymbol
anotherSymbol[] := 2 old

Language`ExtendedDefinition[old]
(* Language`DefinitionList[
    old -> {
        OwnValues -> HoldPattern[old] :> anotherSymbol, SubValues -> {},
        UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {},
        DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    }
] *)
```

Assignment to `ExtendedDefinition`:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[new] = 
    Language`ExtendedDefinition[old] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new
(* Language`DefinitionList[
    new -> {
        OwnValues -> HoldPattern[new] :> anotherSymbol, SubValues -> {},
        UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {},
        DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}
    }
] *)
```

is free of side effect of `ExtendedFullDefinition`:

```
?? anotherSymbol
(* Global`anotherSymbol
anotherSymbol[]:=2 old *)
```

and of course correctly copies definition of `old` to `new`:

```
?? new
(* Global`new
new=anotherSymbol *)
```

Comment: Tks. Very interesting. +1