# DynamicModule variables that retain values during code reloading

Tags: front-end, dynamic

At times I'll find myself building a some interface component where I want to have some localized dynamic variables, and while testing I might realize that some bit of the code needs to change, which means I lose the current state of all the localized variables, some which might be bothersome to set once again. In such case my typical solution is something like:

```
DynamicModule[{
  persistant = 21,
  transient = 2},
      Column[{
          InputField[Dynamic[persistant]],
          InputField[Dynamic[transient]],
          Dynamic[persistant*transient],
      }],
  Deinitialization :> (saveVar = persistant),
  Initialization :> (FinishDynamic[]; If[ValueQ[saveVar], persistant = saveVar])
]
```

Which will retain the value of `persistant` even if I rerun the code. However if you have a bunch of variables that you want to retain it becomes bothersome to save each and everyoen and reload them, and what more you might want to save `DownValues` as well as `OwnValues` so I thought that I'd make a bit more general solution using `DumpSave` or `Save` to save definitions and load them in using `Get`:

```
Deinitialization :> (If[FileExistsQ["tempfile"], DeleteFile["tempfile"]];
       Save["tempfile", {persistant}]),
Initialization :> (FinishDynamic[]; If[FileExistsQ["tempfile"], get["tempfile"]])
```

But when trying this I've run into problems since the names that are saved are the local temporary names eg. `FE`persistant$$161`instead of just`persistant` which means the values aren't loaded back again correctly. So my question is whether theres either another way to achieve a similar result or if the naming problem can be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by reading the saved symbol and [copying it to the new one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19903/1517)

Below I define `copySymbol` that copies the definition of a symbol to another and making sure that the `FE` context is not excluded.

`saveSymbol` `Save`s a given symbol in `$TemporaryDirectory`, for instance `FE'abc$123` is saved as `MMAsave_abc_FE'abc$123` (read ' as `)

`readSymbol` takes a name and a destination symbol, and `Get`s the corresponding definition and copies it to the destination symbol, with some trickery to avoid evaluation of `OwnValues` along the way. By looking at the last part of the filename it knows which symbol to copy.

`removeSymbol` takes a name as argument and removes everything in `$TemporaryDirectory` that begins with `"MMAsave_"<>name<>"_"` to help remove all old definitions.

```
ClearAll[copySymbol, saveSymbol, readSymbol];
Attributes[copySymbol] = HoldAll;
copySymbol[old_ /; Head[old] =!= Hold, new_] := (
  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[new] = 
   Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[old, "ExcludedContexts" -> 
      DeleteCases[
       OptionValue[Language`ExtendedFullDefinition, "ExcludedContexts"],
       "FE"]] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new)

Attributes[saveSymbol] = {HoldFirst};
SavePrefix = FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "MMAsave_"};
saveSymbol[sym_] := With[
  {name = StringReplace[SymbolName[Unevaluated[sym]], 
     name_ ~~ "$" ~~ ___ :> name]},
  Save[SavePrefix <> name <> "_" <> Context[sym] <> 
       SymbolName[Unevaluated[sym]], sym]]

Attributes[readSymbol] = {HoldAll};
readSymbol[name_String, dest_Symbol] := Block[{
   file = First@FileNames[SavePrefix <> name <> "_*"],symname},
  symname = StringReplace[file, 
    SavePrefix ~~ name ~~ "_" ~~ symname_ :> symname];
  Get[file];
  With[{old = ToExpression[symname, InputForm, Hold]},
   copySymbol[old, dest] /. 
    HoldPattern[copySymbol[Hold[a_], b_]] :> copySymbol[a, b]
   ]]

removeSymbol[name_String] := DeleteFile@FileNames[SavePrefix <> name <> "_*"];
savedSymbolQ[name_] := Length[FileNames[SavePrefix <> name <> "_*"]] != 0
```

It can be used as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{persistent = 21, transient = 2}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[persistent]], 
   InputField[Dynamic[transient]], Dynamic[persistent*transient]}],
 Deinitialization :> (removeSymbol["persistent"]; saveSymbol[persistent]), 
 Initialization :> (FinishDynamic[]; 
   If[savedSymbolQ["persistent"], readSymbol["persistent", persistent]])]
```