# Creating new functions using the names of existing ones

Tags: function-construction

I have a list of functions

```
  {G[x_, y_], F[x_, y_], C[x_, y_]}
```

how I can create the list of new functions such as

```
  {dG[x_, y_], dF[x_, y_], dC[x_, y_]}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems you don't care what people ask. You've not responded to the comments from your previous question. And you are using capital letters again...

Comment: `{g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]} /. 
 x : (g | f | c) :> Symbol[StringJoin["d", SymbolName[x]]]`?

Comment: @Kuba Sorry! Previous question was solved and closed

Comment: So `C` is not built-in anymore?

Comment: @kguler Here you explicitly list the functions names (g | f | c) I would like to avoid this and just add some symbol like "d" or any other to the functions names

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков, pls see the updated answer.

Comment: [This maybe?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** My original answer renames the functions in the input list. The following creates new function names:

```
ClearAll[funcNamesF];
funcNamesF[funcs : {_[___] ..}, pre_String: "d", post_String: ""] := 
 Module[{newnames = Symbol[pre <> SymbolName[#] <> post] & /@ Head /@ funcs, nf = funcs}, 
 nf[[All, 0]] = newnames; {newnames, nf}];

funcs = {g[x_, y_], g[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]};
{funcs, funcNamesF[funcs, "zX", "Z"]}
(*{g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]}, 
  {{zXgZ, zXfZ, zXcZ}, 
   {zXgZ[x_, y_], zXfZ[x_, y_], zXcZ[x_, y_]}}}*)


funcNamesF[funcs, "zX", "Z"][[1]] (* names only *)
(*  {zXgZ, zXfZ, zXcZ} *)

funcNamesF[funcs, "zX", "Z"][[2]] (* LHSs for the new function definitions *)
(* {zXgZ[x_, y_], zXfZ[x_, y_], zXcZ[x_, y_]}} *)
```

---

```
funcs = {g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]} 
(* {g[x_,y_],f[x_,y_],g[x_,y_]} *)

newnames = {df, dg, dc};
funcs[[All, 0]] = newnames;
funcs
(* {dg[x_,y_],df[x_,y_],dc[x_,y_]} *)
```

or

```
funcs = {g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]} ;
newnames2 = Symbol["d" <> SymbolName[#]] & /@ Head /@ funcs;
funcs[[All, 0]] = newnames2;
funcs
```

or

```
funcs = {G[x_, y_], F[x_, y_], C[x_, y_]};
funcs /. x : (Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcs) :> Symbol["d" <> SymbolName[x]]
```

or (thanks: @Kuba)

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@funcs, x_ ~~ "[" :> "d" <> x <> "["]
```

Comment: Since OP does not care to add the context you may want to add another method: `ToExpression@
 StringReplace["{G[x_,y_],F[x_,y_],C[x_,y_]}", 
  x_ ~~ "[" :> "d" <> x <> "["]` :)

Comment: @Kuba, much nicer (as always:))

Comment: @kguler I would like to create another set to functions instead to rename the existing one. But thank you anyway just answering my stupid questions without context :) !

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков, hope the updated answer works...

Comment: @kguler Thank you!