# Wrongly assigning a value to an expression

Tags: assignment, downvalues

Sometimes I misstype an equality and I write an assignment instead.

For example, if I write

```
f'[x] = 2
```

instead of an equation, `f'[x] == 2`, it seems that the expression `f'[x]` now works as a variable which stores the value `2`. And in fact,

```
f'[x] // FullForm
(* 2 *)
```

I can undo this by unsetting the assignment,

```
f'[x] =. ;

f'[x]
(* f'[x] *)
```

But I do not understand how and where this value is stored.

If I write

```
f[x] = 2;
```

I know that `f` gets a downvalue for when evaluated at `x`, but in the case of `f'[x]` I do not understand, is it modifying the definition of `Derivative`?

Comment: Related: [(40314)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/121).  Actually halirutan's answer to that question makes this seem like a duplicate, but I don't want to cast a binding vote on it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will be associated to `Derivative`. The basic way to check this is to look at the definition of `Derivative`:

```
?? Derivative
```

This won't show anything about `f`, but it will show that `Derivative` has the [`ReadProtected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadProtected.html) attribute.  This prevents the definitions from being printed.  It also shows that `Derivative` does not have the `Protected` attribute, which is a big hint that its definitions can be easily changed.

So let us remove `ReadProtected`,

```
ClearAttributes[Derivative, ReadProtected]
```

and check again

```
??Derivative
```

Now you can see the definition.

---

As @Kuba said, there is a more convenient undocumented way (since version 10) that works without needing to remove attributes:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`

PrintDefinitions[Derivative]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of `f'[x]`:

```
f'[x] // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> ```
> Derivative[1][f][x]
> ```

If we make a definition on a similar object with a substitution for `Derivative`, the rule is bound to that substitution:

```
foo[1][f][x] = 5;

? foo
```

> ```
> Global`foo
>
> foo[1][f][x]=5
> ```

More specifically it appears in the [`SubValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121) list:

```
SubValues[foo]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[foo[1][f][x]] :> 5}
> ```

That itself could be found with:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[foo]
```

> ```
> Language`DefinitionList[
>  foo -> {OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {HoldPattern[foo[1][f][x]] -> 5}, 
>    UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, 
>    DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}}]
> ```

Reference: [Copying one symbol into another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/121#19903)

Exactly the same evaluation is followed for your case, and indeed the rule is found in:

```
f'[x] = 2;

SubValues[Derivative]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[Derivative[1][f][x]] :> 2, . . . }
> ```

My point is other than the parsing of `f'[x]` into `Derivative[1][f][x]` no special behavior is observed here.