# Problem with labeled functions and ParallelEvaluate

Tags: bugs, parallelization

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 13.0.1**

---

I came across behaviour of `ParallelEvaluate` that I do not understand.
In a loop I define five functions labelled with 1,2,....

```
imax = 5;
Do[(myfunc[i] := $KernelID), {i, imax}]; (* On purpose not myfunc[i_] *)
```

Executing

```
ParallelEvaluate[{myfunc[1], $KernelID}]
```

returns

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, 
 {9, 9}, {10, 10}, {11, 11}, {12, 12}, {13, 13}, {14, 14}, {15, 15}, 
 {16,16}}
```

As expected, both parts of the expression `{myfunc[1], $KernelID}` were executed on the sixteen available subkernels. This works like this up to `imax=17` on my machine (Windows Server 64 bit. Mathematica 13.01). But then...

```
Clear[myfunc];
imax = 18; (*or larger*)
Do[(myfunc[i] := $KernelID), {i, imax}]; (* On purpose not myfunc[i_].*)
ParallelEvaluate[{myfunc[1], $KernelID}]
```

returns

```
{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 6}, {0, 7}, {0, 8},
 {0, 9}, {0, 10}, {0, 11}, {0, 12}, {0, 13}, {0, 14}, {0, 15}, {0, 16}}
```

`myfunc[1]` is always executed on kernel 0, i.e., on the main kernel attributed to the notebook. Only the second part of `{myfunc[1], $KernelID}` is excecuted on the subkernels.
Is this expected?

Instead of integer I can also use strings as labels like:

```
f["a"]:=$KernelID; f["b"]:=$KernelID; ...
```

I get the same problem. I would like to define more than 17 labelled functions and execute anyone of them in parallel on all subkernels. Is the number of labelled functions and the number of kernels somehow connected?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov unfortunately, I can't recall whether I reported it. Might be worth to simply report it again anyway, since that should push it up on their priority list if they see that more people are running into this.

Comment: @LukasLang Certainly. I'm surprised that such annoying and simple-to-fix bug persists at least from version 8. Probably too little reports. I'll report it with a link to your answer.

Comment: @LukasLang Reported as [CASE:4938187].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce the issue on Windows 10 Pro x64 with *Mathematica* 13.0.1, 12.3.1 and 8.0.4. My laptop has only 4 physical cores, but the "special" number is also 18.

Looks like it is an evaluation leak in `DistributeDefinitions`:

```
Clear[myfunc];
imax = 18; i = 0;
Do[(myfunc[i] := Echo[{++i, $KernelID}]), {i, imax}];

DistributeDefinitions[myfunc];
```

[image: screenshot]

`Echo` is printed 36 times. Hence every definition is evaluated twice in the main kernel. It is a bug, please report it to the support.

As a workaround I can suggest creating definitions in the parallel kernels without using `DistributeDefinitions`:

```
ParallelEvaluate[imax = 18; Do[(myfunc[i] := $KernelID), {i, imax}];, DistributedContexts -> None];
ParallelEvaluate[{myfunc[1], $KernelID}, DistributedContexts -> None]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

Another workaround is to copy `DownValues` from the main kernel to subkernels manually:

```
imax = 18; Do[(myfunc[i] := $KernelID), {i, imax}];
With[{downValues = DownValues[myfunc]}, 
  ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[myfunc] = downValues, DistributedContexts -> None]];
ParallelEvaluate[{myfunc[1], $KernelID}, DistributedContexts -> None]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

If the situation is more complicated, and the `Symbol` to distribute contains different kinds of `*Values`, one can use undocumented [`` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` and `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/280) for copying them all at once.

Also related:

- [`ResourceFunction["CopyDefinitions"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CopyDefinitions)
- [`ResourceFunction["DefinitionData"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DefinitionData)
- [`ResourceFunction["CompressWithDefinitions"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CompressWithDefinitions).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! Yes, also in my opinion this is bug. Following your suggestion I reported it today to support@wolfram.com .

Comment: Thank you also for the workaround. However, for my real case this is not very elegant. I have a large notebook for analysing experimental data sets. Each data set gets a label like: "Experiment1",... And I define functions like setup["Experiment1"]:=(SetDirectory["experiment1location"];...) These functions are defined in different  places of the notebook. I could manually wrap around   ParallelEvaluate for all these definition, but then these functions are not defined for the main kernel. So, I would need to  define them twice, I suppose.

Comment: @dnet I've added another method which should fit your purposes better.

Comment: @dnet Thank you for reporting!

Comment: Great! I did not know about DownValues. Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the bug is still persistent in 13.1