# Replacement inside held expression

Tags: evaluation, replacement, expression-manipulation, hold, faq

I wish to make a replacement inside a held expression:

```
f[x_Real] := x^2;
Hold[{2., 3.}] /. n_Real :> f[n]
```

The desired output is `Hold[{4., 9.}]`, but I get `Hold[{f[2.], f[3.]}]` instead. What is the best way to make such a replacement without evaluation of the held expression?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Generally, you want the  [Trott-Strzebonski](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/) in-place evaluation technique:

```
f[x_Real]:=x^2;
Hold[{Hold[2.],Hold[3.]}]/.n_Real:>With[{eval = f[n]},eval/;True]

(* Hold[{Hold[4.],Hold[9.]}] *)
```

It will inject the evaluated r.h.s. into an arbitrarily deep location in the held expression, where the expression was found that matched the rule pattern. This is in contrast with `Evaluate`, which is only effective on the first level inside `Hold` (won't work in the example above). Note that you may evaluate some things and not evaluate others:

```
g[x_] := x^3;
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = f[n]}, g[eval] /; True]

(* Hold[{Hold[g[4.]], Hold[g[9.]]}] *)
```

The basic idea is to exploit the semantics of rules with local variables shared between the body of `With` and the condition, but within the context of local rules. The `eval` variable will be evaluated first (*regardless of whether the condition ends up being `True` - as in this case, or `False` - thanks to [@luyuwuli](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6468/luyuwuli) for pointing out the problem in the original wording for this part*) , inside the declaration part of `With`, while the code inside the `Condition` , here the body of `With`  (`g[eval]`), is treated then as normally the r.h.s. of `RuleDelayed` is. It is important that `With` is used, since it can inject into unevaluated expressions. `Module` and `Block` also have the shared variable semantics, but wouldn't work here: while their declaration part would evaluate, they would not be able to communicate that result to their body that remains unevaluated (more precisely, only the part of the body that is inside `Condition` will remain unevaluated - see below). The body of `With` above was not evaluated either, however `With` injects the evaluated part ( `eval` here) into it - this is why the g function above remained unevaluated when the rule applied. This can be further illustrated by the following:

```
Hold[{Hold[2.],Hold[3.]}]/.n_Real:>Module[{eval=f[n]},
   With[{eval = eval},g[eval]/;True]]

(* Hold[{Hold[g[4.]],Hold[g[9.]]}] *)
```

Note b.t.w. that only the part of code inside `With` that is inside `Condition` is considered a part of the "composite rule" and therefore not evaluated. So,

```
Hold[{Hold[2.],Hold[3.]}]/.n_Real:>Module[{eval = f[n]},
    With[{eval = eval},Print[eval];g[eval]/;True]]

(* print: 4. *)
(* print: 9. *)
(* Hold[{Hold[g[4.]],Hold[g[9.]]}] *)
```

But

```
Hold[{Hold[2.],Hold[3.]}]/.n_Real:>Module[{eval = f[n]},
   With[{eval = eval},(Print[eval];g[eval])/;True]]

(* Hold[{Hold[Print[4.];g[4.]],Hold[Print[9.];g[9.]]}] *)
```

This should further clarify this mechanism.

Comment: The Trott-Strzebonski method looks a bit magical. Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: @Alexey I updated my post with some explanation. It may not be completely satisfactory, but this is how I think of it currently.

Comment: Why `Condition` inside `With` forces evaluation not only `With` (with except to the `Condition`) but also enclosing `Module`? Without the `Condition` the r.h.s of the rule stay completely unevaluated.

Comment: @Alexey For the same reason as when you define a global function as `f[x_]:=Module[{var = x^2},With[{var = var},Hold[var]/;var>10]]`.  What happens is that everything in the enclosing scoping constructs that does not go into `Condition` gets evaluated - this is needed to compute the result of test in `Condition`. The semantics of rules with shared local variables is different from the standard rule-substitution semantics, this is what makes all these things possible. The further non-triviality of Trott-Strzebonski technique is that local rules are used, so all expression levels are accessible.

Comment: @Leonid, can you please add this to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag ?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure I will. I will collect a few more related useful things and then post it there, within a couple of days.

Comment: This trick also came up in the question [Evaluating only particular Head type in expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4251036/421225)

Comment: @Simon Indeed. This was before my time on SO :)

Comment: +1 The Trott-Strzebonski technique appears to be the officially sanctioned solution.  You may have some academic interest in my response which discusses a technique involving the unofficial, unsupported symbol `RuleCondition`.

Comment: @WReach Thanks, very nice indeed. I discussed `RuleCondition` here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition/5869885#5869885, but it did not occur to me to try using it here. Nice finding!

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand it correctly, but my experiment doesn't agree with this conclusion,"Since the condition is True, it forced the `eval` variable to be evaluated inside the __declaration__ part of `With`" e.g. `Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = (Print["!"]; f[n])}, g[eval] /; False]` will always print `!` even though the condition is False.

Comment: @luyuwuli You are right, this has been the wrong choice of words, and that sentence was actually misleading. The part inside declaration is evaluated in any case, since in general it is needed for the condition check. Whether the condition ends up being `True` or `False`, decides whether the rule is considered at the end as applicable or not, by the pattern matcher. I have edited the post to address this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Glad I can help:) BTW, I always learn a lot after rereading your posts.

Comment: @luyuwuli Thanks. Sometimes I also learn a lot from rereading my posts :)  (I obviously learn a lot from (re)reading posts of others, too, but that's probably less surprising).

Comment: I wonder if this [`ResourceFunction["Inline"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Inline/) is an implementation of the famous trick? If not, does it achieve the same objectives?

Comment: @Gravifer Well, you can check for yourself, the source of all WFRs is available. I frankly don't have the time to check right now.

Answer (score 87):

`RuleCondition` provides an undocumented, but very convenient, way to make replacements in held expressions.  For example, if we want to square the odd integers in a held list:

```
Hold[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] /. n_Integer :> RuleCondition[n^2, OddQ[n]]
(* Hold[{1, 2, 9, 4, 25}] *)
```

`RuleCondition` differs from `Condition` in that the replacement expression is evaluated before it is substituted.  The second argument of `RuleCondition` may be omitted, defaulting to `True`:

```
Hold[{2., 3.}] /. n_Real :> RuleCondition[n^2]
(* Hold[{4., 9.}] *)
```

It is very unfortunate that `RuleCondition` has remained undocumented for so long, given its extreme usefulness.  The Trott-Strzebonski trick discussed in @Leonid's answer is one way to achieve the same result using only documented symbols:

```
Hold[{2., 3.}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = n^2}, eval /; True]
(* Hold[{4., 9.}] *)
```

A slightly less verbose technique uses `Block`:

```
Hold[{2., 3.}] /. n_Real :> Block[{}, n^2 /; True]
(* Hold[{4., 9.}] *)
```

Judicious use of `Trace` reveals that both of these techniques ultimately resolve to `RuleCondition`.  One must make up one's mind whether it is better to use the undocumented `RuleCondition` or rely upon implementation artifacts in `With` and `Block`.  I suspect that the behaviour is unlikely to change in all three cases as so much *Mathematica* code depends upon the existing behaviour.

Comment: Great analysis! It is unbelievable that WRI [had published the Trott-Strzebonski trick](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html) but still hide this convenient function! Unbelievable but true...

Comment: @Alexey I think that Leonid's response better qualifies as the accepted answer as the Trott-Strzebonski trick seems to be as close as one is going to come to an officially sanctioned technique.  I discuss `RuleCondition` mainly out of academic interest.

Comment: Well. But `RuleCondition` is really straightforward and includes no magic and as you mentioned the Trott-Strzebonski trick relies on this function too. Probably we can use `RuleCondition` without risk.

Answer (score 29):

Although less magical, it can be done by `ReplacePart`

```
expr = Hold[{2, 3, 4, 5}]
pos = Position[expr, _Integer]
newparts = Extract[expr, pos] /. n_Integer :> n^2
ReplacePart[expr, Thread[pos -> newparts]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on solutions proposed by @Leonid and @WReach I have noticed something peculiar with the use of `Block` and `With` for the `Trott-Strzebonski` solution.

Consider the following code:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := x^3;

Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
Print[eval]; eval /; True
]
```

this will yield:

```
(* 
64.
729.
Hold[{Hold[64.], Hold[729.]}]
*)
```

using `Block` will give the same result as above.

```
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> Block[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
Print@eval; eval /; True
]

(* 
64.
729.
Hold[{Hold[64.], Hold[729.]}]
*)
```

However, things become strange - as @Leonid pointed out - with the use of Composite expression in `Condition`:

using `With` prevents the evaluation of `Print`

```
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
(Print[eval]; eval) /; True
]

(* Hold[{Hold[Print[64.]; 64.], Hold[Print[729.]; 729.]}] *)
```

However, with the use of `Block` the Print statements get evaluated

```
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> Block[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
(Print@eval; eval) /; True
] 

(* 
64.
729.
Hold[{Hold[64.], Hold[729.]}]
*)
```

Now one begins to wonder how `RuleCondition` - as mentioned by @WReach - will behave with Composite expression

```
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> RuleCondition[Print[(g@*f)[n]]; (g@*f)[n]]

(* 
64.
729.
Hold[{Hold[64.], Hold[729.]}]
*)
```

It turns out that `RuleCondition` behaves in a similar way to `Block`

So perhaps not a million dollar but a $5 question: **Which one to use (Block, RuleCondition or With)?**

In my opinion both have their own advantages. For instance, `With` will allow you to evaluate a part of the expression and at the same time inject unevaluated code in the substitution process.

**`With` will enable code injection**

```
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> With[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
(g[eval]; eval) /; True
]
(* Hold[{Hold[g[64.]; 64.], Hold[g[729.]; 729.]}] *)
```

In the example above (in spirit with what @Leonid mentioned) we substituted the `Reals` and also injected code that remained unevaluated i.e. `g[64]` and `g[729]`

**`Block` and `RuleCondition` together with `Sow` and `Reap`**

However, if the goal is to evaluate some code while making substitution 'Block` can be quite effective:

```
Reap[Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> Block[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
  (Sow[PrimeQ@eval]; eval) /; True
  ]][[2, 1]]
];
(* {False,False} *)


Reap[
 Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.]}] /. n_Real :> Block[{eval = (g@*f)[n]},
 (Sow[EvenQ[Round@eval]]; eval) /; True]
]
(* {Hold[{Hold[64.], Hold[729.]}], {{True, False}}} *)
```

In the example above we could the result whether `eval` generates a Prime whenever the substitution is made. Likewise, this can be achieved using `RuleCondition`.

Comment: Also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5866016/590388). Note that `With` doesn't evaluate its second argument at all (it becomes evaluated after leaving `With`), while `Block` evaluates it. This helps to understand the difference you describe.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks for pointing me to it !

Answer (score 1):

Trott-Strzebonski is great, but there is a case when some additional trick is required. At least I couldn't figure this out any other way...

Consider this slightly silly example. You have some expression/association/data structure etc. containing some code with side-effects or undesirable evaluation (basically anything that is ValueQ).

```
code = <|a :> Echo[1], b :> 1 + 2|>
```

So the only safe way to extract it is to use extra head argument to `Lookup` with Hold.

```
Lookup[code, a, None, Hold]
(* Hold[Echo[1]] *)
```

Or any other head with `HoldAll`. And there are other functions with the head argument exist for this exact purpose, another example would be `Extract` and `ToExpression`.

The goal is to insert values from `code` into another held expression based on keys without evaluating anything, like here:

```
expr = Hold[b, a + b]
...
(* Hold[1 + 2, Echo[1] + (1 + 2)]*)
```

Applying Trott-Strzebonski naively trying `Unevaluated` doesn't quite get there:

```
Hold[b, a + b] /. key_ /; KeyExistsQ[code, key] :> 
  With[{y = Unevaluated @@ Lookup[code, key, None, Hold]}, y /; True]

(* Hold[Unevaluated[1 + 2], Unevaluated[Echo[1]] + Unevaluated[1 + 2]] *)
```

One can use `Position` + `Extract` + `ReplacePart` here of course with some convoluted expression handling to make delayed rules for `ReplacePart`:

```
pos = Position[expr, key_ /; KeyExistsQ[code,key]]
With[{newparts = Flatten[Hold @@ (Lookup[code, #, None, Hold] & @@@ Extract[expr, pos, Hold])]},
  ReplacePart[expr, List @@ Thread[Hold @@ pos :> newparts, Hold]]
]
```

But here is another trick:

```
Hold[b, a + b] /. key_ /; KeyExistsQ[code, key] :> With[{
    bind = Function[Null, Unevaluated[{y := #}], HoldAll] @@
        Lookup[code, key, None, Hold]
},
    With[bind, y /; True]
]
```

The idea is to make a delayed unevaluated binding and then use Trott-Strzebonski with it!

I'm quite surprised it works, I figured it out recently myself and it doesn't seem to work with `RuleCondition` for some reason too.

One more extra note:  instead of `Function[Null, ..., HoldAll]`, `` GeneralUtilities`HoldFunction `` can be useful.

---

Just realized how silly this particular example is because association already provides you with the rules and one can just do:

```
expr /. code
```

But if the `code` was instead something like `Hold[Echo[1], 1 + 2]` and a procedure of extracting subcode from it depended on LHS of a rule and `Extract[code, ...]` in a much more complicated fashion, then this trick would still work.