# How to automatically put the part of a variable name after the first letter in symbolized subscripts?

Tags: front-end, programming, notebooks, subscript

So here is what I have thought:

Use `ToString` and `StringLength` in order to get the number of characters in the variable name.

If it is bigger than one, change variable name by putting everything but the first character as subscript.

`Symbolize` subscipt to avoid issues.

Example:

Going from $ux1 - i1$ to $u_{x1}-i_1$

$x$ is a variable but I do not want any interference with u_{x...}!

About the symbolization of subscripts I looked up and found this:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
```

For the rest I have not been able to do it mainly because I do not manage to make the function go through an expression and change all the elements of it. I also tried to use `Replace` but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Using subscripts in *Mathematica* often needlessly complicates things.  Since you are looking for an automated replacement I think you prefer not to enter subscripts manually which I think is wise.  I believe it also means you are looking for a formatting function.

A basic approach is to work with strings.  We may write:

```
ux1 - i1 /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === $Context :>
  (Subscript[#, "" <> ##2] & @@ Characters @ SymbolName[s])
```

[image]

If string output is not acceptable we may wish to use `HoldForm` to keep elements from evaluating.  This is important if for example `x1` or `i` are Symbols with a value:

```
x1 = i = "Fail!";

ux1 - i1 /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === $Context :>
 (HoldForm @@@ MakeExpression /@ Subscript[#, "" <> ##2] & @@ Characters @ SymbolName[s])
```

[image]

Additionally you may consider the case where these replacements must be done inside a held expression, where e.g. `i1` has a global value.  You will need `Unevaluated` and `RuleCondition`:

```
i1 = x1 = i = "Fail!";

Hold[ux1 - i1] /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === $Context :> 
  RuleCondition[HoldForm @@@ MakeExpression /@ Subscript[#, "" <> ##2] & @@ 
     Characters @ SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ s]
```

[image]

If I am correct that you want this for formatting purposes you might make use of a formatting wrapper, which will allow you to extract the original unmodified expression, or define rules for function to work with that expression.

```
MakeBoxes[subscriptForm[expr_], fmt_] :=
 MakeBoxes[#, fmt] &[
  expr /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === $Context :>
    RuleCondition[HoldForm @@@ MakeExpression /@ Subscript[#, "" <> ##2] & @@
      Characters @ SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ s]
 ]
```

Now:

```
expr = subscriptForm[Hold[ux1 - i1]]
```

[image]

```
First @ expr
```

> ```
> Hold[ux1 - i1]
> ```

Comment: Waow I am going to take time to digest all of this, I will probably learn new things before being able to understand all this code. Thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: @Ouistiti You're welcome.  Let me know if you need help understanding any of it; you're right, there's a lot there.  I believe the only undocumented thing I used is `RuleCondition` which you can read about [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121).

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
f[x_] := If[Length[#] > 1 && MemberQ[Names[$Context <> "*"], ToString@x], 
    Subscript[ToExpression@First@#, ToExpression@StringJoin@Rest@#], x]&
    @ StringSplit[ToString[x], ""];
```

It first defines a pure function, where `#` is the unnamed argument. Then it applies it to the list of characters of `x` converted to a string. A simpler example of this method:

```
# Log[2, #] & @ 3
```

This is the same as `3 Log[2, 3]`.

Use the expression from above like this on general expressions:

```
Map[f, ux1 - i1, -1]
```

> -Subscript[i, 1] + Subscript[u, x1]

It should work for simple expressions, but I can't guarantee it for more complex stuff. I always avoid `ToExpression` wherever I can (which is pretty much always). There are lots of opportunities for unforeseen side effects...

Comment: Yes but how to use it on whole expression such as my example: ux1-i1. If you have time I would also be very interested in understanding your function, especially the end of it, what is the part after the If[] doing ?

Comment: @Ouistiti See my edit