# Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?

Tags: output-formatting

You have all convinced me not to type in formulas with subscripts.  However, in order to be able to match the subscripts in my whiteboard math, I figure a 2nd best solution is to want to display instances of `C[i]` with $C_i$ , only in the output, for a chosen set of $C$ and for any $i$

```
DisplaySubscripted[val_] := 
 Format[val[args__]] := Interpretation[Subscript[val, args], val[args]]
SubscriptVariables[valueList_] := Scan[DisplaySubscripted, valueList];

(* Usage*)
SubscriptVariables[{a, b}]; (* Label the variables I want to display subscripted*)
Solve[a[1] + a[2] - 2 b[2] == c[1], b[2]]
(* This subscripts the a[1], a[2], b[2] and not the c[1], as I hoped.
  It also doesn't seem to mess up the symbolics*)
```

Am I missing something, or is this a side-effect free approach to this problem? (it also works well with `Subsuperscript` and `a[1][2]` displaying as $a_1^2$ and it doesn't seem to mess up the superscript with powers)

ALTERNATIVELY: I also thought that Notation may be a way to do this.   Easy enough to do this for an arbitrary variable. e.g.

```
Needs["Notation`"];
DisplaySubscripted[var_] := 
 Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
    SubscriptBox[var, "1"]]\[DoubleLongLeftArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{var, "[", "1", "]"}]]];
DisplaySubscripted["f"];

f[1] (* Displays in output properly as f_1*)
```

However, I can't figure out how to match this for arbitrary subscript patterns.  The obvious one does not work:   `Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
    SubscriptBox[var, "_"]]\[DoubleLongLeftArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{var, "[", "_", "]"}]]]`

I am also not entirely sure that passing `var_` as strings is the best way to do it, but if I use `DisplaySubscripted[f]` instead, it displays the namespace (i.e. `Global'f_1`).  If the Format approach I gave first works, it seems much simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your approach is fine; in fact I just recommended something similar in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30867/121).

However, for the best handing of using your formatted output as input may want to use `MakeBoxes` for the reason [described by Michael Pilat.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/618728)

You also might consider putting a list your subscripted symbols in a global variable for easy changes, or Blocking.

Something like this:

```
MakeBoxes[a : h_[args__], fmt_] /;
  MemberQ[$subs, Unevaluated @ h] :=
 ToBoxes[Interpretation[Subscript[h, args], a], fmt]

$subs = Hold[a, b];

expr = Solve[a[1] + a[2] - 2 b[2] == c[1], b[2]]

Block[{$subs = {c}}, ToString[expr, StandardForm]]
```

[image]

Notes:

- I used `ToString` to cause `MakeBoxes` to trigger *inside* the `Block`; this is similar to what I did for [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882).
- I put the Symbols inside `Hold` so that global definitions would not conflict; the `MakeBoxes` definition is written to handle this.  A list can also be used as shown in the `Block` example.

---

### Extension

Matching symbols by pattern was requested.  I believe it is best to use string patterns, and require all symbols (in the list) to be in String form:

```
MakeBoxes[a : h_[args__], fmt_] :=
  ToBoxes[Interpretation[Subscript[h, args], a], fmt] /;
    MemberQ[Names @ $subs, ToString @ Unevaluated @ h]

$subs = {"a", "b*"};

expr = Solve[a[1] + a[2] - 2 b[2] + bx[1]^2 == c[1], b[2]]
```

The patterns in `$subs` can be anything that is accepted by [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Names.html).

If you want to handle both literal Symbols and string pattern you will need to convert the Symbols to strings.  The easiest way would be `Names[ToString /@ $subs]` but this would preclude using [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html) patterns and would fail to hold Symbols unevaluated; I recommend just using strings as above.

In version 7 if I **Copy As** > **LaTeX** the expression above I get LaTeX with subscripts:

$b_2\to \frac{1}{2} \left(a_1+a_2+\left(\text{bx}_1\right){}^2-c[1]\right)$

In version 9 this does not work right; you could leave out `Interpretion` to fix the problem at the expense of being able to copy&paste the expression within *Mathematica*:

```
MakeBoxes[a : h_[args__], fmt_] := 
 ToBoxes[Subscript[h, args], fmt] /;
   MemberQ[Names@$subs, ToString@Unevaluated@h]
```

---

### Refactored full definitions

Here is refactored code for the generation of your full set of definitions.

- The code is far more concise and easily modified; one can make a change in one place rather than a dozen.
- I noted that repeated calls to `Names` was the cause of a considerable slow-down so I changed that to `StringMatchQ`.
- I [`Protect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Protect.html)ed the symbols `{bar, hat, tilde, vec, underbar, plus, minus, star}` because I don't think you'll want those accidentally evaluating to something else.
- I rewrote definitions that call `Subsuperscript` to use `argsub_` rather than `argsub__` as the latter could result in invalid input to `Subsuperscript`.
- If you use the following code outside of package, without `Begin` and `End`, you should add `SetAttributes[makeDef, HoldAll]` to prevent things like `h` from possibly evaluating incorrectly.

The Symbols used before `Begin` are created in the present (typically `` Global` ``) context; the usage messages are therefore not superfluous, but may be replaced with merely `$scriptedconstants; $scriptedfunctions;` if desired.

```
With[{symbols := Sequence[bar, hat, tilde, vec, underbar, plus, minus, star]},
  Unprotect @ symbols; ClearAll @ symbols; Protect @ symbols;
]

$scriptedconstants::usage = "a list of string patterns for symbols: constants";
$scriptedfunctions::usage = "a list of string patterns for symbols: functions";

Begin["formattingRules`"];

makeDef[pat_, body_] := (
  MakeBoxes[a : pat, fmt_] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[body, a], fmt] /;
    StringMatchQ[ToString @ Unevaluated @ h, $scriptedconstants];
  MakeBoxes[a : pat[sub_], fmt_] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[body[sub], a], fmt] /;
    StringMatchQ[ToString @ Unevaluated @ h, $scriptedfunctions]
)

set1 = {
  bar      -> OverBar,
  hat      -> OverHat,
  tilde    -> OverTilde,
  vec      -> OverVector,
  underbar -> UnderBar,
  plus     -> SuperPlus,
  minus    -> SuperMinus,
  star     -> SuperStar
 };

set2 = {
  plus  -> "+",
  minus -> "-",
  star  -> "*"
 };

makeDef[h_[#], #2[h]] & @@@ set1;
makeDef[h_[argssub__][#], Subscript[#2[h], argssub]] & @@@ Take[set1, 5];
makeDef[h_[argsub_][#], Subsuperscript[h, argsub, #2]] & @@@ set2;
makeDef[h_[argssub__], Subscript[h, argssub]];

End[];
```

(You may notice a funny offset in lines containing `$` above; this is a [known bug](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529/121) in the SE rendering.)

Comment: The only additional feature I would be interested in is whether we could have it match patterns.  e.g. `$displayscripted = {a_}` where `ab[1]` becomes $ab_1$

Comment: @jlperla I recommend a string pattern directly, rather than a `Pattern` object: `$displayscripted = {"a*"}` -- if this is acceptable I will adapt my answer to include it.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, just realized there is 1 more potential issue.  The goal would also be to copy/paste as latex.  I try to latex copy the displayed output from things like `a[1]`, displaying as $a_1$, it copies as `a[1]`.  If I do things like: `ToString[a[1],StandardForm` and then latex copy/paste the output it is closer, but still wacky.  Finally, if I put in my other forms such as `a[1][2]` to $a_1^2$ or `a[star]` to $a^{*}$ I get an error like `Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded` or it simply doesn't copy  properly.

Comment: My implementation of $a^{*}$ is `MakeBoxes[a : h_[star], fmt_] /; MemberQ[$variablelist, Unevaluated@h] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[SuperStar[h], a], fmt];` for example.

Comment: @jlperla For LaTeX you may need to choose between that and having the copied expression be valid input (as the original).  That is, can you do without `Interpretation`?  Your `SuperStar` code doesn't seem quite right; do you really mean to match the symbol `star` expressly?  If you could include an example of a problematic expression in your question, along with the `MakeBoxes` definitions that you are using, I may be able to fix it.

Comment: My goal was to match `star`, reserving and abusing the symbol to aid in easy equation typing (and diff'ing in SVN with a .m file).  The implementaiton of `a[1][2]` to $a_1^2$ is `MakeBoxes[a : h_[argssub__][argssuper__], fmt_] /; MemberQ[$variablelist, Unevaluated@h] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[Subsuperscript[h, argssub, argssuper], a], fmt];`

Comment: I would state the goal of this to be: 1) Type in equations as things like `a[1]`, etc. in my .m file or notebook.  2) Have the output displayed as $a_1$ in the output window when executing the package or notebook.  3) Be able to copy/paste the output into a latex file.  3b) It wouldn't hurt to be able to copy/paste parts of the output in the notebook to edit equations in the input, but I would actually prefer it to copy as `a[1]` so that all formulas in the input look proper.  If you are saying that 3) and 3b) are mutually exclusive, I choose 3)

Comment: @jlperla I momentarily edited and then reverted my answer; The code under **Extension** already allows me to "Copy as LaTex" correctly.  What method are you using that is failing?

Comment: I take the exact code you have in the extension, run it in a notebook (mathematica 9 on windows), Select some or all the output in the notebook, right click and go "Copy as Latex".  When I paste it, I got things like: `\text{$\$$CellContext$\grave{ }$a}(1)+\text{$\$$CellContext$\grave{ }$a}(2)+(\text{$\$$CellContext$\grave{ }$bx}(1))^2-`  However, following your suggestion, if I remove the `Interpretation` from the Extension code, it seems to copy/paste as I had hoped.

Comment: @jlperla Apparently this is version specific -- I am a v7 user.  I shall try to enlist other help.

Comment: @jlperla [rm -rf](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) has confirmed the problem but doesn't have an immediate solution.  I shall restore my recommendation to leave out `Interpretation`, noted specifically for later versions.

Comment: @mrwizard Thank you for all of your help.  As you suggested, the caveat to give is that without the Interpretation, one cannot copy/paste the text from the output as it will contain the subscripts, etc. and will not match the existing math you may have.

Comment: @jlperla I know it's not ideal.  Unfortunately without having the problem at hand I will have difficulty finding a solution.  The only thing I can think of at the moment is trying `InterpretationBox` -- give me a minute to code that.

Comment: @jlperla Please try this; it might also fix the recursion problem: `MakeBoxes[a : h_[args__], fmt_] :=
 Block[{$inSSfmt = True},
   InterpretationBox @@ ToBoxes /@ {Subscript[h, args], a}
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$inSSfmt] && MemberQ[Names@$subs, ToString@Unevaluated@h]`

Comment: Alas, when I try this the expression it has a bunch of RowBox in it.  i.e. the solve gives back: `\text{RowBox}[\{\text{b},[,2,]\}]\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\text{RowBox}[\{\text{a},[,1,]\}]+\text{RowBox}[\{\text{bx},[,1,]\}]^2+\text{RowBox}[\{\text{a},[,2,]\}]-c(1)\right)`

Comment: @jlperla Alright, I'm out of ideas.  I suggest you post a new question with a minimal example asking why Copy As LaTeX from an Interpretation expression doesn't work right in v9.  Actually that makes me wonder, do you still have this problem if you directly (manually) use `Interpretation[(* stuff with subscripts *), (* stuff without subscripts *)]` and try the copy?

Comment: Looks like you are right, this part of the problem is separate.  See the minimalist test in: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30940/copy-paste-of-interpretation-to-latex-fails-but-works-for-inputtext

Comment: A workaround has been found in the other question.  See posted code fora  complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing all of the above, following code implements the list of formatting rules.  The features are:

- Displays in output based on the set of formatting tags. e.g. `a[1]` displays as $a_1$
- Matches string patterns such as "a*" to `ab[1]`
- Copy/paste in the notebook of the output `a_1` actually copies `a[1]` as it should.
- ToLatex takes an expression and generates the latex with the formatting.  i.e. `a[1]` becomes `a_1` in latex.
- Special cases for hats, bars, etc. e.g. `a[star]` displays as $a^{*}$
- Rules include variations for both variables and functions. i.e. $\hat{f}_l(z)$ and $a_l$
- Can handle derivatives $f[l]'[z]$ to $f_l'(z)$
- Can handle functions with/without subscripts.  e.g. $f[z]$ and $f_l[z]$ simultaneously if $z$ is flagged as a parameter.

Usage:

```
$scriptedconstants = {a, ab};
 $scriptedfunctions = {f};
$scriptedfunctionsvars = {x};

val = {a[1], ab[1], a[1, 2], a[bar], a[hat], a[tilde], a[vec], 
  a[underbar], a[plus], a[minus], a[star], a[l][bar], a[l][hat], 
  a[l][tilde], a[l][vec], a[l][underbar], a[l][plus], a[l][minus], 
  a[l][star]}
val2 = {f[x], D[f[x], x], f[l][x, z], f[l], f[l]'[z], 
  D[f[l][z], z, z], D[f[l][x, z], z], D[f[hat][x, z], z], 
  D[f[l][hat][x, z], z], f[1][z], f[1][z_], f[bar][z], f[bar][x, z], 
  f[hat][z], f[tilde][z], f[vec][z], f[underbar][z], f[plus][z], 
  f[minus][z], f[star][z], f[l][bar][z], f[l][hat][z], f[l][tilde][z],
   f[l][vec][z], f[l][underbar][z], f[l][plus][z], f[l][minus][z], 
  f[l][star][z]}
 val // ToLatex
val2 // ToLatex
```

This displays as:
$$
\left\{a_1,\text{ab}_1,a_{1,2},\bar{a},\hat{a},\tilde{a},\overset{\rightharpoonup }{a},\underline{a},a^+,a^-,a^*,\bar{a}_l,\hat{a}_l,\tilde{a}_l,\overset{\rightharpoonup }{a}_l,\underline{a}_l,\text{Subsuperscript}[a,l,+],\text{Subsuperscript}[a,l,-],\text{Subsuperscript}[a,l,*]\right\}
$$
(the super/subscripts here actually show correctly in the FrontEnd, but are the only thing which don't translate to Latex well.  An independent problem from this code)
$$
\left\{f(x),f'(x),f_l(x,z),f_l,f_l'(z),f_l''(z),f_l{}^{(0,1)}(x,z),\hat{f}^{(0,1)}(x,z),\hat{f}_l{}^{(0,1)}(x,z),f_1(z),f_1(\text{z$\_$}),\bar{f}(z),\bar{f}(x,z),\hat{f}(z),\tilde{f}(z),\overset{\rightharpoonup }{f}(z),\underline{f}(z),f^+(z),f^-(z),f^*(z),\bar{f}_l(z),\hat{f}_l(z),\tilde{f}_l(z),\overset{\rightharpoonup }{f}_l(z),\underline{f}_l(z),\text{Subsuperscript}[f,l,+](z),\text{Subsuperscript}[f,l,-](z),\text{Subsuperscript}[f,l,*](z)\right\}
$$
And the `ToLatex @val2` generates as:

\left{f(x),f'(x),f_l(x,z),f_l,f_l'(z),f_l''(z),f_l{}^{(0,1)}(x,z),\hat{f}^{(0,1)}(x,z),\hat{f}_l{}^{(0,1)}(x,z),f_1(z),f_1(\text{z$\_$}),\bar{f}(z),\bar{f}(x,z),\hat{f}(z),\tilde{f}(z),\overset{\rightharpoonup }{f}(z),\underline{f}(z),f^+(z),f^-(z),f^*(z),\bar{f}_l(z),\hat{f}_l(z),\tilde{f}_l(z),\overset{\rightharpoonup }{f}_l(z),\underline{f}_l(z),\text{Subsuperscript}f,l,+,\text{Subsuperscript}f,l,-,\text{Subsuperscript}f,l,*\right}

The full listing of code for this, slightly modified version from that of mr-wizard  is:

```
NotScriptedVarQ[z_] := ! MemberQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, z, Infinity];

makeDef[pat_, body_] := (
  MakeBoxes[a : pat, fmt_] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[body, a], fmt] /;
    MemberQ[Union[$scriptedconstants, $scriptedfunctions], Unevaluated @ h];
      MakeBoxes[a : pat[sub_], fmt_] := ToBoxes[Interpretation[body[sub], a], fmt] /;
        MemberQ[$scriptedfunctions, Unevaluated @ h]
)

set1 = {
  bar      -> OverBar,
  hat      -> OverHat,
  tilde    -> OverTilde,
  vec      -> OverVector,
  underbar -> UnderBar,(* After here subsuper is ncessary to have both annotations*)
  plus     -> SuperPlus,
  minus    -> SuperMinus,
  star     -> SuperStar
 };

set2 = {
  plus  -> "+",
  minus -> "-",
  star  -> "*"
 };

makeDef[h_Symbol[#], #2[h]] & @@@ set1;
makeDef[h_Symbol[argssub__][#], Subscript[#2[h], argssub]] & @@@ Take[set1, 5];
makeDef[h_Symbol[argsub_][#], Subsuperscript[h, argsub, #2]] & @@@ set2;
makeDef[h_Symbol[argssub__?NotScriptedVarQ], Subscript[h, argssub]];
```

Comment: I am glad you have a solution.  Would you like me to add a condensed version of your rule creation code to my answer?

Comment: By all means, please edit or move things into your answer if you prefer. I think this is a very useful utility for people.  So far, the only missing pattern I have found is that while `F[h][z]` matched my function pattern I also needed `F[h]'[z]` to match to $F_h'(z)$ so I could write an ODE in terms of `F[h]`

Comment: Okay; tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. If you have any ideas of the best/idiomatic way to create the as a package it would also be appreciated. I had trouble with contexts, etc when I tried it

Comment: When you say "ask a package" do you just mean a convenient way to load these definitions?  If that is so you shouldn't need things like `BeginPackage`; if on the other hand you only want the definitions to be active only in certain contexts or the like you'll have to clearly specify what you want.

Comment: I see. I think that I was getting fancier than required. In that case, what I have is fine

Comment: I completed my package code; see the update to my answer and the bullet points within.

Comment: Beautiful code, the entire test suite I gave is working well.  One thing of note: If the constant pattern is `$scriptedconstants = {"a*", "b"};` and we type in `{a[1][2], b[1][2]}` we get $a_{12}$ and $b_1[2]$.  Both gives behavior I like as frequently for constants.  The only cases I am working with that dont' seem to be covered by all of this is `$scriptedfunctions = {"f"};` with the tests of `{f[l][x,z], f[l]'[z], D[f[l][z], z, z], D[f[l][x,z], z]` going to $f_l[x,z], f_l'[z], f_l''[z], f_l^{(0,1)}[x,z]$

Comment: Attached is my final, I promise, test suite: `val = {a[1], ab[1], a[1, 2], a[bar], a[hat], a[tilde], a[vec], 
  a[underbar], a[plus], a[minus], a[star], a[l][bar], a[l][hat], 
  a[l][tilde], a[l][vec], a[l][underbar], a[l][plus], a[l][minus], 
  a[l][star]}
val2 = {f[l][x, z], f[bar][x, z], f[l][bar][x, z], f[l]'[z], 
  D[f[l][z], z, z], D[f[l][x, z], z], f[1][z], f[bar][z], f[hat][z], 
  f[tilde][z], f[vec][z], f[underbar][z], f[plus][z], f[minus][z],  f[star][z], f[l][bar][z], f[l][hat][z], f[l][tilde][z], 
  f[l][vec][z], f[l][underbar][z], f[l][plus][z], f[l][minus][z],  f[l][star][z]}`

Comment: I think I see the problem.  You can use `h_Symbol` everywhere I used `h_` to keep from including compound heads, or you can make your string patterns more specific.  I'm not sure about the Derivative thing; I'll try to give this another look when I have time.

Comment: If you meant to try things like `makeDef[h_Symbol[#], #2[h]] & @@@ set1` everywhere, it didn't seem to change enough, but when I did both that and change the $scriptedconstants in the first StringMatchQ to `Union[$scriptedconstant, $scriptedfunctions]`, it seemed to fix both the multiple arguments and the derivatives.  I have posted up the code, the test, and the output in my full code listing above.  Take a peak if you wish to see if there are any unintended side effects, but I think the whole test suite is fulfilled.

Comment: Where have you posted the new code?  By the way I do mean to return to this problem at some point but I've been busy with other things and other answers.

Comment: Just edited in my answer above.  Thank you for all of your help. If Wolfram isn't paying you, they should be.

Comment: They're not.  I thought you were paying me -- when do I get my check? :o)

Comment: Joke all you want, but if you had a legit way to accept money with a receipt, I would definitely give you money from research funds.

Comment: After using it for a few weeks, I posted up my final version.  The string pattern matching was neat, but just a little too slow and I reverted back to the older method.

Comment: I see.  Did you try caching `StringMatchQ` values?  If not, would the string matching possibly be worth the memory consumption to do so?

Comment: For the string matching I essentially used your posted version (without adding anything).  While impressive and powerful, it seemed that every-time anything was displayed in the FrontEnd it had to go through some elaborate calculations.  With your original answer and direct symbol matching, it seems to add in no overhead.  Perhaps caching could help, but in the end I decided that the feature wasn't worth it.

Comment: Regarding your last update I believe you could use `FreeQ`: `NotScriptedVarQ[z_] := FreeQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, z]`