# Copy/paste of Interpretation to Latex fails, but works for InputText

Tags: output-formatting, latex

As part of [another issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30886/5), the following has come up.  Create an `Interpretaion`:

```
Interpretation[Subscript[a, b], a[b]]
```

Select and copy the $a_b$ output from the notebook.  If you paste it into a text file, you get: `a[b]`, which is correct as the `Inputform`, and what we want.

However, if you select it and choose Copy as Latex, you get: `\text{$\$$CellContext$\grave{ }$a}(\text{$\$$CellContext$\grave{ }$b})` in a text file.

I would like to be able to copy this and get the latex as $a_b$, or $a[b]$ as a worst case.  Are there any tricks that could help here?  (I don't think this has anything to do with subscripts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a way around it which works under Linux and *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and uses `ToString` like this

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect.  Confirmed on Mathematica 8 on windows, will verify on 9 on windows next week.  I actually prefer the command to copy/paste.  Code on the motivating example is also being updated.

Comment: One caveat, in my version at least, is that when you select the string in the output, you should choose "Copy as Plain Text" as otherwise it copies as a string with escape characters, etc.

Comment: @jlperla Yes, you have to do that because `ToString` makes already the LaTeX transformation.