# Preventing Superscript from being interpreted as Power when using Ctrl+^ shortcut?

Tags: formatting, variable-definitions, keyboard, input-forms

I have very strong desire to use superscript as the index of the variable.

However, it looks like that the Mathematica automatically recognize the superscript as the power and I got message that my variable with superscript is 'protected'.

Could you help me to make the superscript used as the index of the variable instead of power?

#### UPDATE (16-June-2015):

This question is being reopened and a bounty is being awarded on this. Previous answers are very good, however the bounty is to be awarded on an answer which solve this specific problem:

> How to change the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> keybinding so that it produces Superscript instead of Power.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do, although somebody else might have an answer. I've had this problem before, and just use subscripts instead. For example: $$v_{k\_,j\_}:=\mbox{Sin}[k^2+j^3];$$
Is there a reason why subscripts are not as good for your application?

Comment: @shivams, these seem related to your update of this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68864, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85823

Comment: @MichaelE2 Incidentally I believe one will need to edit the Menu items rather than the KeyEvent items if one is to override this particular combination.  If you can show me otherwise please do so.

Comment: I was wondering about that, because I noticed the difference in the other answers and yours.  It makes sense that Menu key combinations are intercepted before they become a KeyEvent in a particular notebook.  But I assume one could get a superscript with a different combination using KeyEvent, which would be *my* preferred solution, since I use Ctrl-6 so often -- I want Power! ;-)

Comment: @Michael I added that to my answer too.  I still don't like the fact that the typesetting menu says Superscript when it means Power however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's not `Power` here: [esc]int[esc] [ctrl-6] `1` [ctrl-shift-5] `0` `x` [esc]dd[esc] `x`.  (No <kbd> in comments, I guess.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point.  However I still find the *interpretation* of Superscript in such uses misleading from a menu section titled Typesetting.  If it were "2D entry forms" or something I would not be surprised.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't mean to disagree with that.  Did something change at some point?  Consider `Superscript[6, 4]` vs `ToExpression@SuperscriptBox[6, 4]` -- the naming inconsistency is not limited to the menus, as if in V1, say, `Superscript` was interpreted as `Power`.

Comment: @shivams I see that the bounty is about to expire.  Is there anything more I can do to improve my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. Your solution works!! Albeit with a bit of modification regarding the location of the mentioned files on my Linux system :)

Comment: @shivams You're welcome!   Could you inform me of the changes needed?  I would like to update my answer to be applicable to more systems.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My relevant file was located as : `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr`. This is for Mathematica 9 on Linux Mint.

Comment: @shivams Does `$OperatingSystem` return `"X"` on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No. It returns `Unix`.

Answer (score 29):

[`Superscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Superscript.html) is *not* interpreted as [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Power.html):

[image]

Presumably you are referring to what happens when you enter a power in superscript notation using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.  Mathematica is capable of representing both this power notation and a formatted plain `Superscript`.  In my opinion it is a failing that the power notation appears in the **Typesetting** menu while the latter is missing; if anything it should be the other way around I think.  Since there is no key combination for raw `Superscript` I propose using a palette or [input alias](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases.html):

### Palette

You may enter a formatting template using a palette button which may be created with:

```
CreatePalette @ PasteButton @ Superscript[\[SelectionPlaceholder], \[Placeholder]]
```

[image]

Click that palette button to insert a template for plain superscript in the current Notebook.  Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move between fields.

### Input alias

Either open the **Option Inspector**, select **Global Preferences**, type "InputAliases" to find the appropriate entry, and add this to the list of rules:

```
"sps" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "Superscript"]
```

Or add it programmatically (run this only once):

```
AppendTo[
 CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"],
 "sps" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "Superscript"]
]
```

Now type: <kbd>Esc</kbd>`sps`<kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter a template for plain `Superscript`.

(In version 10.0.0 the first field will not be automatically selected due to a bug; see [Input Aliases in Mathematica 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54595/121).)

---

### Bounty

A bounty was added for:

> [A] solution to map the Ctrl+^ keybinding to produce superscript instead of power.

To accomplish this first copy `MenuSetup.tr` from the installation directory to the matching path in your user directory and open the user copy for editing:

```
os = $OperatingSystem /. "Unix" -> "X";

CopyFile @@ (
  FileNameJoin[{#, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", os, "MenuSetup.tr"}] & /@
    {$InstallationDirectory, $UserBaseDirectory})

% // SystemOpen
```

Then within the user copy edit the appropriate `MenuItem` to read:

```
MenuItem["&Superscript", 
 FrontEndExecute[{
   FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Word], 
   FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
    TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "Superscript"], 
    Placeholder]
 }],
 MenuKey["6", Modifiers -> {"Control"}]
]
```

**Restart *Mathematica*.**

You may now enter raw Superscript by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> where <kbd>6</kbd> is the number-line six above the alphabetic keyboard.

You can still enter Power notation by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Keypad-6</kbd>, the latter assuming that Num Lock is on.

---

For those you prefer the reverse behavior you can instead copy and edit `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and change the `Item`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["^", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"]
```

to:

```
Item[KeyEvent["^", Modifiers -> {Control}], 
  FrontEndExecute[{
     FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Word], 
     FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
      TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "Superscript"], 
      Placeholder]
  }]
]
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is Power and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is raw Superscript.  However the **Typesetting** menu item remains misleadingly named **Superscript** so I would personally change that to **Power** if adopting this binding.

Also see:

- [Can I modify Ctrl-- to insert Indexed expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75265/121)

Comment: Glad that you updated your bounty answer to match Linux systems as well. This should now work for Windows and Linux. However, perhaps if you get your hands around a Mac, then check if this works on that as well.

Comment: How do you name `\Sigma^2` i.e. variance? I try both `\Sigma` CTRL-^ + `2` and `superscript[\Sigma,2]` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Note that this superscript gives problems when used in a string. The `FullForm` still contains `TemplateBox` and `TeXForm` gives an error when applied to it. (While it functions normally when applied to the old "Power" superscript in a string.)

If I try to evaluate the box first by doing something like `TeXForm@ToString[ a (Ctrl + ^) b]` I also get a very weird result `\text{ b$\backslash $na}`.

(Sorry for the formatting. I meant if I use your key combination above to create a superscript `a^b`.)

Comment: @Kvothe Thank you, I was not aware of that TeXForm bug.  I shall open a new Question on this as I don't know a good solution.  (One could convert strings to held expressions, then replace Hold with Defer, but this seems like something that should be patched at the level of TeXForm.)

Comment: @Kvothe It turns out that is a known TeXForm bug, and there is a patch: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76801/121

Answer (score 10):

For internal representation, I prefer [avoiding subscripts and superscripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395), so I'll give a way for using superscripts for input and output formatting, while the internal expression is of the form `x[i]`.

For output formatting, something like this:

```
Format[x[i_]] := Superscript[x, i]
```

Example

```
Table[x[i], {i, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For input, this works, but I would wonder whether it is safe:

```
Power[x, i_] ^:= x[i];
Unprotect[Power];
Power /: Set[Power[x, i_], val_] := x[i] = val;
Protect[Power];

x^i // InputForm
(* x[i] *)
```

It also works with keyboard input of superscripts.

```
(x^1 + x^2)^3 // Expand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use superscripts so as to follow some textbook symbols then use `Symbolize`

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

I'm going to paste an image because pasting `Symbolize` gives you this:

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["y", "1"]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I asked people about this before, they wrote up: [Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or/30950#30950)  As with the other answers, this focuses on only output.  But uses an `Interpretation` instead of just changing the functions themselves.  You should just be able to copy/paste the code to try it out.  To change from subscripts to superscripts for your code, it should just be a copy/replace.

As for why you shouldn't use subscripts/superscripts, it took me a while to figure it out, but basically it is because $x_i$ is not a symbol.  Try to call `FullForm` on $x_i$ to get `Subscript[x,i]` which is tough to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Mathematica's Notation package to define what your particular form means. Here I create a datatype G[] from sub- and superscripted letter e. Note in the final example that regular superscripting still means raise to a power.

[image]