# Best way to write an equation with subscripts and superscripts

Tags: syntax, parametric-functions, variable-definitions, custom-notation, indexed-variable

This post is not about a specific `Mathematica` problem but about to develop the best way to enter mathematical equations with subscripts and superscripts. I have a model of a large number of equations in which variables have subscripts, superscripts, and an index to create a set of equations using `Table`.

I wonder if anybody can suggest me the best way to enter model equations such as those in dynamic stochastic equilibrium models. Equations have all kinds of subscripts and superscripts, and I like to know the best way of writing such equations in Mathematica.

**EDIT 1**
Here is an example of a model I aim to solve. Using the suggested `subscript` and `superscript` notation to write a `Mathematica` code will be very complicated and there must be another way to code this model because `Mathematica` is supposed to be powerful solve much more complicated and larger system of non-linear equations.

[image]
[image]

As can be easily seen from this example model, I could log-linearize the model and redefine the variables and solve the system. My question is not about solving this model but entering the model equations in an efficient format using `Mathematica`. It is obvious to me that using long-subscript and superscripted variables is not the way forward. I am interested in a `robust` and `stable` coding of model of this kind.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some limitations that you can face when using sub/super-scripts https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica

Comment: For instance, you cannot clear a value of such an object easily https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-subscripted-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: My recommendation is to avoid directly transcribing math into MA code. Try to adapt to MA programing paradigm. For instance the following object `y[a,b][c,d][x]` could denote a function with 2 sup and 2 superscripts and one variable.

Comment: ... and you can always use `Format` to define print forms, e.g. `Format[y[a_, b_][c_, d_][z_]] := Subsuperscript[y, Row[{a, b}], Row[{c, d}]][z]`

Comment: I think it's better to show us the specific equation system you want to code.

Comment: I edited my question with an example model of non-linear equations. If I find a way to `Code` models of this kind efficiently, it will be a real contribution to using `Mathematica` for modeling non-linear systems.

Comment: Are the $k$ in $R_{k, t+1}$ and the $k$ in $k_t$  the same?

Comment: Is t time? Is this a system of difference equations?

Comment: @Chris K: `t` is time and it can be thought as a system of difference equations. My question is not about solving the model but writing the system equations most efficiently using `Mathematica`. `k` and `k subscript t` is the same variable. No subscript means current time `t`.

Comment: Well, my experience is, the best way to code an equation system is (at least partly) determined by subsequent solving process. Another question: do the superscript always mean `Power` in the system?

Comment: @xzczd: You touched upon an important point. Superscripts of variables should only refer to location or position of the variables, has nothing to do with mathematical operations like square or square root etc. Power should be treated separately. My question ultimately boils down to ask: Is `Mathematica` an efficient programming language for solving a large system of dynamic non-linear equations with many superscripts and subscripts and powers...?

Comment: Then I think it's better to follow the suggestion from @yarchik , unless your system is so complicated that notations like `y[a,b][c,d][x]` are too hard to read and check.

Comment: @xzczd: Yes, my notations are complex and that is why I consulted this forum to have an efficient coding methods. I still do not beleiv that `Mathematica` cannot handle modeling of the complex non-linear equations system. Simply I cannot beleiv that is true.

Comment: Still, I think it's better to talk a bit about how you'll solve the system. There're ways to code this system in 2D form efficiently. (At least more efficient than directly typing `Superscript[…]` and press `Ctrl+Shift+N`. ) But they may not be convenient for certain subsequent processing.

Comment: If you want to use built-in functionality for solving difference equations (`RecurrenceTable`) to solve your system, you will have to use Mathematica notation: `k[t]` not `k_t`.

Comment: @ChrisK `Subscript` can be used in this case actually: `RecurrenceTable[{Subscript[a, n + 1] == 3 Subscript[a, n], 
  Subscript[a, 1] == 7}, Subscript[a, n], {n, 1, 10}]`

Comment: @xzczd Huh, that's a new one for me.  Interesting!  I thought `RecurrenceTable` was basically a discrete-time clone of `NDSolve`.

Comment: @ChrisK It's OK to use it in `NDSolve`, too: `s = NDSolve[{D[Subscript[y, x], x] == Subscript[y, x] Cos[x + Subscript[y, x]], 
    Subscript[y, 0] == 1}, Subscript[y, x], {x, 0, 30}];

Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[y, x] /. s], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]` :D

Comment: @xzczd Yeah, I expected that would turn out to be the case as soon as I made my last comment.  That's pretty ugly, but the `RecurrenceTable` actually looks nice.

Comment: If the only issue here is just typing `Superscript` in an easy way, you'll find this post interesting: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57492/1871

Comment: According to the answer below, your problem is completely solved by the solution given in my last comment, isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing Superscript from being interpreted as Power when using Ctrl+^ shortcut?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33672/preventing-superscript-from-being-interpreted-as-power-when-using-ctrl-shortcu)

Comment: @xzczd: Yes, of course, your answer helped me. The answer I gave below is in fact a duplicate of the info given in the link you provided. However, with a simple example I showed the fine difference between subscript and power notations in the same equation. I think my answer with an example is useful for those who are not very technical. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out an answer to my questions:
1) how to typeset mathematical equations in the text-book format, and 
2) how to differentiate superscripts from power notation.

My answer to question (1) is taken from this forum. To write an equation with superscripts and power at the same time, run the following `Code` once in the beginning of your program:

```
AppendTo[
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"], 
"sps" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
"Superscript"]
];
```

Then enter `Esc`  `sps`  `Esc` to write an equation with pure superscript notation, and then use `Built-in MMA` pallate for power notation `Ctrl+^`. This will create a math equation or notation with superscript combined with power notation.

To answer question (2), I give an example of creating a math notation with pure power. Just looking at the following example should be sufficient to see that in the first math notation, pure superscripts are combined with power 2, and in the second math notation using the MMA pallate `Ctrl+^` is used to create pure power notation. Using these two different notations in typesetting math equations is so powerful and makes our life very easy.

Thank you all commenting on my question and especially the `MMA links` provided by some of the comments given.

[image]