# Functions involving variables that have been "Symbolized"

Tags: symbols, custom-notation

I used the `Notation` package to symbolize expressions of the form `Superscript[u,_]`. I then proceeded to manually input the values of various $u^x$ where $x$ varies in `L={a,b,c,d,...}`. How can I define a function that takes an element $x$ in `L` and outputs the value of $u^x$? I've tried doing something like

```
F[x_]:=Superscript[u,x]
```

but whenever I evaluate it I just get $u^x$ (i.e. `F[a]` outputs `Superscript[u,x]`). I also tried composing with `ToExpression` and many other functions but they don't seem to work.

Edit: The reason as to why I'm using the `Notation` package is because  I want to set expressions like this:

[image]

where I later set the values of each block and then perform operations with $w^{A,B}$.

Comment: Input $u^x$ manually and press Ctrl+Shift+I and observe, then you'll probably know what to do. (Well, but why are you using `Notation\`` package if you need the `Superscript` be "alive"? )

Comment: What do you mean by "alive"? I'm using the `Notation` package to make the notebook more readable. In reality I'm manually setting the values of multiple matrices $u^{x,y}$, each of which consists of blocks $u^{x,y}_{z,w}$. I'd like to find a way to verify some properties for all these matrices without having to manually check each one. Using Ctrl+Shift+I only turned $u^x$ into `u\[UnderBracket]Superscript\[UnderBracket]x`.

Comment: I mean, by default the `u` and `x` in `Superscript` is separated i.e. you can do something like `Superscript[u, x]/. x->aa` to obtain `Superscript[u, aa]`, but `Notation\`` package will transform it to `u\[UnderBracket]Superscript\[UnderBracket]x` that is a single symbol and you won't be able to make replacement easily anymore.  "I'm using the Notation package to make the notebook more readable." I don't understand, `StandardForm` of `Superscript` is already 2D, why do you need `Notation\`` package?

Comment: I just added a picture explaining why I feel like I need the `Notation` package.

Comment: The answers in that other questions helped me a lot. I added a new shortcut Superscript and will be using that to input my values, it is clunky at times though. You can post your last comment as an answer to accept.

Comment: When writing my (now removed) last comment I didn't notice you've actually mixed up `Superscript` and `Power`. Please see the revised answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you've mixed up `Superscript` and `Power`. Though the 2D form (to be more precise, `StandardForm`) of them looks the same, they are totally different. When one presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, the 2D form of `Power` will be created. According to the mentioned behaviors (`InputForm` of your symbolized $u^x$ is `u⎵Superscript⎵x`, `Set::write` warning in picture, etc.), what you've really done is inputting 2D `Power` rather than `Superscript`.

Symbolizing the 2D `Power[…, …]` is a bad idea in my view, because:

1. `Power` is so frequently used, symbolizing it will probably cause other trouble.
2. The superscript in symbolized `Power` cannot be modified in a simple manner. (Actually avoiding undesired modification of subscript/superscript/… is one of the main purposes of using `` Notation` `` package. ) But you need to modify the superscript.

Since what you really need is just avoiding `Set::write` and manipulating the superscript later, using `Superscript` instead of `Power` should be the way to go. To input `Superscript` easily, the solutions in the following post should help:

[Preventing Superscript from being interpreted as Power when using Ctrl+^ shortcut?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33672/1871)

Finally, though the original question has now been proved to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/284701), let me show a solution anyway:

```
<< Notation`

Symbolize@ParsedBoxWrapper@SuperscriptBox["v", "_"]
(* Notice it's important to use 1D Power[…, …] in the following line *)
G[x_] := ToExpression@MakeBoxes@Power[v, x]

G[a] /. a -> b

(* v⎵Superscript⎵a *)
```

[image]

This solution works because `` Notation` `` is essentially a package that influences the transformation between boxes and expressions, so we can call the transformation rule created by `Symbolize` programmatically with `MakeBoxes` and `ToExpression`.