# Convert an expression's symbols of form a$x to a[x]

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, regular-expressions

I want a function that takes expressions of the following form: `a$x` and converts them to `a[x]`.

In particular, consider the following test cases

```
exp = a$x + b$x$y + a$x[d] + a$x[d$y]
```

Should become, with some `ToFunctionNotation`:

```
ToFunctionNotation[exp] == a[x] + b[x][y] + a[x][d] + a[x][d[y]]
```

Note: I want to keep this as an expression for further processing.  I tried using matches with `SymbolName` and string patterns, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do they have values?

Comment: Nope.  In reality what I am doing is using `$` for the naming of the variables, then using http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or for display and LaTex output (i.e., `a$x` -> $a_x$ after the Notation is used.

Comment: Shucks, a simple `StringReplace[exp, "$" -> "@"]` does not result in your stated precedence ;-(

Comment: One possible simplification:  I only need 2 levels deep, e.g. `b$x$y` -> `b[x][y]`

Comment: Don't use these symbol names.  Forms such as `a$1` are used internally.  If you use it yourself, it might lead to conflicts and random breakage.  Generally, it's a bad idea to try to manipulate code as strings (e.g. rewrite names programmatically) in Mathematica.  Expression rewriting is almost always better than string rewriting.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you.  My understanding was that Mathematica only reserves the `$` character as the first character in a symbol name?  Nothing would make me happier than to avoid the $, but I am limited in the symbol name separators available in mathematica.  Of course, the `_` I would use in C++ doesn't work, and the ` as a separator introduces namespaces.  Do I have any other options?  All of this is to ensure that I can still do algebra with subscripts, hats, etc. and get it to display correctly, and I can't figure out any other ways.

Comment: @jlperla Try `Module[{a}, a]`

Comment: @jlperla Actually `$` is *not* reserved as the first character.  It is common practice to use `$names` for constants.  You will run into trouble specifically when the `$` is preceded by something and followed by a number.  If using `a[x]` instead of `a$x` really doesn't work in your case, you can try `a$x`, but I definitely wouldn't try `a$1`.

Comment: Thanks to all.  @Kuba can you explain the `Module[{a},a]` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind Szabolcs comment.

But if it is about string manipulation exercise:

```
exp2 = "a$x+b$x$y+a$x[d]+a$x[d$y]";

patt = (NumberString | LetterCharacter) ..;

StringReplace[exp2, 
              x : ((patt ~~ "$") .. ~~ patt
                  ) :> StringJoin @@ Riffle[StringSplit[x, "$" -> "["], "]", {4, -1, 3}]]
```

> ```
> "a[x]+b[x][y]+a[x][d]+a[x][d[y]]"
> ```

**Edit**

```
exp = a$x + b$x$y + a$x[d] + a$x[d$y];
exp /. s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], "*$*"] :> ToExpression[
          StringJoin @@ Riffle[StringSplit[SymbolName[s], "$" -> "["], "]", {4, -1, 3}]]
```

> ```
> a[x] + a[x][d] + a[x][d[y]] + b[x][y]
> ```

Comment: I need this to work on, and then stay as, the expression tree, rather than a string.  Is that possible?

Comment: @jlperla at some point you will have to work with string imo. but maybe not :P I don't know. Here you can `exp2 = ToString[exp]` and use `ToExpression` at the end. Only if those symbols have no values.

Comment: Is there any way to use a Replace with a pattern matching on the symbol, which then does the transformation only on that node in the expression tree?  For example, `p_Symbol?StringMatchQ[SymbolName[p], "$"] :> ??????? `

Comment: @jlperla is my edit what you are after?

Comment: Perfect, that is it.  Seems to work with arbitrary expression trees, and I can't see any issues.  Thanks.