# How to make Mathematica treat Subscript[x, j] as a standalone variable?

Tags: formatting, subscript

When i use `Replace[]` or `/.`, I find that Mathematica does not treat $x_{j}$(`Subscript[x, j]`) as a variable compared to  $xj$. I was wondering, if there is a way to make $x_{j}$ an ordinary variable name like $xj$, because i think
$x_{j}$ is standard mathematical notation compared to $xj$.

Comment: You could symbolize it using notation package. Iam sure this was asked before if you search this site.

Comment: Use `Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]` then the indexed variable `x[j]` will **display** as a subscripted variable.

Comment: Also see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30849/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30884/1871