# How can I break through Function's HoldAll attribute to force evaluation of a body element?

Tags: functions, function-construction

The question concerns creating a function. Let consider the following code

```
With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]},
 {First[#], f'[#]} &
]
```

which returns

```
(* ==> {First[#1], Function[t, Cos[t]]'[#1]} & *)
```

How to can I force it to return the derivative evaluated (only second part of the returned list); i.e., how to can I get

```
(* ==> {First[#1], -Sin[#1]} & *)
```

Comment: As halirutan said, you want to build a function with a part of it already evaluated. Not all of it, or `First@#` would be evaluated and you don't want that. So, you want to inject code into a held expression. Search for that in the site.

Answer (score 8):

`Function`, and in your case the syntactic sugar with `#` you are using, holds its arguments. Therefore, your expression is not evaluated. There are several ways to do this and I'm sure they were already discussed here, but I cannot find the question now. Anyway, one way is to use replacements

```
With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]},
 Block[{expr},
  {First[#], expr} & /. expr -> f'[#]
  ]
]
```

another one is to use yet another pure function

```
With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]},
 Function[expr, {First[#], expr} &][f'[#]]]
```

Additionally, [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/187) discusses the issue too and gives more thourough explanations in the answers.

Comment: What about named formal parameters instead of `#` (there is a possibility there where renamed before function construction)?

Answer (score 4):

```
With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]},
  Evaluate[{First[k], f'[k]}] & /. k :> # // Quiet
 ]

 With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]},
  With[{k = f'[#]}, {First@#, k} &]
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With[{f = Function[t, Cos[t]]}, {First[#] &, f'[#] &}][[2]]
```

Put the & inside the bracket for each function instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I mean.