# Hold expression with RandomInteger

Tags: hold

One more question for today: I'm trying to show two random integers with a plus (+) sign between them, in an unevaluated form. I know how Hold and HoldForm work, but they hold everything, including the RandomInteger:

```
Hold[RandomInteger[100] + RandomInteger[100]]
```

I've tried then Evaluate before RandomInteger, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any help with this? Very much appreciated, as always!

Comment: This is a straight-forward case for the Trott-Strzebonski  technique, discussed e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replace-inside-held-expression). Apply this rule to your expression: `r_RandomInteger :> With[{eval = r}, eval /; True]`. The reason `Evaluate` does not help is that it is too deep for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
HoldForm[#1 + #2]&[RandomInteger[100], RandomInteger[100]]
 (* 77 + 84 *)
```

Comment: +1 but see my answer too for my personal variation

Answer (score 11):

I propose:

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]
```

Comment: The form `+##` rates highly on my weirdo meter. Weirdo. BTW, +1. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, it's a favorite of mine, thank-you-very-much. :D

Comment: Great! Your solution is very compact and can be generalized to any numbers of terms, +1 :)

Comment: @ybeltukov I'm glad you appreciate it.  Thanks for the vote.

Comment: @Blackbird It is not *directly* documented that I know of, but it comes from an understanding of *Mathematica*'s parsing.  `+x` parses as `Plus[x]` as can be seen with `Hold[+x] // FullForm`.  So `+##` is `Plus[##]` and then it's just a matter of `SlotSequence` which *is* directly documented.  As a second example `1 x` parses as `Times[1, x]` so we can use `1 ##` as shorthand for multiplying arguments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:thanks for replying, I thought I have already finished my quota of stupid questions for today.

Comment: @Blackbird Oh s#!t, there's a quota on those now? :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ya there is and I am increasing it as well..:p actually one more question , is it possible to write such a short notation for `Subtract` and `Divide`, because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Blackbird I can answer that with one of my favorite retorts: "It works, just not the way you think it does."  `Hold[-x] // FullForm` shows that `-x` parses as `Times[-1, x]`, so if you want to multiply and then negate arguments it will work fine. :^)  I'm not sure what you tried with for Divide but I figure something like `1/x` which parses as `Times[1, Power[x, -1]]`.  That's even stranger as now you will have a power tower ending in `-1`.  Incidentally what multiple-argument form of subtract and divide were you aiming for?  I mean, did you want `a - b - c - d` for example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : well if OP had requested for a `Divide` or Subtract operator between the operands than how you can modify this post with somewhat similar syntactic approach.

Comment: @Blackbird Again, do you mean e.g. `a - b - c - d` and `a / b / c / d` or something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : yes yes the same.

Comment: @Blackbird That gets pretty complicated because of the internal format of those expressions.  Basically *Mathematica* doesn't really use that format: it's purely for input.  I need to leave for the day but at another time when we are both here perhaps you would post a question asking about these so that I may answer with more room than comments provide.

Comment: ok I shall post one, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can hold it too,

```
Hold[Plus[a, b]] /. {a -> RandomInteger[100], b -> RandomInteger[100]}
```

> Hold[91 + 4]

```
HoldForm[Plus[a, b]] /. {a -> RandomInteger[100], 
  b -> RandomInteger[100]}
```

> 87+22

Read the difference between `Hold` and `HoldForm` to know they are very close.

Comment: This is a nice place to show the difference between `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`.

Answer (score 2):

Late to this party, but here's a nice trick that surprisingly works:

```
Composition[HoldForm, Plus] @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]
```

OR

```
Composition[HoldForm, Plus] @@ {RandomInteger[100], RandomInteger[100]}
```