# HoldForm[Operator ##] on some list

Tags: syntax, operators, hold

Recently in response to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/hold-expression-with-randominteger/31733?noredirect=1#) Mr.Wizard suggested an unusual way to summing numbers. This doesn't seem to be documented.

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]
```

This works fine for `Plus` and in case of `-` it generates -ive of product of list elements. I could not find out how to write a close variation of this for `Divide` or `Subtract` or other operations.

Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [prior comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/hold-expression-with-randominteger/31733?noredirect=1#comment99134_31789) I know that you are interested in forms such as:

```
a - b - c - d
a / b / c / d
```

There is no simple short form for these as there is for `Plus`.  To understand this you must understand how *Mathematica* parses and displays these expressions.  Let's look at the first one:

### Subtract

```
HoldForm[a - b - c - d]
```

> ```
> a - b - c - d
> ```

No surprises.  But now `FullForm`:

```
HoldForm @ FullForm[a - b - c - d]
```

> ```
> Plus[a, Times[-1, b], Times[-1, c], Times[-1, d]]
> ```

So our simple expression is not quite so simple in the internal format.  Each negative term is actually represented as `Times[-1, x]`.  But what about Box form?  This is what is sent to the Front End for display:

```
HoldForm[a - b - c - d] // ToBoxes
```

> ```
> TagBox[RowBox[{"a", "-", "b", "-", "c", "-", "d"}], HoldForm]
> ```

We will need a helper utility<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121)</sup> to see what the Front End sends to the Kernel:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]
```

Now:

```
"a-b-c-d" // parseString
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"a", "-", "b", "-", "c", "-", "d"}]], StandardForm}
> ```

### Divide

The same analysis of the division/fraction case:

```
HoldForm[a/b/c/d]
```

> ```
> a/((b c) d)
> ```

This time you may get a bit of a surprise.  Let's look at the `FullForm`:

```
HoldForm @ FullForm[a/b/c/d]
```

> ```
> Times[Times[Times[a, Power[b, -1]], Power[c, -1]], Power[d, -1]]
> ```

Once again we see that there is no "division" operator, but rather denominators are represented as `Power[x, -1]`.  Why though is this displayed as `a/((b c) d)`?  Let's look at the box form sent to the Front End:

```
HoldForm[a/b/c/d] // ToBoxes
```

> ```
> TagBox[FractionBox["a", 
>   RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"b", " ", "c"}], ")"}], " ", "d"}]], HoldForm]
> ```

So our `Times`/`Power` expression is converted to this different format *during Box conversion* even though the internal format contains no "fraction" head.  This Box formatting is not prevented by the `Hold` function.  See [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882) for another example of this.

What about the *input* format however?  Clearly `a/b/c/d` can be *displayed* by the Front End as you can simply type that in.  What is its Box form?

```
"a/b/c/d" // parseString
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"a", "/", "b"}], "/", "c"}], "/", "d"}]], StandardForm}
> ```

### Input Syntax

By now you are probably understanding what I meant when I said "it's complicated."  You may also see that there is a difference between inputting the equivalent expression, which may be displayed differently, e.g. `a/((b c) d)`, and having *Mathematica* display a certain form such as `a/b/c/d`.  We can explore both.

Taking things in reverse order, we can use `Row` to merely display an expression:

```
Row[{a, b, c, d}, "-"]
Row[{a, b, c, d}, "/"]
```

> ```
> a-b-c-d
>
> a/b/c/d
> ```

This is not meaningful mathematical input.  It is only a display form.  Also it is not "intelligent" about mathematical formatting such as negatives:

```
Row[{a, -b, c, d}, "-"]  (* note -b *)
```

> ```
> a--b-c-d
> ```

This was the motivation for using e.g. `HoldForm[+##]` rather than `Row` in the first place: we *wanted* the automatic formatting, just not the automatic evaluation.

If you desire a shorthand for entering a valid mathematical expression you could negate after in the case of subtraction:

```
-+## &[a, -b, c, d]
```

> ```
> -a + b - c - d
> ```

You'll note this also negates the first term.  It isn't clear to me if you want this or not; you could use `# - +##2 &` if you do not.

For formatting purposes this won't work:

```
HoldForm[-+##] &[1, -2, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> -(1 - 2 + 3 + 4)
> ```

You would instead need to negate the terms first:

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ -{##} &[1, -2, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> -1 + 2 - 3 - 4
> ```

Division will not display as `a/b/c/d` anyway, as already demonstrated, so you are probably better off using `Row` for that display format.  (Or building Box form directly, though I'd rather not make this answer any longer to show how.)  For inputting a valid mathematical expression you could use:

```
#/(1 ##2) &[a, b, c, d]
```

> ```
> a/(b c d)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
HoldForm[Divide@##] & @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]
```