# How can I get the number of slots in Function?

Tags: functions

Suppose that I define

```
f = Function[#1 + #2];
```

And I want to define a new function, `argsNum`, so that it returns a number of arguments of input function:

```
argsNum[f]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

since `f` has 2 slots, `#1` and `#2`.

I found the good Q&A, [Function that counts the number of arguments of other functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/function-that-counts-the-number-of-arguments-of-other-functions) but it does not work on functions of form like `Function[#1 + #2]` or etc.

It works on `Function[{x, y}, x + y]`. But I need a function that works on slots.

How can I modify the function in above link or define a new function which also works on slots?

Comment: `Count[f, _Slot, ∞]`

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?  For reasons that Mr. Wizard mentions in his answer, I think that such a function wouldn't be needed most of the time.  But of course I might be wrong.  If you explain *why* you need this, we might be able to give a better answer (and people would also be more interested in the question).  As MrW. said, pure functions can take any number of arguments that is greater than the largest slot number.  The new named slots introduced in v10 complicate this further (e.g. `#one + #two &`)

Comment: @m_goldberg What about repeated use of the same Slot?  Even in the most narrow application that won't work.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually I am making a function with one argument and that argument would be another function that I want to check. To make this explanation be simple, `GoodFuncQ[func]` returns true if `func` has exactly 2 arguments, otherwise, false.

Comment: @Analysis Thanks for the Accept.  Considering your application I think it would be better to `Check` for error messages during application, as I suspect such tests cannot be written robustly for all possible input, at least not without unreasonable overhead.  Perhaps one of the argument testing frameworks I presented [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23356/121) will be useful to you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is not well specified for several reasons:

1. Pure functions accept a flexible number of arguments

   ```
   #1 + #2 &[a, b, c, d]
   ```

   > ```
   > a + b
   > ```
2. It is common for some arguments to not be used:

   ```
   #1 + #3 & @@ {a, b, c, d}
   ```

   > ```
   > a + c
   > ```
3. [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) includes all arguments after the given position:

   ```
   +##3 & @@ {a, b, c, d}
   ```

   > ```
   > c + d
   > ```

Without clarifying how each of these cases is to be counted it is impossible to give a general answer.

Comment: `+##&`, seriously? Not that it doesn't amuse me, it's not something I would consider writing. (+1)

Comment: @rcollyer It's a long-time favorite of mine. :D  Actually I like it so much I wish there were more short-form operators that would work this way. (Monadic.)

Comment: Mr.Wizard, can you explain how the evaluation of (3) works? Why is `+` special in this respect and are there other operators which work in the same way?

Comment: @sebhofer `+x` parses as `Plus[x]`.  `+` is special because most *Mathematica* operators do not have a monadic form; I cannot write `*x` for `Times[x]` for example.  I can write `1*##` which parses as `Times[1, ##]` however.  I wrote some about this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31797/121); please take a look at that before asking follow-up questions.

Comment: That makes sense. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Sorry. I only realized that `*##` doesn't work (and `-##` neither for that matter). Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that post. I looked for "monad" but came up empty handed.

Answer (score 9):

As [@Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) has pointed out, [your question isn't well specified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56670/5485). However, a pure function always needs a *minimum* number of arguments, otherwise an error message is thrown:

```
#1 + #2 &[a]
```

> *Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in `#1+#2&` cannot be filled from `(#1+#2&)[a]` >>*
>
> ```
> a + #2
> ```

So finding the minimum number of required arguments of a pure function is a well-posed problem. We can solve it by simply detecting if the above error message is thrown for a given number of arguments; if so, we increase the number of arguments and try again:

```
EnoughArgumentsQ[f_Function, numargs_Integer] := 
  Quiet[
    Check[
      f @@ ConstantArray[Null, numargs]; True, 
      False, 
      Function::slotn
    ],
    Function::slotn
  ];

MinNumberOfArguments[f_Function] := 
  NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, ! EnoughArgumentsQ[f, #] &]
```

This is not a very efficient approach, but it gets the job done in a pretty robustly fashion:

```
MinNumberOfArguments /@ {
  (* 0 *)
  Function[{}, Null],
  (* 1 *)
  MapIndexed[#1^#2 &, #] &,
  (* 2 *)
  #1 + #2 &,
  (* 3 *)
  {#1,#2,#3,##} &,
  (* 4 *)
  #1 + #4 &
}
```

> ```
> {0,1,2,3,4}
> ```

*Mathematica* is bound to have a cleverer internal way of determining the minimum number of arguments before it throws the `Function::slotn` message. If anybody knows how this is done, and if it's accessible, that'd be great :).

Comment: Interesting, because you used `Check` it even gets the pathological `Map[Function[{x, y}, {#1, #2, x, y}] &, #] &`.

Comment: I'd even consider reducing possible run-time of this by first extracting `Slot`/`SlotSequence`, i.e. `Cases[f, (Slot|SlotSequence)[n_]:> n, -1]`, and running down from `n`. Also, I'd use [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) as it returns an expression.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm not sure what you mean with "it returns an expression", but I've changed `MinNumberOfArguments` to use `NestWhile`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `While`, `For`, `Do`, and `Scan` do not have return values. `NestWhile`, `Table`, etc. do. So, your prior code where you had to write `While[...]; i` is not needed as you can write `NestWhile[...]` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my approach to determine the number of slots in the pure function without counting those in any sub-functions. That means `MapIndexed[#1^#2 &, #1] &` (per @TeakeNutma's comment in @JohnMcGee's answer) will only return one slot. I do this by deleting all inner `Function`s before counting the slots:

```
Clear[slotCount]
slotCount[f_Function]:=Module[{deleteInner},
deleteInner=Replace[f,_Function:>Sequence[],{1,Infinity}];
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[deleteInner,_Slot,{1,Infinity},Heads->True]]//Length
]
```

**Notes**: Using `Heads->True` for `Cases` will count slots correctly for cases like `#1[#2]`.

---

**Testing on the example functions in @TeakeNutma's answer**

```
{#,slotCount[#]}&/@{Function[{},Null],MapIndexed[#1^#2&,#]&,#1+#2&,{#1,#2,#3,##}&,#1+#4&}//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not quite sure `#1 + #4 &` would have 4 slots (instead of just 2). Below is a modified version of my `slotCount` function that will return 4:

```
Clear[slotCountPositionAware]
slotCountPositionAware[f_Function]:=Module[{deleteInner,slotList,maxSlot},
deleteInner=Replace[f,_Function:>Sequence[],{1,Infinity}];
slotList=DeleteDuplicates[Cases[deleteInner,_Slot,{1,Infinity},Heads->True]];
maxSlot[l_List]:=If[l=={},0,l/.Slot[x_]:>x//Max];
maxSlot[slotList]
]

{#,slotCountPositionAware[#]}&/@{Function[{},Null],MapIndexed[#1^#2&,#]&,#1+#2&,{#1,#2,#3,##}&,#1+#4&}//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This method does not like this function for input: `Function[{x, y}, {#1, #2, x, y}] &`.  (That's a function that returns a `Function`.)

Comment: I've never seen mixing of named slots and hashtag(?) slots in a `Function` before. Isn't `#1` the same thing as `x` and `#2`, `y`? I'm working on my function to see if it could accommodate such cases, hopefully with some success.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've defined another instance of `slotCount` to handle special functions like the one above. Let me know what you think and where I can improve: `Clear[slotCount]
slotCount[f:Function[Function[__]]]:=
Module[{deleteInner},
deleteInner=Replace[f,_Function:>Sequence[],{2,Infinity}]//First;
Cases[deleteInner,_Slot,{1,Infinity},Heads->True]~Join~First@deleteInner//Length
];
slotCount[Function[{x,y},{#1,#2,x,y}]&]`

Comment: That example was borrowed from [a comment by rcollyer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56665/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-slots-in-function/56781?noredirect=1#comment162576_56672).  It is *not* mixing `Slot` and named parameters in the same `Function`, but rather one function nested inside another like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56714/121).  The outer function using `&` and `#` contains the inner function using `Function` and `x`/`y`.  Using the entire thing as `fn`, `fn[1, 2]` yields `Function[{x, y}, {1, 2, x, y}]` which is itself a complete function.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Length@Union@Cases[f, _Slot, Infinity]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

The `Union` eliminates duplicates

Comment: This doesn't work for cases like `f = MapIndexed[#1^#2 &, #] &`, which only has one argument.

Comment: This would fail for `f = #1 + #3 &`