# Is it possible to specify which range that slot takes from?

Tags: functions

consider this example:

```
list = {a, b, c};
Table[{Sin[i], Cos[j]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, list[[i ;;]]}]

(*{{{Sin[1], Cos[a]}, {Sin[1], Cos[b]}, {Sin[1], Cos[c]}}, {{Sin[2], 
   Cos[b]}, {Sin[2], Cos[c]}}, {{Sin[3], Cos[c]}}}*)
```

for the following code:

```
{Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ list[[# ;;]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

we can get same result if the slot inside `Sin` `(Sin[#])` takes the values from the outer range `({1,2,3})`

so in general, is it possible to specify which range that slot takes from?

Comment: I read this question twice and I still don't understand it.  Edit: Okay, thanks to Verbeia's answer I think I understand.  I do find the phrasing of the question confusing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to *localize the outer Slot*, like this:

```
With[{indx = #}, {Sin[indx], Cos[#]} & /@ list[[indx ;;]]] & /@  Range[3]

(* {{{Sin[1], Cos[a]}, {Sin[1], Cos[b]}, {Sin[1], Cos[c]}}, {{Sin[2], 
   Cos[b]}, {Sin[2], Cos[c]}}, {{Sin[3], Cos[c]}}} *)
```

You could also rework the process to get the full set of tuples of `{Sin[1],Sin[2],Sin[3]}` and `{Cos[a],Cos[b],Cos[c]}` and keep the ones you want, using something like:

```
MapThread[#1[[#2 ;;]] &, {Outer[{Sin[#1], Cos[#2]} &, Range[3], list],
   Range[3]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can nest Functions to accomplish what I believe you want to:

```
f = i \[Function] {Sin[i], Cos[#]} & /@ list[[i ;;]];

Array[f, 3] // Column
```

> ```
> {{Sin[1],Cos[a]},{Sin[1],Cos[b]},{Sin[1],Cos[c]}}
> {{Sin[2],Cos[b]},{Sin[2],Cos[c]}}
> {{Sin[3],Cos[c]}}
> ```

This looks nicer in the Notebook:

[image]

Other methods include:

```
# /. i_ :> ({Sin[i], Cos[#]} & /@ list[[i ;;]]) & /@ {1, 2, 3}

With[{i = #}, {Sin[i], Cos[#]} & /@ list[[i ;;]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}  (* Verbeia's *)
```

Nevertheless I feel that the `Table` construct is at least as clear as any of these.

Answer (score 5):

> is it possible to specify which range that slot takes from?

The short answer is "no" (not counting solutions with named arguments since they aren't `Slot`s) but if you really, really want to do it you can write it like I've done below, then `#1` refers to the inner `Map` and `#2` refers to the outer `Map`:

```
Map[
 Map[
   {Sin[#], Cos[#2]} & @@ # &,
   Thread@{#, list[[# ;;]]}
   ] &,
 {1, 2, 3}
 ]
```

This technique can be used for more levels I think, so that if you had four `Map` inside each other you could use `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and `#4` to refer to the different levels. But it isn't worth the trouble to start thinking about it.

Comment: Nice. consider this also, {Sin[#1], Cos[#2]} & @@@ Thread[{#, list[[# ;;]]}] & /@ Range[3]

Comment: @Algohi Yep, that works too.