# Take a list with the amounts of the random samples from another list while holding the index

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list called `cant` with some amounts of samples to take from the list `community` as follows:

```
cant = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
community = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
```

I'm trying to find a better way to do this task:

```
where = {};
Table[AppendTo[where, 
 Table[Flatten[{RandomSample[community[[i]], 1], i}], {cant[[
    i]]}]];, {i, Length[community]}];
```

The result is:

```
where 
{{{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 1}}, {{1, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}}, {{4, 5}, {1, 5}, {3, 5}, {1, 5}}}
```

Because with

```
where[[1]]
{{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 1}}
```

The 5 samples in the first item (3, 2, 3, 4, and 4) have the index of community 1. I read about Reap and Sow, but really I couldn't understand how to implement this. Any idea of how to make this faster because I'm working with large communities and sampling thousands?

I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapThread[Thread[List[RandomChoice[#1, #2], #3]] &, {community, cant, Range@Length@cant}]

(* {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}}, {{3, 2}}, {{4, 3}, {1, 
   3}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}}, {{2, 5}, {3, 5}, {1, 5}, {6, 5}}} *)
```

---

Some variations:

```
MapIndexed[Thread[List[#1, First@#2]] &, MapThread[RandomChoice[#1, #2] &, {community, cant}]]
MapIndexed[Function[i, Join[{i}, #2]] /@ #1 &, MapThread[RandomChoice[#1, #2] &, {community, cant}]]
```

Comment: I believe `RandomSample` should be `RandomChoice`.

Comment: I agree, though it depends on OP's goal (if there should be any repeated values in the sample). Also @Mr.Wizard I finally know what you were talking about [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56665/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-slots-in-function/56781?noredirect=1#comment162905_56781), about nesting pure functions.

Comment: I think the OP's code is unambiguous in this regard. It should be `RandomChoice` (though he correctly uses `RandomSample` in his code, in a different way).

Comment: Ah now I see your point. Evaluating `Table[RandomSample[community[[1]],1],{4}]` several times helped me see what's going on. I fixed my answer based on your recommendation. Thanks so much!

Comment: I created a function with the first line you gave me and works better than my initial idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
{(community[[#]]~RandomSample~1)[[1]], #} & /@ 
   ConstantArray[#, cant[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length@cant]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread[{RandomSample[community[[#]], cant[[#]]], #}] & /@ Range[Length[community]]
(* {{{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 1}, {4, 1}}, 
    {{3, 2}},
    {{2, 3}, {4, 3}},
    {{3, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 4}},
    {{3, 5}, {5, 5}, {4, 5}, {1, 5}}} *)
```