# How many arguments does a function require, and how to use that in `Manipulate`

Tags: functions, manipulate, wavelet-analysis

The goal is to vary the order parameters in wavelet transforms in the `Manipulate` environment. The various transformations have arguments of different rank. For example,

`HaarWavelet[]` has no order argument.

`DaubechiesWavelet[m]` has a single order argument $m$ and the desire is to present choices for $m$.

`BiorthogonalSplineWavelet[m,n]` has an order parameter $m$ and a dual order parameter $n$ and the desire is to let the user control $m$ and $n$.

The current state of my effort is this:

`data = DiskMatrix[10];
Manipulate[
 dwt = DiscreteWaveletTransform[dat32, wavelet];
 gdwd = WaveletMatrixPlot[dwt]
 , {wavelet, {HaarWavelet[], DaubechiesWavelet[], MeyerWavelet[]}}]`

[image]

The different transforms can be selected, but there is no capability to change the order parameters. How can order parameters be introduced?

Comment: Related: [(7040)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7040/121),
[(56665)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56665/121)

Comment: MrW: valuable insights. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there ought to be something cleaner. While we wait for a better answer, you may use this to return the minimum and maximum number of arguments allowed for each wavelet:

```
nArgs[fun_] := 
 StringCases[ToString@DownValues@fun, 
            Shortest["ArgumentCountQ"~~__~~(n1:NumberString)~~__~~ (n2:NumberString)] :> 
            ToExpression[{n1, n2}]]


{#, nArgs@#} & /@ ToExpression /@ Names["*Wavelet"]

(*
{{BattleLemarieWavelet, {{2, 2}}}, 
 {BiorthogonalSplineWavelet, {{2, 2}}}, 
 {CDFWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {CoifletWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {DaubechiesWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {DGaussianWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {GaborWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {HaarWavelet, {{0, 0}}}, 
 {MexicanHatWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {MeyerWavelet, {{2, 2}}}, 
 {MorletWavelet, {{0, 0}}}, 
 {PaulWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {ReverseBiorthogonalSplineWavelet, {{2, 2}}}, 
 {ShannonWavelet, {{1, 1}}}, 
 {SymletWavelet, {{1, 1}}}}
*)
```

So:

```
m[fun_] := nArgs[fun][[1, 2]]
d = DiskMatrix[10];
Manipulate[
 WaveletMatrixPlot@DiscreteWaveletTransform[d, wv[Sequence @@ x[[;; m@wv]]]],
 {{x, {1, 1}}, ControlType -> None},
 {wv, {HaarWavelet, DaubechiesWavelet, MeyerWavelet}}, 
 Dynamic@Panel@Grid[{Slider[Dynamic@x[[#]], {0, 10, 1}], x[[#]]} & /@ Range@m@wv]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cleaner is better. Nice idea.