# Curl and other functions of functions

Tags: vector-calculus

Where can one find the source code of the Mathematica function Curl? Alternatively, how can one define a function the argument of which is restricted to be a 3D vector function of three variables named x, y, z?

Comment: It is actually rather difficult to determine if a symbol is specifically a function of `n` arguments.  See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85812/2079.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this: [Is it possible to do vector calculus in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19596/245)

Answer (score 2):

I would define

```
curl[u_?(VectorQ[#] && Length[#] == 3 &)] := {D[u[[3]], y] - 
   D[u[[2]], z], D[u[[1]], z] - D[u[[3]], x], 
  D[u[[2]], x] - D[u[[1]], y]}
```

**EDIT**

This function is intended to deal specifically with lists of length 3.  It can  handle symbolic inputs, but these must be explicitly defined as having 3 components.

```
curl[{fx[x, y, z], fy[x, y, z], fz[x, y, z]}]
```

> ```
> {-Derivative[0, 0, 1][fy][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][fz][x, y, z], 
>  Derivative[0, 0, 1][fx][x, y, z] - Derivative[1, 0, 0][fz][x, y, z], 
>  -Derivative[0, 1, 0][fx][x, y, z] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][fy][x, y, z]}
> ```

This is certainly not the only way (and may not be the best way) of defining `curl`, but matched the OP's request for an implementation that applied to 3-vectors.  (I assumed that the originator was aware of the built-in `Curl` and wanted something different).

Comment: Thank you, I see now how to specify u, thanks to the use of #.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this definition in order curl works like `D` ? I mean: With D, you may do some formal calculus. Try `D[f[x], x]` or `D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 1}]` or `D[2 f[x], x] - 2 D[f[x], x]`. But if you enter `curl[2 f[x]] - 2 curl[f(x]]`, you  don't get 0. Even if you use Expand, Simplify, etc. you are stuck with your input.

Comment: @AndréBellaïche you would have to start expanding the program by adding definitions for `curl`.