# Checking if input is a function

Tags: functions, variable

I would like to write a program to find the leading coefficient of a given polynomial. (Sounds easy, right?) I'd like to be able to handle the format `x^2-x+7` (with any formal variable `x`) as well as the format `#^2-#+7&`. I would also like to be able to reject/error on inputs which are not univariate polynomials.

I thought the function `Variables` would make this easy, but it turns out that

```
Variables[#^2-#+7&]
```

gives

> {#1^2 - #1 + 7 &}

which isn't helpful. My current plan:

1. Check if the input is a function; if so, substitute `f[\[FormalX]]` for `f`.
2. Check if `Variables[f]` has length other than 1; if so, fail.
3. Define `x` as `Variables[f][[1]]` and return `Coefficient[f,x,Exponent[f,x]]`.

But I'm stuck on the first step. Is there a good way to do this? Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does checking the head work, i.e. `yourFunction[x_Function]:= do something to x.`?

Comment: `Variables[#^2 - # + 7]` will work, tho.

Comment: @J.M. That's interesting -- is there a way to convert an anonymous function to this form automatically?

Comment: `Variables@First@Function[#^2 - # + 7]`

Comment: BTW, you might also be interested in `PolynomialQ[]`.

Comment: also `Variables @@ (#^2 - # + 7 &)` or `Variables @@ Function[#^2 - # + 7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lead[f_Function ] := lead[f@\[FormalX]]
lead[f_?PolynomialQ] /; (Length[(v = Variables[f])] == 1) := 
 Last@CoefficientList[f, v[[1]]]
lead[2 x^2 - x + 7 ]
lead[ 3 #^2 - # + 7 &]
```

> 2
>
> 3

Note this breaks if you supply a pure function with more than one slot.
See here if you need to deal with that: [How can I get the number of slots in Function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56665/2079)