# What happens when you divide by ##?

Tags: evaluation, pure-function, operators, sequence

I've been playing around with sequences a bit. In particular with using `##` with unary and binary operators.

Let's start simple, the following all make some kind of sense:

```
  + ## & [a,b] (* a + b *)
x + ## & [a,b] (* x + a + b *)
x * ## & [a,b] (* x * a * b *)
x ^ ## & [a,b] (* x ^ a ^ b *)
```

Now here is a slightly weird case:

```
  - ## & [a,b] (* -a*b *)
x - ## & [a,b] (* x - a*b *)
```

I guess, this sort of makes sense if `-` is actually interpreted as something like `+(-1)*`. But it also means that `+##-##` is generally non-zero.

But now here's the real puzzle:

```
x / ## & [a,b]   (* x a^(1/b) *)
x / ## & [a,b,c] (* x a^b^(1/c) *)
```

Wh... what? Can anyone explain what's happening here or at least give some justification like the one for subtraction? Answers which correct my explanation for subtraction are also welcome!

(No, I would never use this stuff in production code. But knowing what exactly is going on under the hood [could come in handy some time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A8478+%5Bcode-golf%5D+mathematica+wiki%3Ano).)

**Bonus Question:** Are there any other operators that yield unexpected and potentially "useful" results? (I mean, `!##` will yield `Not[a,b]` but that's neither very unexpected nor useful.)

Comment: Related: [(31797)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31797/121)

Comment: Users interested in such question should consider `Trace[x/## &[a, b, c]]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation for `Minus` states that

> -x is converted to `Times[-1,x]` on input.

So `-Sequence[a,b] == Times[-1,Sequence[a,b]] == Times[-1,a,b]` by this definition. Similarly the documentation for `Divide` states that

> x/y is converted to x y^-1 on input.

and therefore `x / Sequence[a,b] == x Sequence[a,b]^-1`. `Sequence[a,b]^c == Power[a, Power[b,c]]`. When `c == -1` you get `Power[b, -1] == 1/b`.

Comment: Accepting this, because it covers both `Minus` and `Divide`.

Answer (score 17):

```
x/## & // FullForm
```

> ```
> Function[Times[x,Power[SlotSequence[1],-1]]]
> ```

and `Power[a,b,c...] == Power[a, Power[b, c...]]` so now it should be clear.

This syntax is mentioned in the last bullet point in details of [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) documentation.

Comment: beat me by a femtosecond

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I was thinking it would probably be analogous to the minus case, but couldn't work it out. I think linking to the documentation for `Divide` would be more useful than linking to the documentation for `Power` though.