# Hazrat Exercise 9.2: Sequence resolves to Factorial?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, sequence

Throwaway comment in Hazrat p105:
Observe that `Range[10]/.{x_,y___}->y/x` amounts to 10!

I can't for the life of me figure out how this works.

It seems to resolve to `Sequence[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]/1` which then defaults to `Times[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]/1` which seems like odd behaviour.

I checked the documentation but this doesn't resemble their examples of a sequence being ready to splice into another function.

Any comments?

Comment: Ponder on the following: `Range[10] /. {x_, y___} -> FullForm[HoldComplete[y/x]]`. In general, when in doubt as to how things are evaluated, look at its `FullForm[]`.

Comment: This is because `Sequence[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]/1` is really `Times[Sequence[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], Power[1, -1]]` behind the scenes, which is the same as `Times[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, Power[1, -1]]`. The point is that `a/b // FullForm` is `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(71348)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71348/121)

Comment: Thanks all.  That's subtle and I will try and add HoldComplete//FullForm to my toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I described form like this in answer to [HoldForm[Operator ##] on some list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31797/121).  Using a method from [Using a list of tuples in a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3143/121#3146) we can see what `y/x` actually means to *Mathematica*:

```
HoldForm[FullForm[ y/x ]]
```

> ```
> Times[y, Power[x, -1]]
> ```

As discussed in [Why are numeric division and subtraction not handled better in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121) the `/` operator is silently converted into a combination of `Times` and `Power`, and it is *this* expression into which the sequence bound to `y` is inserted.

So we have directly:

```
Times[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Power[1, -1]]
```

It is arguable whether or not `Sequence` is involved here. (I remembering arguing this with Leonid as a matter of fact.)

Note that `Divide` is not interpreted in the same manner:

```
Range[5] /. {x_, y__} :> Divide[x, y]
```

> Divide::argrx: Divide called with 5 arguments; 2 arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> Divide[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```