# Unevaluated form of an expresion

Tags: hold

I have two matrices - `s1` and `s2`.

I want their sum to remain unevaluated.

For instance, the command

```
s1 + s2 // MatrixForm
```

should result to two separate matrices joined by the plus operator.

I guess that I have to wrap `s1 + s2` inside a function like `Hold` or `Unevaluated`, but I cannot find the proper workaround.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `Inactivate[MatrixForm[s1] + MatrixForm[s2], Plus]`

Comment: Sektor, thanks for the required modifications. I totally forgot them:-)!

Comment: Hi, ilian and thank you. Is there any alternative for versions prior to 10?

Comment: If just for display purposes, maybe `Row[{MatrixForm[s1] , "+", MatrixForm[s2]}]` ?

Comment: Ok! It looks great!

Comment: for V < 10: [31727](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31727/5478)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I cannot understand why command Defer[s1+s2] returns s1+s2.

Comment: Kuba, very useful post! Thank you.

Comment: @Kuba I think this might be considered a duplicate of that one; what do you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so, but since there is V10 the linked topic needs merges/linkes or new answers with showcases of `Inactive` too.

Comment: @Kuba Okay, why don't you answer 31727 with `Inactive` and I shall close this one as a duplicate of it?

Comment: Try this `ReplacePart[
 ReplacePart[
  HoldForm[s1 + s2], {1, 1} -> (s1 // MatrixForm)], {1, 
   2} -> (s2 // MatrixForm)] `

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do this now and I will try to find closely related topic later. I think I saw them but don't have time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s1 = {{8, 6, 6, 1}, {9, 8, 4, 4}, {5, 3, 5, 5}, {10, 5, 6, 2}};
s2 = {{9, 1, 10, 5}, {1, 9, 1, 3}, {8, 4, 4, 9}, {2, 9, 6, 2}};
Apply[
 HoldForm[#1 + #2] &, 
 MapThread[List, {s1, s2}, 2], {2}] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  8+9 & 6+1 & 6+10 & 1+5 \\
>  9+1 & 8+9 & 4+1 & 4+3 \\
>  5+8 & 3+4 & 5+4 & 5+9 \\
>  10+2 & 5+9 & 6+6 & 2+2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Or

```
SetAttributes[plus, Listable]
Apply[
 HoldForm[#1 + #2] &, plus[s1, s2], {2}] // MatrixForm
```

> (*same result*)