# Pass unevaluated function with evaluated arguments

Tags: functions, evaluation, hold

I am almost sure that this question has been asked somewhere. I found similar ones, but I cannot find exactly what I need, which might mean that I am on the wrong track.

I search a method to pass an unevaluated function with arguments to a second function. I could achieve this with `SetAttribute[,HoldAll]`. However the arguments of the first function should be evaluated when I pass it, which does not seem to be the case with `Hold`.

To give an example: I tried things like:

```
mytest[test_] := Module[{}, Print[test];]
mytest1[test_] := Module[{}, myvar = 2; ReleaseHold[test];]

SetAttributes[mytest1, HoldAll]

myvar = 1
mytest1[mytest[myvar]]
```

This prints `2`, because that is the value of `myvar` when `ReleaseHold` is called. However I want it to print `1`, the value of `myvar` when I call `mytest1`. In general myvar would be an expression which may contain global variables. I do not insist on using `ReleaseHold`. In fact the solution should be such that `mytest` would be evaluated by `NIntegrate`. In Maple I would achieve this by enclosing the name `mytest` in single quotes when passing it to `mytest1` which would delay evaluation by one step.

**Edit**

For clarification consider the following example, which is closer to the real case:

```
parameters = {a -> 1}

mytest[expr_, parameters_] := Module[{},
  NIntegrate[expr*a /. parameters, {var, 0, 1}]
  ]

mytest1[parameters_] := Module[{},
    globpar = 1;
    NIntegrate[mytest[globpar*var*var1, parameters], {var1, 0, 1}]
  ]

mytest1[parameters]
```

Mathematica returns the correct result `0.25` for this, but it issues a couple of error messages like `NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand var\ var1 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}."`. I want to avoid this (not by suppressing the error message!), because I want it to be fast and also the real function `mytest` might have a worse behavior if you insert non-numerical values. Hence I want that NIntegrate in `mytest1` first inserts a numerical value for `var1` and then passes the resulting expression as an argument to `mytest` to integrate it over `var`. I.e. I want that it evaluates the argument of the function first, which can however still contain names after evaluation.

Comment: myvar is a global variable.  The expression mytest[myvar] is passed as that to ReleaseHold but that's after myvar=2.  If you remove the SetAttributes it will work as you specify.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/12  Actually, it sounds like you are approaching a problem in the wrong way.  If you describe the actual problem that prompted you to try to do this, we might be able to offer a better solution.  There's no equivalent of Maple's single quote in Mathematica (well, `Unevaluated` comes close but it's not the same).

Comment: Or perhaps you're looking for `With[{myvar=1}, mytest1[mytest[myvar]]]`?  `With` can be used to inject something into a held expression.

Comment: After the update to your question, can you explain why [this solution](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820) isn't acceptable?  This is the usual way to handle nested numerical functions (NIntegrate inside NIntegrate, FindRoot inside NMinimize, etc.)

Comment: Maybe l don't understand it fully, but what l belief to understand is that it would act work to add a type 'NumericQ' to the definition of mytest,  because I am passing a complete expression dependent on at least the integration variable var to that function. Maybe there is a type/pattern which tests for an expression in one variable?, but then I could wonder if it is efficient.  Also the expression could in principle depend on more parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `Hold`  and `Evaluate` can achieve this: `Hold[mytest[Evaluate[...],...]]`. Illustrated with the example given in the question:

```
parameters = {a -> 1}

mytest[expr_, parameters_] := Module[{},
  (* globpar = 2; *)
  NIntegrate[expr*a /. parameters, {var, 0, 1}]
]

mytest1[parameters_] := Module[{},
  globpar = 1;
  NIntegrate[
   Hold[mytest[Evaluate[globpar*var*var1], parameters]], 
    {var1, 0, 1}]
  ]

mytest1[parameters]
```

Uncommenting `(* globpar = 2; *)` shows however that the global variable is evaluated only in the function `mytest` which can be avoided with one additional assignment of `globpar*var*var1` to a local variable which becomes the argument of `Evaluate`.