# Pattern matching and HoldForm

Tags: pattern-matching

Create rules based on data.
I have a system that picks out on date,based on some rules. I then want to generate a new rule based on this date and apply the rule to a new dataset.

```
datePicked={{2008, 3, 21, 0, 0, 0.}}
rule=datePicked/. {t_, n_, o_, b___} :> HoldForm[{t, n, v_, b} /; v <= o];


d=DateRange[{2008, 2, 21, 0, 0, 0.`}, {2008, 3, 21, 0, 0, 0.`}]
Cases[d,#]&@@rule
```

Problem is that the rule I have made is not general, it has assigned the $ to v. How can I make it general?

Comment: Why are you using `HoldForm`? It works fine without it.

Comment: Because then i only get the value from datePicked. but I want to make a rule based on datePick the output should be {t,n,v_,b}/;v<=0, However it comes out as {t,n,v$_,b}/;v$<=0, which means that I cant apply that pattern because it is not general due to $ sign.

Comment: As you can see the output is a pattern with a rule which is used in Cases, but since it is not general it does not work. I therefor want to make the output general by removing the $ signs each assigned to v.

Comment: Ok, I see. What you really need is something like `rule = datePicked /. {t_, n_, o_, b___} :> Identity[{t, n, v_, b} /; v <= o];`, where `Identity` serves as an escaping mechanism, so that the condition is not interpreted as a part of the rule during rule application in the above code. The reason your pattern didn't work was *not* due to `v` to `v$` renaming, but due to the presence of `HoldForm` in your pattern - the `HoldForm` head is not transparent for pattern-matching. As an alternative, you could use `HoldPattern` in place of `HoldForm`, but I like the solution with `Identity` better.

Comment: Works fine for me, just double-checked on a fresh kernel, copy-pasted from my comment. I tend to think this is a problem on your side. Just replace your definition of `rule` with mine, and try again.

Comment: Works great. However, when I look at the code with Trace I am not able to see what is going one. Could you show me how you are able to see the problem?

Comment: *"how you are able to see the problem"* - long experience :). Pattern-matching only shows in `Trace` when there are non-trivial calls to evaluator (via `Condition` or `PatternTest`). In this case, your entire pattern was wrapped in `HoldForm`, and the pattern-matcher was able to determine the fact of (non)match without testing the condition in the pattern. The problem of `Condition` being interpreted as a part of the rule rather than belonging to the answer (r.h.s.) only, is indeed rather subtle. This is a good question. If no one does this first, I will convert my comment into a proper answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Leonid explained in the comment, `HoldForm` is not transparent for the pattern matcher as opposed to `HoldPattern`:

```
MatchQ[#, HoldForm[_]] & /@ {a, HoldForm[a]}
MatchQ[#, HoldPattern[_]] & /@ {a, HoldForm[a]}
```

> ```
> {False, True}
>
> {True, True}
> ```

From the above you see that an expression will match the pattern `HoldForm[_]` only if its `Head` is `HoldForm`. `HoldPattern` is specially designed to be transparent for the pattern matcher, and so `HoldPattern[_]` is equivalent to `_` for the pattern matcher.

`Condition` (`/;`) is interpreted as a part of rule only if it is placed on level 1 inside it:

```
FullForm[lhs :> rhs /; test]
```

> RuleDelayed[lhs, Condition[rhs, test]]

```
{1, 2} /. x_Integer :> f[x] /; OddQ[x]
```

> {f[1], 2}

*Mathematica* [converts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/280) such structures to undocumented `RuleCondition` for the purposes of pattern matching:

```
Trace[1 /. x_ :> f[x] /; OddQ[x]] 
(*=>  {{x_:>x/;test,x_:>x/;test},1/. x_:>x/;test,{RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[1]],test],Fail},1} *)
```

If one wraps `Condition` with arbitrary head it is no more a part of the rule:

```
{1, 2} /. x_Integer :> f[x /; OddQ[x]]
```

> {f[1 /; OddQ[1]], f[2 /; OddQ[2]]}

The role of such head may serve `Identity` as Leonid suggests:

```
{1, 2} /. x_Integer :> Identity[x /; OddQ[x]]
```

> {1 /; OddQ[1], 2 /; OddQ[2]}

`HoldPattern` is also suitable but it is not necessary in your case.