# How I create a 'TraditionalForm' expression in which only parts are evaluated?

Tags: evaluation, formatting, latex, traditional-form

I have an expression for the form

```
Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] = ρ^f[a,b]ω[c]ρ^-f[a,b]
```

that I want to render in `TraditionalForm` for a variety of values `a`,`b`, and `c` so that, for example when `c==7` and `f[a,b]==5` for given `b` and `c` I get

$$W_5(7)=\rho^{5}\omega(7)\rho^{-5}$$

but I can't figure out how to get *Mathematica* to evaluate the parts I need evaluated, while leaving alone the parts I need left alone to get the desired result.

For example,

```
TraditionalForm[Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] = ρ^f[a,b]ω[c]ρ^-f[a,b]]
```

just results in

$$\omega(7)$$

How can I control evaluation and formatting of my expression to have the desired parts evaluated (here for example the application of `f` and the values of `a`,`b`, and `c`, without also collapsing the whole structure of the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = TraditionalForm[
  HoldForm[Subscript[W, f[a, b]][
     c] == \[Rho]^f[a, b] \[Omega][c] \[Rho]^-f[a, b]]];

res /. {c -> 7, f[a, b] -> 5};
```

[image]

For your second question you can try this:

```
g[a_,b_]:=a Sin[b];

res /. {c -> 7, f[a, b] -> g[2 , 3]}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! What about when `f` is defined elsewhere; that is, I have `f[a_,b_] := ...` somewhere else and can vary; i.e the right hand side of the `f[a,b] -> ...` rule is not constant but depends on `a` and `b`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius please check the update.

Comment: Yes but `a` and `b` could be coming from anywhere. For example `TraditionalForm[HoldForm[Subscript[W, f[#, b]][c] = ρ^f[#, b] ω[c] ρ^-f[#, b]]] & /@ Range[3] /. {b -> 2, c -> 7, f[a, b] -> g[a, b]}` leaves all the `f` unsubstituted, while I need them replaced with the evaluation of `g`.

Comment: In this case use pattern replacement: TraditionalForm[
     HoldForm[
      Subscript[W, f[#, b]][
        c] = \[Rho]^f[#, b] \[Omega][c] \[Rho]^-f[#, b]]] & /@ 
   Range[3] /. {b -> 2, c -> 7} /. {f[a_, b_] -> g[a, b]}.

Comment: That leaves `g[a,b]` unevaluated. For example if `g[a, b] := a + b` it leaves `1+2`, etc. rather than `3`; and if `g[a, b]` is more complex, it results in errors.

Comment: Please not that your expression is inside Hold. If you want to evaluate any part inside, check this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replace-inside-held-expression

Comment: I've managed, in my context, with `TraditionalForm[HoldForm[Subscript[W,#][#]=ρ^f[#]Subscript[ω,#]ρ^-f[#]]]& /@ Range[4] /. ((f[#]-> g[#,c])& /@ Range[4])` but still get useless results. For example $ρ^0$ should just be absent, and some cases get weirdly formatted, e.g. as $\frac{ω_4 ρ^{-(-1)}}{ρ}$, instead of $ρ^{-1}ω_4ρ^1$.

Comment: I've posted a [follow on question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76859/37) covering this last issue.

Answer (score 3):

Crucial, for answer to this question, is: **why parts of our expression should "stay unevaluated"**.

`=` in *Mathematica* is [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) function. If we want to express assignment, but just don't want to evaluate it, then we can use `=` and `HoldForm` like in [rasher's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76728/how-i-create-a-traditionalform-expression-in-which-only-parts-are-evaluated#76729), or, if we just want to suppress `Set` evaluation, we can [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) it:

```
Inactivate[Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] = ρ^f[a, b] ω[c] ρ^-f[a, b], Set] // TraditionalForm
```

> $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\omega (c)$

If later we want to perform this assignment we can take above expression and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) it.

If we want to express equality, not assignment, then use `==` as already [suggested by Algohi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76728/how-i-create-a-traditionalform-expression-in-which-only-parts-are-evaluated#76730) it renders the same in `TraditonalForm`, but there's no `Set` evaluation to suppress.

```
Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == ρ^f[a, b] ω[c] ρ^-f[a, b] // TraditionalForm
```

> $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\omega (c)$

---

There's still "unwanted evaluation" on right hand side. The question is similar: **why we don't want `ρ^f[a, b] ω[c] ρ^-f[a, b]` to evaluate to `ω[c]`**.

If we want it to preserve exactly this form and prevent any evaluation, then we should use `HoldForm`, as in other answers.

If we just want to prevent simplifications of multiplication, then again we should ask ourselves why.

- If this is an ordinary commuting multiplication, but we just don't want it to perform built-in simplifications, then we can inactivate [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) function, for example like this:

  ```
  Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == Inactive[Times][ρ^f[a, b], ω[c], ρ^-f[a, b]] // TraditionalForm
  ```

  > $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\rho ^{f(a,b)}*\omega (c)*\rho ^{-f(a,b)}$

  If we don't want `*` signs, we can change `TraditionalForm` boxes of `Inactive[Times]` to be the same as of ordinary `Times`:

  ```
  MakeBoxes[Inactive[Times][x__], TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[HoldForm@Times[x], TraditionalForm]

  Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == Inactive[Times][ρ^f[a, b], ω[c], ρ^-f[a, b]] // TraditionalForm
  ```

  > $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\rho ^{f(a,b)}\omega (c)\rho ^{-f(a,b)}$

  As in case of inactive `Set`, we can at any point `Activate` `Times`.
- If `ρ` and `ω` don't commute, then use [`**`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) instead of `Times`.

  ```
  Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == ρ^f[a, b] ** ω[c] ** ρ^-f[a, b] // TraditionalForm
  ```

  > $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\rho ^{f(a,b)}\text{**}\omega (c)\text{**}\rho ^{-f(a,b)}$

  Again if we don't want stars, we can change `TraditionalForm` boxes of `NonCommutativeMultiply` to be the same as of ordinary `Times`:

  ```
  MakeBoxes[NonCommutativeMultiply[x__], TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[HoldForm@Times[x], TraditionalForm]

  Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == ρ^f[a, b] ** ω[c] ** ρ^-f[a, b] // TraditionalForm
  ```

  > $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\rho ^{f(a,b)}\omega (c)\rho ^{-f(a,b)}$

---

## Negative powers

In *Mathematica* expressions with with negative numeric powers are **rendered** as division by same expressions with positive power:

```
a^-5
```

> $\frac{1}{a^5}$

As we can see in `FullForm`:

```
a^-5 //FullForm
(* Power[a,-5] *)
```

This is still `Power` expression, so no simplifications where performed. Result we're getting is done when expression is converted to boxes and holding evaluation will not help here.

```
HoldForm[a^-5]
```

> $\frac{1}{a^5}$

It may seem to work when we do something like:

```
HoldForm[a^-b] /. b -> 5
```

> $a^{-5}$

But what really happens is that we have held multiplication of `-1` and `5` which can be seen in `FullForm`:

```
HoldForm[a^-b] /. b -> 5 // FullForm
(* HoldForm[Power[a,Times[-1,5]]] *)
```

Above expression is rendered as we want because exponent is not a negative number. It is a more complicated expression. This expression would evaluate to negative number, but we've prevented its evaluation. Here we see also another feature: multiplication by `-1` has also some special rendering rules.

That's why holding evaluation will fail e.g. in this situation:

```
HoldForm[a^-b] /. b -> -5
```

> $a^{-(-5)}$

If we want to get different boxes for `Power` expressions, instead of holding evaluation, we need to define special box representations.

Going back to example from question. `Power[ρ, ...]` in `TraditionalForm` is rendered, as power of any other symbol:

```
ρ^5 // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^5$

```
ρ^(1/2) // TraditionalForm
```

> $\sqrt{\rho}$

```
ρ^-5 // TraditionalForm
```

> $\frac{1}{\rho^5}$

```
ρ^-a // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^{-a}$

To change this behavior we need to redefine `TraditionalForm` boxes for such expressions, for example like this:

```
MakeBoxes[HoldPattern@Power[ρ, x_], TraditionalForm] := SuperscriptBox["ρ", MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]]
```

Now we get:

```
ρ^5 // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^5$

```
ρ^(1/2) // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}$

```
ρ^-5 // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^{-5}$

```
ρ^-a // TraditionalForm
```

> $\rho^{-a}$

---

## Summary

With special formatting defined e.g. like this:

```
MakeBoxes[HoldPattern@Power[ρ, x_], TraditionalForm] := SuperscriptBox["ρ", MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]]
MakeBoxes[HoldPattern@NonCommutativeMultiply[x__], TraditionalForm] := RowBox[List @@ (Function[expr, MakeBoxes[expr, TraditionalForm], HoldAllComplete] /@ HoldComplete[x])]
```

we get:

```
Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] == ρ^f[a, b] ** ω[c] ** ρ^-f[a, b] // TraditionalForm
% /. {f[a, b] -> 5, c -> 7} // TraditionalForm
```

> $W_{f(a,b)}(c)=\rho ^{f(a,b)}\omega (c)\rho ^{-f(a,b)}$
>
> $W_5(7)=\rho^5\omega(7)\rho^{-5}$

without any evaluation manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls = HoldForm[Subscript[W, f[a, b]][c] = ρ^f[a, b] ω[c] ρ^-f[a, b]]

ReplaceRepeated[ls, {f[a, b] -> 5, c -> 7}]
```

[image]

Then just *TraditionalForm* that...